# Who's that pokemon (based on its etymology)?

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, natural-language, test-battery

As we all know, most Pokemon are created by combining some English (or Japanese) words; these words are the Pokemon's "etymology." For example, "charmander" is "char" and "salamander" put together.

Your task is, given a Pokemon's etymology and number, output the original Pokemon name. A short answer will be able to compress the 890 Pokemon into much fewer characters by exploiting the fact that the etymologies and the names themselves use mostly the same characters.

**Input:** The Pokemon number, and an array/list of etymologies, all lowercase

**Output:** The Pokemon's name, also lowercase

The full list of test cases can be found here: https://pastebin.com/B3rRdiPn. Each line is a test case with the format:

```
<pokemon number>;<comma separated etymology list>;<pokemon name>
```

This list was created from https://pokemondb.net/etymology by running the following code:

```
let collectedRows = [];
let rows = $(".data-table tr").slice(1)
let isOddPrev = false;
// Replacements due to typos, remove 'palindrome' since girafig doesn't come from the word 'palindrome', 'palindrome' is just a descriptor
var repl = {"anacondo": "anaconda", "armadilo": "armadillo", "[palindrome]": ""}
rows.each((_, row) => {
  let isOdd = row.classList.contains("odd");
  let etym = $(row).find(".cell-etym-word").text().toLowerCase();
  if (repl.hasOwnProperty(etym)) etym = repl[etym];
  if (isOdd !== isOddPrev) {
    collectedRows.push({name: $(row).find(".cell-name").text().toLowerCase(), etymology: [etym], num: parseInt($(row).find(".cell-num").text().replace(/\s/g, ''), 10)});
  } else {
    collectedRows[collectedRows.length - 1].etymology.push(etym);
  }

  isOddPrev = isOdd;
});

// Output:
collectedRows.map(pokemon => pokemon.num + ";" + pokemon.etymology.join(",").replace(/\,$/, '') + ";" + pokemon.name).join("\n")
```

**Examples**:

The full list of test cases can be found at the pastebin link, but here are some example inputs and outputs:

```
1, ['bulb', '-saur'] --> 'bulbasaur'
122, ['mr.', 'mime artist'] --> 'mr. mime'
29, ['nidoru' ,'rhino', '♀'] --> 'nidoran♀'
16, ['pigeon'] --> 'pidgey'
17, ['pigeon'] --> 'pidgeotto'
23, ['snake'] --> 'ekans'
```

Note that due to 'nidoran♀' and its family, you need to be able to handle input/output in UTF-8.

The winner is the entry with the highest accuracy, with ties broken by code length. In practice, this means that the challenge is code-golf -- you need to get 100% accuracy to be a competitive entry -- since you can trivially create a lookup table, but feel free to post a sub-100% accuracy answer if you think it does something creative (someone else might extend it to handle the edge cases).

If you wish, you may also include a data file, and the number of bytes of that file is added to your byte count. This is just if you want to keep your code and data separate.

Comment: Why do we take the pkmn number as input?

Comment: @RGS It looks like the etymology doesn't resolve uniquely to a name, `16, ['pigeon'] --> 'pidgey'`, `17, ['pigeon'] --> 'pidgeotto'`. So, sometimes you need the number.

Comment: @xnor maybe it would be interesting to only take etymology as input and let the solutions return any of the possible names when there are several Pokémon with the same etymology

Comment: What is accuracy here? Name completely right Vs name completely wrong? Or are different mistakes weighed differently?

Comment: Waiting for a Pyke solution.

Comment: Seeing as there are already solutions, it's probably too late to want to correct this, but Slowpoke and Slowbro have weirdly repeated etymologies

Comment: I think that the `♀` symbol is unicode, not UTF-8

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js 11.7+)](https://nodejs.org), 100%, 2094 bytes

Same as below, with the data file compressed with Brotli instead of zlib.

```javascript
n=>a=>(require('zlib').brotliDecompressSync(require('fs').readFileSync('a'))+'').split`/`[n-1].replace(/\d.\d?/g,([i,p,l])=>a[i].substr(p,++l||9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZbJzqTIFUb3/RS/alNVorqYJ1vVVgLJkMkMCQndLZl5noIpQf3u5ZQXli1vI76Iu7k636mjLZoTUI3Lr/2QZj/z@ePHB8imtQLZl8/5/Pnr33/5JZ@/76BaMrFqM@foky@fo8/fPrg1zzPwPQdD9@WTRFq@wu8GLYXYyYJYQWSW47ZqXJPYfyHzxXqchAt3hwameKFwmg@o@yB5ZngJlrW@FxQLg7y1nS2oe4qM0QdbhGSjBYCa/bDyuCQK@gqyli2EE8pPN6YrDyi@75vdEHnrY8JE6oof9nkWxUJDh0nhJ9oIezMq3qL1nig8VanTam8BO2gF7SENZa/rySRKcIGvMOeHocZZkYgoT6uYuH26qHZ/fXYVqVWHNGjXKzsDtU/inpu0S8zkeEDoS5piV1fD@9GaiP1ZepKdR6Cjs60bVstuGjCE1AZTC8qZWmLgj7aIeWLDIw8G1LbNGdRjbVgP7XG6zMPSd2l3AUS7uyIi/QO05GzGuh5PhETesfGUIskcRk9itRfCjXFfOMUj7OYxxuT6eq/90b2uVa8@qW2F6Ui68JIfjCp5PwhJn414GYN2iJLF7McyrgIwGqnfFjsve2h1CUVbpBffzLLphp2L3WFsSd0O/JlhcgV29UG5CYGPquYBiBqfrQz4WewNst8SghR4hrdH4u5ujr9Q4mgO/Ir1dPc6rrh50ik1QupC4lRS5ZVa6MoNSiGTn3xg8KQXXOOx6dMRqXPdhiWlEfHNm71z83kbv9pLuFSSL2dhiTa9VozLWunRzOCKbXt6TKqjyufKDFLMeZKGzPhhwT5GDEEqaDl4GI5fuE6F9h6sCB2o1DNcCDXi70v/RDQqwFC3lW6IZh17qFtxlY/78znUcqmEqSNxJG@ZwNSYSdgIISpW5lxwKxh6aXltt/3VbfukuWsyWQj8IngxP4Wie81iTbpPaBO864RghEg4/Wp5vh5fBHdNH5Viu8ZyU1@xfNWY8ojTCXOTJ03qkEFsGuS9AF7iZZu99/kWzvXsrZCNoTWM6oa9PaaaQYcbtyQ2xeNGhkZB4yaBTLdIhgQzWzCc19qmueK3eZCDqZA1h5tRDMOeE@X5Q2I5bJqFl8fpBSd15Wz/hQI39xQTXPqhqq@HIsX4e@tMa5KipngtrBRERjFV8ct1KqzZPfoMytqbKaJcTiA1Src/tH7Lt3qyKrVcuUBCbNqgh9K7NqCfH3Ne7x03zJmsP3rrMIXCURHVFx7@stGtHkao6kw7kk86ZTUQhfkLxD1r6HxM5QHQ2dSFBA6gRhIigIEQJSC6JdN6HwHhV2roByrAqs7jGngo@BVKUQXRvMjorreoW8FEn3gjJaxf8DZSsytOteUQMcNZxpHZJQUeawXgO3OR7orO9DRTQBwYdmGUDFtl9Eg72LY68ngxOOMNHdQTpccxZF6rMH5qC8BGNSsc7yPCFdY2W0vDkE95GXHX8Og4xLA52Pj5gVkSRVNy6wt1TqEbAlJ94g17V4JbLssSQrY@1wHlyAU0vQQrPnR0sYs9NN9U47i5logf3iu4b8gKTG4hxMWD0hO1XySHBGKKy4V4g2Tm9Jh8pMa@zlnOerHzdLkPxwlVhImX7BY5zSu5OnbeoBnKTrMqGxk@9wb7XKvazVTE6e@OO1fmU1P9HK4OIsQeC2MXs3nb3JKFME5rA6BrxCtzeyIqBipZnRxaoBgWDiq6Z1HqnEWKvDnC4joaXuJ591mAssTK0REeaFZBCx3MheUUiLUhWfC7BhqEHWLoinhXg00riRGlLSA1Edsc70L42KYyHQ@sATvQggpvm/fCbEYVl6g1gD7f8VXA8a7Z3MmdndvdKyQxviVlVxNUT3J@CqV9fCNfxjpFlQ@3TbExU/x09enplPUT0a@6Ar9f7bV6KSvDKhNvv1GLyxclGTqsB@I72jlMrqij5BGTcvd3sli14SZa57PmqbAE7XS@bjVjr5SSaCiNiX52BcJdZHeBQPMCgZR5YUT/SbaqtoRXZA3cZM7TSM7uUCHmBgNGOoovOFv4b@zaK3odbd5MR9yK@hRPHMk2rTh4vZatlsHusTHFM4@xzcsGSYV7gsWaL3srQZvcfBS2agmexpYuoDv1ItViYAg5iksTxRuvijdN/tG8VgqsiqVuTp0rz1VpIvt@aw1@oHBbk9qrJb37IQiesw2PE5XxYaweNGa3WIjFixZIJ5KEowGxSGFA8lGrlUBKd1yRzxEb@uX5qvBQl0v2hIG1obWA3kSIucMIsSAIvsAq2mX3YmDf5WEymqEVnr3Z7W0XYVvLJZAYA75iN72GNreY9aRHJveuXOGTOY7zRrbyg5GpNcwxytUq6BIu/eRAZLp6HeunQfGm0go8iQ7fdKuz@5U48vSAsFLcOD1reCRt@YeGPzy7uUrdmq9TjdtyKSVCzmTZmGfr4JC84ObEFh4@ZkwCj1ROLUsqNG18WN/Ga0@Oa45fJlPzCn1zNWRYLykCKpclxx0OKN93TfhhmSZXkQieDKBE6s2e@DogCX1amgTLYjx2h8hUmEd2iapnqgJ7l8NijcPZSem8iBxsdU3qSQvg4aoHWm@K6SaAvxVyG1oSKpXzmz9GZUjnKzg4H0Jr8/kiU393BOmdn9EWyU2IBhOsGBDZHnN6C1QEPulsDfx2XY6dwsUD593SezyviR2WDDz2UZxd6wMPNnqG6KNve@ve4u7AHFHO2y8Hu9KwzSh77nNAarPmBJegXBQDNqiuf68KebgGe@PF3hSGIOhIx6APxvXthdv2HW/mlUCMT98@PsXRnFHEp69ff/klGfp5aLPv7VB8@exUZ/Yx5B9ptEQf@dsz//bx@QP6eJsneHPlv8Xz6/c264ulfN9@/oiPJXs76ltRf/zsf/wW/fjty3/k9Wyr@J2OwbC0lZAlQzeCbJ7//c//GO7/j/gKfX4fz2NbLf@E//l7/yv65zs0tlGSfYH/SL//kf4DLr59@b36Nn5r//z6Hvx79ef3eY3nBXwZv0FQ@9df7NevP3/@Cw) (not working on TIO)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 100%,  <s>2176 2158</s>  2151 bytes

This is similar to the self-contained version below but uses an external data file of 2010 bytes named `'a'`. The TIO link generates a local copy of this file.

The final size was computed according to [the rules for scoring multiple files](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4934/58563):

$$2010+140+1=2151$$

```javascript
n=>a=>(require('zlib').inflateRawSync(require('fs').readFileSync('a'))+'').split`/`[n-1].replace(/\d.\d?/g,([i,p,l])=>a[i].substr(p,++l||9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fX3JkuM4k@a9niKsLllpkZmhXVS3/T0W@77vUV1mA5IQheACBhdJlPWhre9zn7nPpY/zDL/1i/SL9PgGSpFV1mZVGXDHFwwJBAH/3B3OdzVXZVCYvPqe2VD/17Tc@ttWoT9qU@jfvkzLL1//8ZdfpuWPRWEqfWQSfd9kwW9f1JdvW3v1dKqLH9PCpr/9Gj7N/LC@7B1W3fOd7edir7O7l1zdvB3cL/cu87Izets3bzovHjJ1Nw665/lsOEiu7s9Wq8Pd@Hl34r939tToarVMiujy4X2348937ba@y7Kpt3e26h6eRP776/Rw3HSqIAyudgbBwD@6fiwezOiwGffmpwdFqIYXg52Dq93n@yK@bl6f0@n94fn0aXn91D0x@eRUT5@Ory868/HOznlzPt6@eR9cjJ7Piofi9PhirPrv3ZvudtfL46dk73w56nnvneNZvnd6/zp9uZrEN9277f2zJ29v/LZ9@nC/Oy2SnZeTaNU7HNjpvdEPb9d1Z1cvFheT8OT1qf9cz8bL3u3@TXQyGviXt1Xa651Ol73HpLgdXZ2dhunJ@d2lutt9HNrDj3d/N573F5Ns@qJvq3lw8XCwl9nHM2958/RwnXSe7M3V0WvkRVevN89m3hvap4Oby@Hq5iN4vhpme1Hx0B9eDY9et9@fH0blRTF9n768jUd7JvnoLf3V/fZk@77uL3cvu/U4W82qg@FB96K36s2vTm36cXzpDV4vl1PT3GV5/XiTXH88H6vJm97eT66n/evr/ulxL7w7WfSGb4VX97w4GFdHb3fXo@3jwuzk8w99BCN0dBoeX6f68n1k9s3o7DZ4OZ7vmo9xdjT5WJ7m0@3tQr12Lg5PO6PsJh43B7uqp9LFva4WN8/L6@lydb0/vr09vD/uqfjm7mUnv69m2c7z0/Dy5WnwZvzn8PkuvXz2zCjMsv3Z5dSP43L/bjU7SAbHze3Nx@vJ06qnDyuV7QTH0WyptgMdz98PL7P0@iKNq9H1x0NyFzx3p/n7ZJ7vBg/zsu4fh@r1enpzvfN@9LJ/W92OT8vk5r48WN2Pbycn/nnZOTuO7EOTqIt@T8fe08myuyjf72ZnSaRH3m30ai/ezV5zfvFaXYc7d3V429k9S/cfrsf3dzuXvenQyzs72cs8SVZht3tkc2v397rHe/3rSD82e6cqqC7Pe53Z8V19vB3vPQWjAz1KipfFRbS4nu2eRZejqH6/K/P6PnrMzz7eTmZFr@ql3YNgVhqvPsvPb29Pn/ZMYK7Gd7s305Pz0/3V64ff@dh@Kk/ezq6uz7rl0/5k0J1dXBycPNqrPE3istM8PRTT@2h4vBztW3/7cpVOtl@ft4cnh4tu/FTtrh690/pk@3VqZnV58HxyXJw/7BTLg6uPo/ezfqNtVebl1fn74nrxsLpuvNDXar/XO16mb4@75Xl3ke2cGHU@vpxeHNXR@yDsvF3P4@cyux68PY9n183pxcXxcPx0ExRlvl3nb2kc9g7V/eMwe9w76r9e9gc76s3rdvaS52S1F1wbv3jpnhRXN0/@48v8OVKTedqcnXb2@@c3w969F6yej54Ob/Lssoonxe35WN099Ibvl8PwbXnbXFyVZ2l8MvJM3xvcj8/P@91g9BSoveHj63WxCK/fusHwbHQe34W7t3aSn6qH0fZOWR3cjs63b5vHp6Drne3feZ1ufXd8PY@y3eTo6vn4pdtcnB2qnbLYezk@Pf8Ik/Qj86qdzCzPn5Om8fyLLBnMDtVb4y8XnaupbTrLc13M90/mL7vToNaH88fFR3Ex/xh5C3vTKc7vH19uzHV15z9VL1UzOzrYGcXbxcu4Mz6yw2fvsHw9vkl3@oO592RX00l6PY1e5m9ldXR8eTnr25dTfZqlp4PhwUl/J4njeHdeXr/mD8HU75cX5bw3yYYfO5Ojm5394evlavtlr9z2uxfheDexH49ZoB4TM1sc7XnbD4dz9XDn97zz/fPt8XZVvNUW2nq/s3fhm5u7@5PwKdvZ929PP8ZN83Q1ifT0Zrna8672z9T9bfcmCp@nR@VzMDo6v7utrnMAeE@wAlzc9@fDuNu3fnqorq6X56Mwn55nnWTeq57DZvi6F92PL7qntzA1speDh93rozA9Dg@Ws4esubl5mrzOJtuDbuK/vO7tTE0yG45Hx/XNqJsqG158bF/eh1Z3o6v7fr@snmF6jE@vTocn@cn7YVZf297xk37aLm7KwagbH@RP2TyDDSzzzzt55@g@OgwOn7b339Kb5@vO8fWr/zydn3qr7bOwez0Izk5Ob47V5WCV3k3vistpevxR7LzfmqB@hjHtHp4vOnWwf3W579l95a/KUdjz8kI/qquTYLa7s79znV5l2XB58/I2vVzdhfvb@@FLUSbbS728veterl5fTy@n972jt55RH9W0H8xgl@50Lnv3yd59Ohw@363goUiS4OEufBp23x6yh37ydL8/qe63o9vpvb7eu4zs/cv1x9vkqZf3Do/LQbU77/Qv7m9fn7qDQdzUq@HTweG82R9tPwZPr3r5lIfnD8@X1dFTMDk9CofhOFjtXpcP49nexUNwE69Gbzf7Nwe7L8li8jC7fbvctmbcOdzZ3@/a9O4xPrs8zK8f82Fs08f3YF/dnJ32nst3o49Xw6Pb@qm6P8zvw4vF6Kl3qO9Ht72Jur0OH8aP9V5/XgYHdvI02S2PHl5MunxOvdt0WgfF/vEomB2b26fB@a7//HA7Oziu51cHk9ezo/7d9XAZvWoT9PevXz4WeR02u8@z7kUWnN2Y6W0ZXz2qp9nbzcycXu7ePSePUXB@kmTds1OdzaPBovQ@9mfv@XAwXlzsDldePgvK@Lh/V9zXp/1uY6/eQpghS5u@nO0cXfcf5x/esrNK95N8qhePK7PzuF9d5qPBZH7gPSb3@9vv117zcHLuT07Pgufq/tF7nK7S7brZXvW6e@lrtXPaS2/T8PHu4d00fnd5ePHx1us87J5U96/9ncnH8@706iSOb8vJy/HyAiylw4fp9H5ZJ8U87/Re7/eOP@LZfAUryPJgZ/A22w1m54/2ePJwe/Zy078@by67V88vg6m/aNLm7e7tavDwkeZ3Fx/F6K1nr7v2ogqibP/oIn2u@kFvT3WH2wepWh2asvve1/Pxx/Mgf@rNR4@Xu/ry7vZt/va8Kk569c7xYTXrwMAtVr1IbXdPy/Aknb2nI@@sO2xy9Xo/MZej/c5Ot7tb7x8cHWzbN3vR3X/JLh4mvd5dlRX5xU4SvLyc3ry89mBYH6PBxd7waTQ6P/P3pt5tf7w3HdX3@fLpPfebwbN@C7qX4@now8TxI1hHnf6kD89tdJlNT/TL8fCkqOaD6a/ftn71ValHg1@/fv3ll8BmpU30j8RGv325Nyu9ZadboarUFiwP@h@2vmxtb4E1W2gVbhqzX38kOouqGfR@2fKbSpf/nH2By03/9l/Z3/5J/e2ffmtN4lVifMCbbJqoSt@pBV3jk8X858t/3f4C6jJPTPU/d/7n79n37h8AyhMV6N92/jn88c/h/9iJvv32u/mWf0v@@Ap/8nfzx4@y9suq@C3/tr2d/Mu/TL5@/a9//P2X37vffv/VrxP/12@/fi9VXfz6xzeSlQi//N4DhJk3mwAQ2@4@dM91VpebAFI4xAAQwUwVAChVolKVhZpQqGylX34frnHwI9WJtlkLc9Ivv4/WsMSsVBE6jBN@@X0MkBKHsAJQVRdVohHEKmr/8rsHmAVdpbJFZU2pP2GhC/UCnuAoJaqsNuE4UqgTAcaygx8N7mORmyRR/B1ZFACOdqorldoin9nS4KDllr4BqrkJuB7dlQp@dZrgyE8LzX@PdSwBDgd/YYsUIJnWoXx01wIAjb0NLI9krOI6U9yDo@1r/NJhAZ@Wrg6/KG0A4DjnJpKbkJsw0g33jP/cY6vKcqf3V53chaNYKBxD@Pe7@l7Bv/A/4kABLf5ovU6L04UKDQ6hYFwbQDiUZa55WuWqKOyC7jGqqAkYHMbpnyDTDQQOYJmpmP6AjlVWsp7HzS/wE/2qCt/GrB/St4sV/k/ztOZvGStuAmREn96se0FoO2lmwpTHTzQrNH9kkJ0AEG8DAtNr1kJEAAgOZGZCW9Q4ljOTWfj5n//nXxFKepWxBI9n56@w31ULNTIh@t1N4EetdeYwTgBQ76//8r99@sv/xtj@X/5lu/GXecr0B5vA2GSRg0gbILQ2JHqKz4IyRUOPFsjSBsRoE@Hzk0AIX56FPo79vE5yk@GsL82SVipULBng0eeg3koluuSPkWknAARH/t1EUYKgvJ5OEUOKRiRY73DIFw5U2Tqie0iapmpRON6r2lf45MCzx88BKbgfhzqySWLzdTfIbT8Orw1DeppCw/MEZCOTZICjGiXW4uLg00@8gDSgH4d0bviLJHVKA4ayEwBCS4AqVGn4CaQ2d403u2BHyEodVC2G2wDzeHegDxFl/CVQzty3mGwAUlvNHEDasCvgaIYmwrmT6IquAKI0oR/HMayxvyoMzS6QpAndPVpy@cnHn@6yOHy5LkqjeKFqm9CHQ5eXTTAzAa6PdRATpGykCZAh351wox/Fth@HLrVZrHH5hk0upimLDVlFhzSChUnpBsBPRQOpch5p7OA2QHEUI1izEtrzqhlBSCECYHAgVREomr7wA@cxrV1tG7ZOHMsc5pRZWBywhaJHDTSGmwDp/gSZmSJpQSIArPcTDBbnWQsTAWA4ygqW0UCFyq2m/BM6B3/ujNsm9OMYg8EQq5WiybvRhl4aYVh2La208JTQ@EoL@sef@3mJJ0Uso@F9Qqi0vQQ3AUH7vk4S2kAKW1e8TSZJK4GxQY@71jkuVtwruzBoRAJUlx63AKyHhqYqbb0OjB2gAZHBOLqVzioV0PMJ@zfBWMUCoPo/oYpab8BEAhytBNp@p7ka8uTRVprQT3O5UHP@bW6JTTYe8TzXqcxwzaM/ptlrs4YMmKyplJFZgm2GeLQRggWA0xpWJfjrsp2R1u1mYxzkMoEn9Nvmjxxv00bzj09tsN86f/o1v7Dyr4C5CViyu1QESzk@jbKakUIEwPQ2MRWbLyyL4enheE9V8X2qq2CmyWoDkaQvbLh5ONShDS0NNS9GlhvQOVx3tkuVDd1K5eFQl1rROJZabp435uXN0uQK2WKAH6QgAC8OJpVFARp86zwc11TWprTmdWlCozaTKQ0/KzbFSeUM8UmX9lKFa7JtSoTgXgp2rqCh3Ugb0LRRKTRloxmYwwmtdJFrAQDHbabqTH573YQ@HrA810n09/@bRYyIgD4pAeCgwaSizdpmslVPcKxCWABLnIArNo5RXollPMFhmzV5RkY2/lFscxcOWFAonx4Z5fv0eWPXAgAOXMxP89SEIT8LpHGPRbeD4zi3Cc4VW/j0DIPETezHIYSnCB5rG@I81ss8sfzsrdUMxfHTUUQgHdQ8OaEZRSIgqP8TyBYtSgREkdla4zfzLa//INnMXWRIU5zsYFzZlcwNNIdVLBgc2Zmh5wTmPew3PLigAjlxxKMz/gkGi2a2xomEQBztxMBfoocqqulqqDBVLVO425mQuQ2Gkhh/sZ1One3XJVq1mGm9kt5F28ReHGlnXc5sQZ@imDXSRERvAxFaBwit6@8zo8wCLVQSjBmhOkSgKoV3nlZWaOlEGBRRKKAMMFUtXhpn7cyUW7EMBXWVcTsUXXnA4ZMR2cSfhgcXNe6qY0YRMVMRf1yQw8IBPDE9poYW1dZUR50z1LtEtvgyzqIGqTWou0SyygqWL75KY4mroKapBdL9DOEVBhWp47PEsNLiB62qqd4C0gyLBE2q4sdWalKHI54VNGK6cEsmLXGtd5PRE/7eZEtRD9snyASmwufcr1er9gFSIiGUTYEoVWRrFbJyp8r9BSascH@JCZqCOVvGLQR4dJfroi75LteFLaVrwtcmSzBQhdgIETC@IhcSjkMZNQUvwA3Yv6H7bSJViQ1mW5ku6dqJyp0N3SU2FRqmzm0DO@hp/z6nL6vnLdvHkZqr3OLXEIJNonONdIknvfOyJACU1v04UtNEFXoNILEF8L6eNDLx4OLSxE4cJpXC881G/3fZSC2YtY1bqYgibYBwvghImuiW6NCj49f81dsWdnXXXbhk5GtALuNG1EjpgiyaHLYSG6qgamjjVJsSYpnhW/rGiaJJhiI3ETBgw7miO1zTJvErzuOgztxHwlFdqZyWD7qLILT3eMCmPoxyxoYdIVBRaAehTZyfZoCYrOH9SkHTCMTbhCieoywrN02JLLWYODPRrFrDnCHTJcaUalzjq4Vl3rPgFvZ2pZf1ouzREmgCtk7hxipeCk0MPL1yLiMcS181tCsoor4gwZ4wlf4BXTpStBgWwDvqlP9M5NqIIi5vyO2Hq5c4n4ImCxVKgsJR5U68b3P6PChzExE4qFWTzywNB22wpeFpi@pWQiw94LaiLd8GNjSyntvKtRFF21DbT4yVxol03EbHWIfcSoXCj6aAAkVKtmNSoig3jMhUCdY4jSr0FrrilRhUWrxiRKWmdfEJAfIaQPaTJS8a/ZQ2dpHrxAZVXWT0cZAjotcCVNxEEA54osLGN@wsTTS0ZRSJRv3U6XhwlzhUCStlpgsyi2FtC2aZCdnTZjKQxW4gMtV2tw@KKsx6NRzJ@Jbl2qMBovNodIlJAR2DaSeOX1izZ1a2I2JQiULTEe93zTs9Kmq30xNv@tk153xvXeJL5CIS19BUxmA8cF6dZoe9NLTZsHOHZN95bbpElioboX8vNzyHIp3LU0x0SXpxQZFubmI/Dqiq6JNl/BO1OHZLHF7uWa57ePeh6QMmupbdp@AWeltpLibw8egzKyUrukIFI7q0HueaVsB8pnBr44ayxMagk7WM7605rw/PUMmOI9Q4AVF9/mDsLXMOZFQ49zFRIbWqE96TPwNB/wlLbtVS1yEt6QvLLvESZGw7z/KI9yZxOVRWhc7jUFktnnPiSzPymeUm5ycm5xb2knM1NvmmTwzl1i3WJdr0XqcIoYGlTRTkpJ0DRKLQOYPeriQlCpx@z/lqyuTuUsSjyjqbAhWlxS6GqauJedVZzEYbtdz8JSq1@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@svPbEL4@YYaBbOt9sjLgYGHNkBpXXxR6CWVhhrj2hYoVNLT26heCNnhQkFg@OM5kNODxdawkmiOeIC6lZAKDm0YE7NabFS4d//PTH0HIktgX3SRjjTtKxSWwUZkZV8EdStvwbZHHTzgGha/sNl3LYR4tEaX2dsaHDImWTrYtZE29YQXpoZIqtzj2ibrDVrpo0KR7V7ffHiwP6YofmTN1FKnwcVuXwaZnFsgzooefay3FH/HhE6R6tas1zIVU8wA6bb@HngGuJ1AoVrI4Ymd8ohTV8rcUuQJnJPCpG8qiFnaGHF44IyNxHxs/dGaBY7byrxoPeI75WpBYMMpxQ1tv7zX/83O4NZrt1oTv5E12OeXqCM3eQi3uceCF/5EhSJxPPWI/KXmoTWAZWxe8ok0kQAWSeJ4UefGtr9br8NvMa20kZCr7HYjz0iemB4E01rEagwAqDBrekCtWzOyAJl0AZsKRdzRR@uYOuzmBvHanscFKtzpdcIEDcAHt8ZlWW2ZHdDCyT1BhTHM6k1rRHQiIzMSWJ3s//4X//xv3hKf7eyxhKxC2C0y8rQGuBrWbVQ6cuXJKYn0YdIBzFdHmVuIqLP0aY5GWw6r4Qroapxc4yoXhlAb/ETjJSmxbG5XNAMQoIZs01cUGyNIRS5talfwwcXXyLg2DxifSxerR5xPj9RK/0ZhiqzRrH5EaJhlzubI4zFCOwNxagmp1ZZWRf3AYUIGMXnNVmRHQjcUhfM3BZkSotZIMEyfj5mjaZQOitEQBD5yJCrN5so1qxROOorE63o@YcdzeVssM6KadUjxpeINb1GgcY6P2@PCJ@khag8l6yQukhzd1uI9ZX8nK3TQ0ARrP8QDbVWdWWmZMSv81GIDlCHePh7xP4CVX6@Hig2rkfOi1pSaJZMjlC2YpEQ@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@EksDf/7xzWkY0hXrNODMCvjBINC5NsJoeBUTQN3wE4xiI2lDHXZ1UMhM9jiQ3A7X77D/OKWpYgpe@VQhy16/w843Qy4c141yC8DxVFGELNDQntteBJQtirIZ4J5X6pPrnVTO89sn2reBokwGcYmiGmVB/tlcgxXBxBsBSiOB9n6XjTbacjZ/hS13lgVJ@2HCURT86Qapy3tgxj3YkO9FzE/iqLCnVBJIlSYCcHhhbtTwS5IHyFLpLo0DXPB08WuM1tJSRSq3avWJ70WU@8UElprSx6svr7ow6luJdVt9Yt2n4P2tyMycIwm5AWttxk5yNAm5jUhaFWDOc8CzyHXI6Qigkjam0XFIU9GkS3UhKacmccH7PnE@h0gs8ylEWKFTfeJ7GSx4NLdTZrkgC8ftE9njDkykrHP2t4JC2ogZsHnm8l8Dy@kHoIq5iSBaffOC9x5r2Cwvc2khgoa3qNOc8kGMOAlAFg9Jv@c8yeQzy3ghRFnWwT6H4ArFjrssmLFdqlwbIZQrZvyCJzeb4rQsg0qiAn1idUznxFSZJm0Eq0@ELlABGxDftdzAINPu13ubgLVnnWEoyLQjRgdThPwnCXMsFJNa@mlZSCiIhU5wzl@qpImAIed5MgcDA4@9PSvVthHEIWPm13Mj@zkojNvO@8TlkjrjLNdK/E@oqGz7YYnIkUsAHww2wkGWJiIo00kVPs02xcOPsrQxS7Mjm0zM@SCqcr4eVAYunadPHC4o1ELCxg4VYM6zaVG9z6gQk0I4IKAWTkAcx5wSis7jxGTzE0dWFnDidUFCHoXQkg0FO5oJ@YHAjlASpvrE8NC0JP@R1jKeoHEO9T6xPPgMIT94hucQKkzi/iA58TObwvoADz8lcX/HTDy6xxkGzNyX9Db2Bsx1D9Hq4w0CftutBsT1plqLE1I2PFRIpLhPpI@S6rdCvQWM2BIrsRJjQIWLMfSJB05hmQo4X32KRICt8UraiOpRmDWGjZjSbj9l3Mc6aNPt@0N2zqmQlkfgs7kEsWauiaAB3SbaI9CzD1Ov4tUalZXboIgOgtFPllcsVizKzortD0drRNAECQd9UePaCKLQX2Fz2NsTd@5AYveorR3O47Am5VhqTPTjqFIqbYRQuNqHh6GuZKckSZKKec43WxnvCYsmU5L21@fgXkajUsjkxchyO3WJ@EVgIBp6YCJYUI14aqWFIBrdfMbhmTb9CxRu@SXGRx3IQqxkcnALu4nsqYSdCTDxo4y3igTacgtHo3VCF@bHJ5TPJQmP1NCF@2tkvtXk7nJJfSgq4wCcfkIfV/kNz1WUpY0QSvRHy4u2FA1DoICBlexsJILinhAhfWT3hLCK8No1lyYC6IAKeoo2vXS@apf0cW8jo20jYwY0awwN8vrsCe65mQrE1gO1zgKXJE4JabCrutRM@BmKk6tPfA8PaiTsn4rcwQ2Xpk5szwEi56FGRdR6qPtE9wpNQUK3GKO4Xo05dZIRhj8mSu1nnKy72ckvACdgLjsNLOyUnO4vuSeVcSuK193st22/df28PhjKbws4N7exkXDsvidOIudgzcRDVLusqj6xO/bzftSqZCcXyCCsZAtkWgcbjOEs@kKa2EXLgLbLpjC@zWpYj0ywBY@S@JWhw31QWgs4ZoCeVTY@ULFwxoekSPIsW4cXQOPO9/SJzG0eBNIFB95QJ21M/@/IgpLzklm4BUXaCOluZn6bbKoLzikBnWsjjI5ViaZN@2aFy/vuE6/LKVoJ1nTOTn9pYfeAU8h5a2wRoNjAEKXDB5w2Ibi2das8aO16mSdehxk6iaOy2JYtj0hd2wkfdy6uAdShIDDvMwzMN8mMIFzuEhX7xPF842s@fyX82jehte4MRWcDAYZIwbMcNKqQOT7osKWBXsBq7cOJWSGm@6DT@wxif65DOe/uoMO7HDvWEs5CI3kp/USe6@V6EQZBMncHTPKoc/kd5zx3cwv7R3SeK1xn8IIguTcDonZCYDa8IUJhpI04yVulTBp4ZiXDgjQuxWLQ4TNWwJrp7JsDsaZFdTkL2Gg6v/A9dEsmKmQ@DLq88DqfrAOxZo0if7yKxNuIP9hAq7mBkP4nCBhBnM2PsrQRRc4gnAgYhuC0IZCM6x5SPCfTDXqEiSxq5x@W9LgBkby5LuWAT5sXSSqQ3Efmoyvw1NI/5IYoOVcEZREQ6NFds5/jiH5tVm4CEtmbgr1cfYKQpgX1eM2ARYTMTmjUPn9BaQus@9/BCjcQvc3tLrFl1WZvu5tLvA/Tr8ESspurM6naO0fUT6W@@f7XaQzQ4xIZBhzoK8yUaDoyZb4kqhLbXnG0iUoMmxeoQEEw5FWuMzo4oJUcNwX6Jf7SAfFAsPSAmxWaw84Zp8uBUpoIm6zTAKYcfnW@hRKzM8UCHBAdnGFCsnWpCBQ1AUWbgzAgVghGWWprtg0YhRrdYii1qC4QUEfMCkCUJgL6G7bmO@aKu@jLbC0gjsy5uM7IBq6MnAwqYSmK3aWGGxAXBkO5jYMNiBj6hc0oEpKaouB1llSyyg6IGragkE8MCKT9ODTJbVbSVl@Kdx/k9nvxSK@TezEbJjP850j/XvyQE2c02CrPm40sR5SNu23MDWdqY7lGya3VRArhYS0MA1Jf3ASgYAFBPL8l8QF9or4c94uMO@s34NNva5Av/rJI@c5bNiA2uIGBOcJTFnSujTCy6eqMgjyw93AOKSlcEumAKCEQP/gyScBJj8CBxBcwIBr4uTepkTnK9kH8D5ajHB7YSqU8kVtZZjLH/TZB@Lwu2Jx1qzP1L9pnnKhgicRbqE0ZAz@RZLUBUcA2nXQTFqLfpb1In7P2VEyRB56NKEsbIexGWrLBT9A/JMojAoKGP/nQ5hL@Z51LABgQA5ySpyhzKcqYgdh@HnZ4pCbj9B8HItUa5f2cbNDEbbJBE7u/NVlzuMDOxb2SSQtPQFKwxLfofYTJtYXYlJw29FvEFjGzOXPrBLFC2Qr4PCWfWFBz5zEejNYnjcCmXdlsfRpp5Vw2A@KFicRL6bgE/iOPEVFCd6KhrMG4k@exmDWtgLjh@vQCHxhkQwtVRXsUckD08LMzeCFpYaSFm1O4jzXeTLUH23idbe8ERHG6baTJN88kCEVpI2LSZrBJfrCuizabDVOI@ZQpsRiMt7WJZii1d3nc/USxBYKKNaS3kS@1OclBh6Kg2MmfigXS5tiAaiPHZkDscJ3HsdrI4vi@EgivKknCKSN@IsYcqZwtRzwxL6xvMSnqc6CD1G2kYzAerx0imcTbUMxcuG1AbHFaWFqbE@c9AjlZX2TC1pXMEmjIfkw0Ec9@ILNYsnuiXopzYsDn5jSffmwjDtQWAA4uPYU6mXIkhxvY16fTDTCAzBFbag66xN1gYonOJYF0k8ywJDaun@w@zRsGWLrlVM6QgaqQ7JoBkUXhw5GJVOn4sBMQM5YMPvTtIFnC3Hvlcvkqdwp@4LGVrctA0/2D51jLMoURmjakMCDGOJXATpAYl/g3M@0zPJHAido8tY5yPpMHmchiyMGCuC74@6PMTUSwvYeeCwkjNKm4dQZED3GvUnxOWdeScx1oZ/8QRdw4dgomceMOnLqzB4PJsK2CQLU9eBHkBnazE7rIeUTcsg2a9aLNBLHFbK5JpF2vScQRK83HQiVUgKLYI8QMczrubaLMnTtvm3gevEOMVpih5QUIZCurz5BooQ00LdMLxccXrQtBWxjChXWHx4kdhnRWokWAuO5nz1Fac2JRiyHVGkWzGGYkzy0VxIWSw/BVoRyIHXVVMAspf5m9JzPOqCS9jQQ5Yjd1YvK6Yp@ruKlRkwtozPmQoXgrjHswitC4giqSBmprXhkyzqpGWQTETNaGLfxILIfgUSNtPGNP67DhRAibS9EVUOSu5Mqw23WuEZWtKL2oVJFUDcikiTCazyY1vIkKBBUbmP6fLiVUAS@l3X0myri@lEDoUmvM8OdL5ZIvCIrcpQsO@Wieu5SDoGIDQ1tfXeKey/EWNgNl5Rh2vXU/5h4o@uczGKOALX6yrpSC1vlcprq0sHRBh2NiGR2L2Tgr43SJ4Di/eQqLLz1UsDiWkoUIWr1S4pEe9iR7rlpxIQFxhJEmcX@UEpE0J3evY8KgIUE@PLFHdFhiPmD2n//6f7Zg7kvKYmGjSGeFyzodEnv0bZ2wrWrZsvBtEtrC/VEKIMJq/X0zloKKxAVThkQdF3ajWAYI7uzIkMumLPgskPSXnwB8eIqzlP3aFYNBje9uMbFFvQzUnEOMbWUc1K1L4wyJMKo6NPhhvpitEGaB/UJrLyjFxTckylgZWqnwpkELHzPuk4RySYmP6iJc93HxmQw2nIpj7q5eEnoVkw0gmXcNzm06cKJCdOhxMmEqTYRxGY8EExHFm9OenSCtlfSqYZ9XcaDQtKE4FGs2YLSEz2QEseFqapA57eKLaiG1MIgXlrTIlgsVSpkiULg2YrocTw1DqXjQJqWBrvUxDIkhJpjoT6a/cr4B0CjnHBgO@htFRXAfN7lmIwyUro24AUc0OR6yiSPlJnLIRCqxsMGF9Gh8wmPXJpxTGqvK8sfjpna9Y/6zKR1e5z75o2lpgnZXIdqYSzDBRSJBBiYg85CTRDmeCXZKJA89bRRR@9QTc6SoIjkYgzqRHdwXQWDddeGhT4fkUOfIy5BPCm6ckXMRjLiwQC6tK48ipNHGP18tRqXduOCATaBaTu/GtMSIxi03HDd0IKwyFNUVW0Qh1RAzlavdwpVX8CQalSSQWD4neLo2wsislpy7XDsXAmh8v/1obAtyziKGT6WqEGpaDE35AIzbiO2mtolFYDobneSqnVYtalo5FA08GKsUNEqanPPRUMFtxPSIL6VmI0sMk6pKV26GxptOzdO2WgQ2n5FPDGZGhLaw5VEAjIoKE7lxGLkMkDrieIcpsGKRjPtIOLvKOZUvAJLhkl5gNEVC4MiZomAegDnCJ05QIW7XITHHv0a4uO5wJEkglBFQ1L4vqQPVuo2oCfttfEUE04bWJSH60sbqOjj0K1tweig0avmkRBm5g01t6bfcRIQkK8WcYyzRG5MFQbu0j8VCyeB/zjZsgcFnIPmh0JEdkL82kZw5UrnBY8roQKX@@/9zh25Juz6BO5RyLIJMgU@mGLBKxP9FFxUJ0WNO@7Bc9MSVwkANNxFD545rhExrd3wW5Pbs7FCijbWc56ZYXC0UC5RB4qYSccmQD/GsSzXRER63pHmyyruVvTWeiEjCEi6jiWl7criZla31T6zyM5DniODcJPEGP@PqpV7jWEAcn2FhL5pz2aLcemyHXJjlh/qx@FH@IOOh3eBKvy34RAQztZjLo5iRWMdyh3zsEJ8jThdS7LaP8SFyEsIoKc8dE8KHbI6JAkxwyg0Jyz3Rwc86E7f31NqsfaYnfOQTNFvCCFPudv104lhMoXeYL43L0SFlO4bEL9f97KMyU0PU@A/@VScgnEM4idpK2fb7VSUWR8QZgpON6gSVuLZQNDKERDTB5MNbtJIzFHi8ly/GHSIheszHsAt2A1IiN5/BxriZpLQOiW6uUZWrEEKqqi0SMiTeCTSe3Ztx4nLbRkQ3g0SC/XHiYv0jjj4msk6sAaDYAJEN2BCzDpsMbgSbZ9JCBNV64CS9pE2mRI2O0eAW1ODPqI0MA0G7FIMRByR/RD/SH@zFixop3DTiWOQPLV2@nmm97iTfKnnfF63vsZIm9lN0hg9FwA9fJgJlkMg0GHExlxlmWiTslkvqoq2sgg@iWP0jYpVqSZkkZcyBURAX0kt5TLRnc7IJP7@gWa6v0KOIAy05fKGNVKCZWtpCnokRc0o67khU20pxHGkiYsAHHjhXK5DUKlS41KoRs8miscBv6AaIK1ASBLFDBASPNiJ18CPVbawulbSpEXFKFeABHclq3DwlSB2R7GgjPm1Y0elQlzRn2BJA7dSILTDiU4eGzznBCrE1rXkH09nUfdleZ40BUmoTSbwHDYoC6m4GCIoaj0sSZYKWcck1o16vLRG2se6jQlb9EUckBQG331XLq2XHHfXYf7Jg8p0Z8S@gxjgHw4hpJHxxOtxN@bScEeCaiBkx1ZxOxfuKLc64Y23irOIR0ckCdGTF4uemLY0UDkKxMSyHJikP7MHzi7aNoAmXlZRZmtSw4fC5tnnbxEJ44gsMjTtqvHK1a1nrqtmMiFyifxOWUX5uUEjdNODjhnUhGevutGFdtN@Mq8eQIShkFDY0Z5GMiF2uFtrQ2g@Dww8LaqSNIA74EmjWMOFZO3BRo9cToL95MA6IGVsuqNDOPhxx8U2bBIpiFgHYW@x9JZ0IiPO48KqiTSIRe4QUpv17lKujyQCtKrWBI2XcAol3zk1hQvbrOBiqVmtUly3gTFFltu@SR0gKNx5EO6tZLdljDoOKul1i@AAiuauAPlq2kLDpKhYS36SNLa7FLtVAh1wvnxQg/iV/AKX1EkasMm7quuCji9As3MJNnDLWSW6Yk4Wco4LuAkkUHA34cEBiQ07Shh3R5WiiVlfuXhGrhBVOc0mcdWlP1LWlPUdDyWsoq4y9lLYI6tzF9GaUhyHIzQPiOTyDIa82pBIBYb3PF3yvowizoWqxBLGrlRBP9fh0lumAT@Dwvg5y3F5ywE8wJ3XNzVKOC4JmqR1GTjHnYFRvAbXkYopTOpbGejmhNuLIZEHeWwpsNhJpgTknGxLRSoH4QLOUOGNJp1rP7EhKeurM4hjozaM9qG2P9oyIX7qECVjmM5eFgi23uIykRmrEPnGXMcGaskXRhppguUI6H6bDNkeBta3JO@KaNA4qxXpanGlLdo@Id1awivCRM5VKmbQE0@@VlP8acQorHrqRD8gJZqxgCVF8zkBLmrEcEdCLXIaCOObczA3VOskVFtl2D/TctREnRkwlB/esmDEuZXZENDNv@AiSBBBAdAGE0YjTehT7QP2//zv8J3VVWgELjHLtFVik5TGa0lMk33nMoy2FPGAXj7QstfgrkZSGGnH6akzREPhXDou4FgJ484wspxDL5iot7Oe9Ew9SfD7wA7r2vM@IKKZD4Sk2/F9Q0kTUaF2KCJaH7/iPVCOSJoLGbW2QnF2RKDmn5GjsuYK7sK40pctQB0XZ2lHjiWRzocETRlIDL5MmVmalCW1r2StdDJU0Log64so2mPa6WSqbFG2p7JHXk8MrfMqRW9pdgQNoNlW81H3H4@Ryfgt1ZemAA67QULArLohLqdFQuIIaI05mBZsm36gMTbKrGzMiIsl8wcacJQiSJAmOmEAqZFTE/TBb2YUMqS0wMkooa8vHYEIgPnzjmohxpzkU84RPQFKvsRPxUWm2F2G94xlYcAsRn8xAjN1qV3UMBHeZHtOkBTGDWg7wBNx0q8WkvwbN7ALvhNQTVa2AMC71kRhbfj5bTrr16fLRZLgJ9FVpErGISZm0JvFk9BcH713SPuhdzv5oMv7LE/pZVXDeDnWJgHCuiAcWu2rRWDxQKh2nqna1jCeT/xaJLdnnx3y2sYGNZ53SAOLcpTSMiXnO0L1OiUR4NEMKqy5IFBSHNrPYsJkIG6PcOB3iJikoPiVW@Hzy3hFg1DgKPO6wE4uSTRLDCZ4gSoLnuMMznzPfIivVd2HvEbIx7oza318bkSC7Ohtjop1SvJ3rYwOP1tPYSDet11hYgzz6wHY4T4tUteRpjYl3SmWDQs91JqZxtSFgHWaqgQ2/FfNhNK3j7@q7zx@b9Mp3H5woaGRrCrLmWOIPFm4pcIlqJyCU8rkD7QOEqx4mWGNJzsCAsi00PCYqis4cXKDJLgFDh2YB6LiJKC7txpaLBLRAdPGsMXFR179o5lxECjVzV09qTBR0ScGKIsMYFS1bS6xCJXkRY2KgzfoSlDdbrZjRgiqplCtgjXdh9auc9ibrtXFN7J58SvcAVmYk2SMLxDoa9zgbU4qNwE@5/0Q01@ygtdNJ4wz1MRFNV73WLhxjcy1E9DlMUEnocikBAmkigqINOjBhzQ4hOfHLKnfmd9wbtn4QOrwuNRakhQAu9FYUtHEHfHtQVoG7QUQwDXz5zHF7Z2uI0tkbY@KZOdNarbbc1wdNnkiO4Jhopl9QxLHEOkqZxHDwrJV7mIlkUi35rdBmmZJsXS0veeCu9o0P4z7XFQo4l1BLlXsTm1zLk88hTDzIqeWEbiz@@FTaCCIb0NZcdyDApZPZGKkyd/uIeDa2ppMBm0cem5ragiJfeJ0Czdc/4VjbAuXMqU9@MIwPZO7YKbYFNJaXxUR6bXei/K6c2Tnu81n/gAsaJOx0NrGSNiIm64rRYBMuJM6NmlbCMuudNewvUgblN5xefqfLqaHWZaAW2kYFJQhRnKuyUigc00etyxgd8@nJujL6OzM@OetKKleVY8yE1Pi8tsNf9pvEmFDpdf48nq5pM@jHAxfV/5U9Ifx8BXHhTJgxk9SGTnAVNt8MAJIWBAGOqFxFOWu@L8AYa7hcBSwKKMm6PhhvFhFMNTzr2hU4lDaivI3kUpXrpeSWShMRXOk85NvTSL0X3x2/GHNBVOoPkibUZajkHH8dujbCum0uEHDXsE0Gcm2E9D5XuVQftbwhBluZlDkaMzNVdCCEiluJj75tI4YPlBT6EyYhP06LofNmtiC/byLHJUl25yXHQ/YyGlNx@pY7wkL1zsX4xu6sPSA6Ho5/Pg3noweqcqfhpI1I72dkqFarpD03t1q1Yzdh5@R0@imzhDS1fFRiqeJgXbgSVgsl6SB64ZJ2xkRUfVgpuHzIQvNKjxonIIrTaGF9wGNvmWS3uUJ3Lto@ZoZa8rK3cSoEVdqV3xmPOOcinXJxWyNnS6ZSXGpM3HQdd6aMjZqfS9QVtcA41YJC7ZJORByrbAUEUfyfz5CZ0sr7n1Ahr38ayxnLxCjKRl2DUOcExE0kZN/8yuc7XLi@iVxQaUwsFZ0uPJiSBAYKW5YuCWxMZDWvY8m12grqoHZ5K3lTx3UK/wuUIxo5xwIlHwnEf9jK2knJ5y1NInXhEl6cUCFtxAw4ykoRbV1pd6Agc5mCY@KscBOohrlVHAWK8di13DSureOO/oX4ogZXiRe1rYTQ8TojGZaX2mUkh1okxHh80oEWGqmHjmLcOADvwfRYu4gZii5gNvY6m0wpolNXQpVSZ@t4vMqkbLhhMIAQ2HA1LcZEWt9d3nZqv9AWgIrUfpctwOO3KsRqA4HiBkLmdGol68fBYtS1KM4Rz@ndSzbmsmIob4HkMKM1Jq8TnegZr3uEQ1lw4zXOr5O6hYiAEG8NmbLLjhBTl4069vhlAGVKpG7K@ZEky4bNhzAdQKd@0dgW495PwrVXpeSBOzaNEVnnBRpPehuFE2R2oehm14TfXzVDTplSGoW8ugo0OnIXIQcj@u4p3UwoNsgLl341JpKKB7wxNqz5tC1bY6wr3d@jpCFTBLXh6lG/LusCrE/3srcxcdPNAm/t2V9Wat1@dI8O71Yqk5fqFNLEPvLutmWtpLIIKVxpEY8YaIa@6ZJfTlRyKZ9MB4VdSSkfr9OV9@fwjhPp9iyAbrMcvQ6v0gV@5C2xzLmWgKu5JgJiuUoirHAcCOLRBEWby@YRFc0UlRjPlNR4QNkJiBnyKVSJ0sPGqCqXSeRx@FNe5RdgucbEfpcSciLK216IlK50wWXomaeDqFwVXk@q7XA4W0mRncQlInnER6Wbj4QzwLXxtTRcX9XyyWQ5NMwnk617T5RHJLSaLeT7cKvt5OBbIWkOvtS7Itl3Fa88rq8aSBm@1j@MGr89U@d1@cQ2WM8VX0rezOe7cuNe91PpdjlAz7KSw@kehz0t15V1aVWlbbOqvC4XwzcyA/NCz3RWioeH9KaFekShMKXFRJrNgU@FKqjP@UU8rr2DL3lkiwlP9PCWGC@kie/54UHXmnZNDJWwn4BULortESXF22DaUoNgBsqxXOvaCJSyq3N5rRy9uVPqncxNKyKy/wm5rt9PulZE5IDzdPM1aUHJURaPz2NaqTNatfVBPaKltpADsmKEgezaCBnTshZIobHAlWPzuAIPllVmn0TiYjmkEyPOIx4KJlfZ5HwOeZpozpZGpXESvi2Jkmkl6Xf9G39wQmvkchU8YqELecMV/hTviyeFVcUJ7BBh7S/cG7A8OXTJ7zpoD/ajov2@RDup3FlmKXa0LuuPhc9cVX@PiGdD9YfKgCpiSI6dq7Tj8ZlLTl/h0rKcxlzVYkZ5fT7KnTTfMTFgo54S6gIrpo/X9z753KyrL1TE7ffiPVAlUsEQTDXGWNUK@LYpLkQuFR6xIcTXG3D0gb5OC0DZlYD0@CUaJFNgyV1BV7W7hlhxQDz5c8o72ljl3tLmEWmUvFFYhgEs1Z0w2uAkxHHyBBUhgRmPNYfbij@tgLjRhpvHpzzDOhSWVdi4bq83Zie39ONTrhd810iLYovd5JA/1TADtds5BpP/FraW8GVe5KV1q9jnbGDUrtOBPanM6hDf3FL8h/wensqUKkseB0ETWC85WV4KMfNLt4DJ5@Il9qRMq7uDG0BWWonTelyqFcwreZFXpeUukkYGiJjmpoezxZFSrT2dHjHOGXu84Id2OXzecPypo3LBaY9oJB/6LXUhx6lmFPzTmRsjHHrmRAWeif4eiicadCY04uT1iEPCbMFSxrRkpy5zBXTtHyQCia9Co3Oaqkjcq9FSJyEIR9r6pXt93kY1VdK2NVc9opByRAZuC3yH2BXWLNYSAvn9W/x6p3UJ7npdgtvjIKehENvnV8mB8tOr5PgFh/RupWLWcGAV36pUuLcqeSNOYeEw2maSL@rWOb4ev@iQq72WMNWkmjdoAlfL2yMqqRL4MKlUx1Ls6AcdjKs4YzxmkzP0ElApDLhJ7NtQrokg9itmQCPLGVMPJJV14V7sgUXdWgl/obc@huteAlpmznohNunON7pulNt3hHpjrp3N9nVp3y0WapPCIzZbiwgdsqMePpzPR1xNGdTu63GELpRcQm65nX7MGZ5FnVp@Zyu@QiPXsVR3KaSJSFrg658qggf1tF3kxrzA51yws1DvSmqkoUYkfLefEMrAbjgnSV4576THYVD3AiMHQsUmqLdxIcddSZ479upJNFQu5EB0oQ3QQNKP6Lj1xtFz1rmj5x7n1ToqTMXWJHlMWogZfcIkcm4cNHHijo173qd3JwUK2WI7DpETEEiD3rAhvlKB87d4nlThx7dicl@qViLgaxLJTsG3yvAey006KPDLH7/8mNriEDjOb7/9bsJvW@rbVqHLP75u/e2ftjbfDm/CH5W9r7BG4m9ff@QqPMzC3wZft7a31I93a7Lfvnzb@tJ29HvY81u59betKfzq19/U17avO3J9f8M/tfU/tr5cn3/Z@oetL0e7pxeHB1@@fv36j//1/wE)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 100%,  <s>2701 ... 2359</s>  2356 bytes

Takes input as `(id)([etymology0, etymology1, ...])`.

The source contains many unprintable characters.

```javascript
n=>g=(a,i=2,s="aZOEDQ]^4+24><e_<ZZ)aku[XdFyXdttoXdt|63a%}5ks/arbok_[__S♀E2a_S♂E_]]Sx_Sy`SytuffS[K~_SB]NO[h~[]?4PS@NB;2ZW)H~~pBR_]3!AA[r~?6G/@W@GA;5'dOOXel?3U~rXk~d,/!Z%~/@82arXix_S)ZD_~?3=I?3=CO;ak*@*@&tuV2)offHUXy`Xy`WseyWelaSs18/Ta*R[WyuWmie4~r/jyUS(~r[WosWkZXarados/lapras~eveeG_NXrT/omy/om(~~ps}5_XT3`[]*i&te[~P2Z[2efD/cyF(4]Q%NB4r>KW_/leledikXi([0Tu_$~f0,`Ye`Ye`/n/x`MXZ!ORR+22T3`oed[]]/ai!/2HV2^3~J_[_]W@+vXP]SarigWH2K3P+ce*&x/qwF`YzH2>Y(QW_M5]N+KW@]$NN`2K4XrT42OBR*@~um[M[y[2u~cZeWYSXgiho-ohWbiRWy,>E2^4C;3NBN^4%euFVM<17M]2|6XV4N3	SryD]Q/TtsJG+~8VA/U4,VE[ME]]2dEWH~]Q~[NOXVRRN<CQ5~leWn[Jse~lJQYvIQail`3aK]Z$NQ]B/3T3YnZ2e]2[/z=IO	],/corphH_[M3]Y2I?4ldo]2/4I/P4`)ec,XZ}7RMNSyut[KR]]2n/@eI]]{64/luv`XIQ{VC/P30TR__]_YiZYiZ)yogre_*zjir01Ss]K]_MO_KSy]XdZ2f|VCL6ZL6ZWx&oMONAA/buVZ]/H4Z{TnGXizC~zC?7{6{VW!Q[yO*iISkZ	M?2Uy_>N]Sjr.]]A/gZ@6$[E/=olu/luca=o~sE222kFuP2%_NA[N]MWa0b4[S&yXyV]SivZ]_]3__+Yo`XrT-zBB__/r0Im/uV$5/az`Ylgpalkia]3_QiphV~phyRYyminOni$[>WgMO/oshaw!*{TW=S<pDGQK###XnV2?5r222$~lYez,>[5aXggen3aXT2`	__2Wr/guFr`3rDAWhawkMWlI]%>DJeeS4|VZ2Y0UIK5)=ko=kL4C^3;niBM>~QEO|72ri18/tiFoPYF`WenWH3sXZ_YuaYoZYccV/ccV>QSt18DME2,]~Jite^3^3]aws`0UlH)FT3ZR/fooUYs{6/alo0U0P&k^5GGLLL4ZXVkC3kkC222lgyem/beheeyem[D<Z~wYxHXxo24MQQ2rk~fooXZ3iTQOQRJlHRK^IWH3]/doQ?4F23]ENSkZWzZASZ$4am~kVm~ormM}53aR}53BGRNK2ieD]Dby~sby^5AG<`RD[O];M3sQR+++OR]ENe<V&xNMK4XI^4kFVeMerQE>OBY082a?50aYv`[5X0TneRKYg`*LkiEMSa17	M/xZ3eas/Z3lt25/zy`Yncie~aA/VRKW(<Z~pC3}5Xk2k_^3/yC3^52?7Wj(Xk(]R8Yc0PGO321_{T4iO[[|5OO3H/fo`ONW23RR~ul/!01_/H5072RaWey]D]GYos`/py=17@Vu~: `_D?2FIQ~de`Wkyu]K/d`4T-o-oL4-o3o~ V4iSg{UYg(]G]<V/xkH3eeaXrUNXcT2zC$[[_a=ka[7nYaZ	Qy/U5`_OK{7{6kwZB{6GG_lerO&t{VWW=/dF`Q;2VXIRFolQnRGRDWk{P07[2%>SskVB3<aSanremZ&@1]3~m`SgC/pZ2V]3%5'd~ riI~rig17K|Vmie/fF,Ym_RisP2eJT2%~f,A~zZWozZ~vZWovZAXVZQ/zaciU/za0UzTJtus~/}W1|Y1{S1`10_}0^J1]}1[|0Z11Y~3X~2W~4V12U0!03S~5R}2Q}3P04O|1N{1M|2L)01K|3J~6I13H05G{0FU2E{2D}4C14B{3A^1@20?/`>{4=0V<~7;YP,15+[4*[3)/k(a`&~i%|4$X`#/P3`_!2Ti`J`_3U3~eYk{5_4/T4~ `Z;20006/wa/09/s^2}6_2	][16na/eanur~tWi")=>i<127?g(a,i+1,/[\r\n "'\--:\\a-z]/.test(c=Buffer([i]))?s:(l=s.split(c)).join(l.pop())):s.split`/`[n-1].replace(/\d.\d?/g,([i,p,l])=>a[i].substr('0x'+p,l||9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fX1Zk9tGlm5E73Z3dLvtXmx32y67vahslUiCa7UtyZK1WpZkVUm1NlWVBJJkCiASxlIsUHLFxLzP@533@zKP9zd0zB@ZP9L3bAmgZMdE2GKek1@BYCKXs@OZOlGZn5ok34htoP81vfyv@PKV2eUL6qK57F3MLn/wB3Xw8OaNR@Onvc@83pUv9NEXB68frKuw@OXhXnCr3Av@mucW/30x6KqP3vq@/4vw51lLpRMbHh0eHW3//H/@899ueooa/37zaDzePj3aLo@3y7yYTrcP750dbV8fP3h4@NP52eH4au/b7S8fXP/c@@MfD3bX75ydJde3jt4dd9@/du3wL@nZ1cHt1pe7X96@9nn/k@Dhwz0dXe0@OUv3wrPgYuv9g4/OWq99OfJUumfgO9YPbhydXe1evgv/f/XwcxV@@uWnX36cFzveup1O77z@ZK88hv92M13u6khtZ51R67H6dOtwtyx2F0b/qXeWtp6VT7YvnKWHuzbbDQ/2VKoCm7UilaQqO/uFPtH69tGDvfRxyy5@Xr4B/16Ae86@7x/tPe4eH44/Ne9@nOvDs7e/9Q4OPT290fLLWxd640cfPbjeS6/c2/3DUSvSf/19pAPz83fCPXPh8M/tx8XRh2fT37cvHu9r/K8V/6F1enx/7@D9h1tbn3ne7@DS9tc6OByPW8q83/Lu7HhPu2dfw3CPd7/87OS1vW/H2yo1s9073r3ut5/5@tOPT998s/Xd8tbx/uqOd2X/wqPd945@fb8/fvDZb@/tfjn@8MGDd/587N3rwS/peQ@vb3365VmxOLx/@Jfy0Ct@cuYf6N339t/bfm9vZn4/txt2vjsxW7vlxSs3vae9n3z1effB9Qe/fdr7SL9e3Nq5/0VneH/svRjs7fQedF/ZTssbb40ftR7n2de3Pzsb7VxrPeldfHvn5uH9m@N3xl5wc/fO2fjR2eGDh3s7W1sP3vziq0f9s0jvxodfZ/os@tXXj/ZP7j56XZnouPu6eu/e@O2DDx88Gl9vvdF93N2PD97y9Ng7bK0u3334yvjXF1u@TZP5naPDd@53x/uveXev9qLAjr3Wa727rW97x@vav7h38P1w6/5bD7ZfL39Z5If3tsZjL259qe@Ox88HvVZUnBzv3X30fOer1rfd9uOto6Px0b45gP/WSztL9dGnq98/M2m7s52N742P7r/78OjedvnmeC848KYvdr76ZnAA/@2efmzvP/zNg2u/vdaaFDt/Phi37vQOnj@Ob@@Z1Vdnq6@uDp8Pnu@8u/v@ozcPy4efmrvb4cEr9696T8qjKw/G28/SS@Pxtdbs4MvBh4c3W5dtVMCd@eqyPctuejAPwlvFt95HRw@uHT4Y399V7UnvcPu1j/9Q7pU7421zcjA@GnePjj7bt8fwXDdW168fHbXS9t1Fq9j5sN9Sq@P9aPb7REWhUQB89I75fTLfOUvm5dZ@uTDxw5/E5sPDK7uz@w9bNpur5fufPn@8e3n7jS@SG7cf3fvb3/62F@94V/sp3MuHZ9G@Xl28cthXe7OZjl/rqr3H3vErR@8c/cbb/VnamhW3fpa@fdz9WXrj2ru789@pZXh/N7o7/ujKja@13n6v92LnwNtvP7l7r/@b9cuhvRx@0/vqaffz2Pzq@v0rZ49uPnwx9FIDazQ3t@y3@7eOd3W8e6eb7R0c7Rdq3x7s@/5Oy/@rv3Pl0XbeGd24f9O7OD775dcm10@7T7tj@Mrs@BftJ9Gd9VuPuwdbram1T/b/@kb2fPCblops@0n724/Dp/3bt7/55pvewd7OX8KvuiH8Az/vF9Gs1IvWRM@1hsbhjS8Ozpb7p3f2Tq3Xu//orUdveek74Rlc8c29g655/Ojho62vozs/3br39C7c5LgV/ME@utq75XXHNx/AU95dHVzb/tnBhz21OAt3Fmc2/ePi/vf9rtqCf67/5vbWg3ue0TfGNyblWTYpn/av3f7ieOvG4cPx5/e72aOtzz777OEWXOov@oudj08f3IeVe/dpDybEzjv6vk4f3bzy8Pp@G7bCq/222j85PuzvtR/Heuve/uz4029Cc/P@tuoMf/PnX71yv3V60NUqax10o9zrt1bl8X7sG32mrrX@urP17r3dC/Bbk6@63/ff2gvf88Kjp91W@devuk/73tXh7rMLe@GF8dZo329/e/th1@scPX/8kzd65uHh4Yv@w4fdOzDKxw8f7Hrdra2zImq93@4cte7020NvS@3q8rfjG@Pb@zY7biXl5c7wy53i7O9rx0c3rnq37j46C/TxblgW43ut4Lj3@NcbFv77prdh/9S1Z2s7vT/9yWzPnj/Zn10Y3x5/sdM6/Vl4p6v1b9Ve@uTBnv/YW3314S8PD4/eVpdDdTiM99XBK4/@Urae9I@PHr577zmsvt@Fy4Przwe3bx/9NNLpw4/z5zu77725e7kV3Dp@9Lm3s3d369e33rbRo5/EW7d/u3VjN/zV82/bw0PvoyvbWbhz/d3uF2pbvfGX@Jc/TfXipwcf/@rLzrh7tjjenn3VSg68nXH3IziqztZSc/cMduTO8N6LHThbWtNbf7y4vzja@oXJvvX014@9j86mF6@drQ527erg7AQ@Tg6u7e28ffCotVK@eQL/tp@sHn@dF9lZ6w/f73Ze7Heeb3eOO@2j79tPv@6Mv@8cvmgfdDr7Z929M2/3rLfT8Z603293t8/6W997j77vftvuPXzRefC8c/@F9816u3PvRffrs8HdTvdOu3/7efvWE@/mc@/G972vOr3rz7vXnna@9NpXW8dXnvcut3e@OBt@vv/txU7/s8Pep4fd9VZ4QR1/fGY@etH7cO/4b7BNHh@97z1@zxy/@/XxO0fdvz7p/uVMv70fvvW8/@ZR78@tx70/na0d//Hgc@8P7fYb7cHrreXvVeu19ubvWtlvn3q/@X7w6yPvlfHhrzqDX8bqFy39cxX/rEh/epb/ZNd8sH75ivmi4w2vzlAw@axzsXX4j/Qf8doHn/xjY@Pv//iH2liNW5dyneUX/MvXQbDQ6YVDM15fv5r9/UJ0ObuUJZGBvvX1S8@siS9ElxKbXFhfX/@7dB23jg/jjc74UqqTSPn6QusfwaV/BFdbs4twoYvJxWgM96DgmpeyYpLl6YVP2qeffAb8Fy8219f/9fnhq4edi4cfTIpo8sHFDzYyVaQfjC8SrYR49dADhDkpmwAgq@4udJ/ouMiaAGI4RA8Q/lylAMhUpBYqDjShkFlRrx72axx8LHSkbVzBHPXq4aCGRWal0sBhHPHq4RAg2XeFSXMA5UWaRxpBzKL2q4cjwCzpKrlNc2syfQ4LXcgX8CaOUqSyvAnHkUKeEDCWbbw1les0MVGk@DcyKQAc7YXO1QJPe5sZHLTE0i9ANjcB59FTyeFPpxGO/DTV/H3MYwpwOPhLmy4AEmsdyK27FgBo7K1veSRDkIBjxT042hONPzpI4W7p6vCH0gYAjnNiZvIQEhPMdMk9wx/2WJCnuXP0Y53chaOYKhxD@HdDbeTwL/yPOGBAi2/Na1c4DaKrwSEUjGsDCIcySzRPq0SlqV3SM0YWNQGDwzj9AWTaQOAAZrEK6Qt0qOKM@TxukxTv6APSC5jfp18XKvyf5mnBvzJU3ATIgO7e1L1AVJ00M2HK4x3NU823DLQjADJqQGB6zSuIEADBgYxNYNMCx3JuYgufoLIglPgqZgqWZ/vHsBuqghqZEN1OE/hdoXXsMI4AkPfj3/zv57753xnb/dFvto1v5inT7TWBoYlnDiJtgNDeEOkprgVl0pKWFtDSBsSgiZjwSiDERNZCF8f@pIgSE@Osz8wp7VTIOGXAiO6DenMV6YxvI9aOAAiO/DMzm0UISmDPRgwxSqFgv8MhXzpQbosZPUPikALJKBzvVTFRuHJg7fE6IAb341DPbBTZpO4GuurH4bVBQKspMDxPgDYySXo4qrPIWtwcJvSJF5AG9OOQnhj@IVGxoAFD2hEAoS0A1MfM8AqkNncNm11wIsSZ9vMKw22Ajfh0oJuYxfwjkI7dr9hsABY2nzuAtOFUwNEMzAznTqRzugKQ0oR@HMegwP48NTS7gJImdHu05fLKx093WRy@RKeZUbxRVU3ow6FLstKfGx/3x8IPCZKV0gRIn59O0OhHsurHoVvYONS4fcMhF9KUxYbson0awdQs6AHAp6KBVAmPNHZwG6A4ijPYsyI68/I5QYghBGBwIFXqK5q@8IHzmPauqg1HJ45lAnPKLC0O2FLRUgOO4SZAOi9B5iaNKpAQAPNegsHmPK9gQgAMR1nBNuqrQLndlD@hs/fDzrBqQj@OMQgMoVopmryNNvTSCMO2a2mnhVVC4yst6B@e7@ctnhihjMboHEItqktwExB07usoogMktUXOx2QUVRQIG7TctU5ws@JeOYWBIxSgOrTcfJAeSpqqdPQ6MHYAB0gG4@jmOs6VT@sTzm@CMYsJQHVfQqWFbsCEAhztBNpu0FwNePJoK03op7mcqhP@a26JTDYc8DzXC5nhmkd/SLPXxiUJMHGZKyOzBNsMGdFBCBIATmvYleDb5TgjrjvNhjjIWQQr9GLzI8HH1GiOz7VBfmv/4M8mqZV/BcxNwJLcpWawleNqlN2MGEIAxmtichZfmBbBc4TjPVXpxlTn/lyT1AYkUZ@w4DbCoQ5sYGmoeTOy3IDOft1ZbVU2cDvVCIc604rGMdPy8EZD3t4sTa6AJQb4IAYBeHMwC9kUoMGPboTjupC9aVHwvrRJozaXKQ2fOYvixHKC@GaHzlKFe7ItM4TgWQpyrqChXUob0HRQKRRlZ3MQhyPa6WauBQAct7kqYvnrugl9PGBJoqPZP/9vPGPETMczJQAcNJhUdFjbWI7qTRyrADbADCfgioVjpFciGW/isM3LJCYhG78U29yFA@anakJLRk0mdL@hawEABy7k1Tw1QcBrgThuWXTaOI4nNsK5YtMJrWGguIn9OISwimBZ2wDnsT5NIstrr2YzFMdPz2YE0n7BkxOas5kQCOq@BLJphRICUSS2FvjLJpb3f6Bs7C7SpylOcjDu7ErmBorDKhQMjuzc0DqBeQ/nDQ8usICOnOLRHr4Eg00zrnFCIRBHOzLwTbSoZgVdDRkmL2QKd9qbJG6DoCTCX2inUyf7dUitWs61XknvsmpiL460ky7nNqW7SOelNBHhNRCBdYDAuv4ua5Sxr0WVBGFGVB1SoHKFT552VmjpSDQoUqFAZYCpavHSOGvnJlsLZSioKwuroejIAoc7I2UTPw0PLnLcVYeMIsVMzfh2gQ5SBxiJ6DE1tKlWojrynKDeIWWLL@MkaqAqgbpDSlaWw/bFVykt6SrIKQuBdM5DeIdBxsLps6RhLdJLtKsu9BoozbBJ0KRKL60tzMLhSM/ySxFduCWTlnStZyamFf6sjE@F3a9WkPFNjut8UqxW1QJSQiGURYHZQpGslcrOvVDuG1hhhedLmqBJWWeLuYWAET3lIi0yfspFajPp2uRrkyToq1RkhBlofGkiSjgO5axMeQMu2d0iXTiEkfXna7HO6NrshZFej0RbVp2rBnbQat84oR@L/hph40idqMTizxAFm0hnGumQnvSMtyUBIFX340hNI5XqGkBkBeBzPSpl4sHFpYmdOExqAeubhf4NOUgtiLWl26lIRWqAcL4ISJpolmjT0pkU/NOrFnZ16i7cMpIakMi4kWqkdEoSTQJHiQ2Un5d0cKomhVjW8C394kjRJEOSmwjoseCc0xMu6JD4AOexX8TulnBUVyqh7YOeIhDVM@6xqA@jHLNgRwhkpNpB6BDn1QwQE5d8XiloGoGMmhDFc5Rp5aYpKUsVJozNbJ7XMCfIdEhjWmjc4/OlZb1nyS3s7Ugv84Xp0RZofJZO4cEq3gpNCHp67kxGOJYTVdKpoEj1BQrOhKn09@jSM0WbYQp6R7Hgr5m5NqJIlzdk9sPdS4xPfhkHCilB4ahyJz63E7ofpLmJCBzUvEzmloaDDtjM8LRFdkUhlha4zenIt74NjOznNndtRNExVPWTxkrjRDxuo2GsTWalVOGtKVCBZkqOY2IiKQ@MlKkMpHEaVehNdc47MbC0WMVIlZoW6TkE0DWA5CdLVjT6lDZ2kenE@nmRxnQ7qCOi1QJY3EQQDnikgnJi2FgaaWjLKJIa9VKn04M7pENlsFPGOiWxGPY2fx6bgC1tJgZa5AZSpqruaqGo1NS74UDGN8tqiwaQzqLRIU0K1DGYdmL4hT17buU4Ig0qUig64vMu@KRHRuFOetKbXjbNOdtbh/QlMhGJaWgqYzDsOatO2WIrDR02bNwheuKsNh1SlnI7Q/teYngOzXQiq5jUJenFDUW6uYn9OKAqpzuL@RO5OHanOLzcc1r38OlD0wdEdC2nT8ottLbSXIzg9uielZIdXSGDER3ajxNNO2AyV3i0cUNZ0sagk7mM92qddwJrKGPDEXIcgagu3xhby5wBGRnOfEyqkFoVEZ/J54HAP4cls2qmi4C29KVlk3gGNLadZXnAZ5OYHHKrAmdxyK0WyznpS3OymSUm4RWTcAt7ybgamqRpE0O6Mot1SG16ViwQQgNLhyjQUTUHSIlC4wxau6IFqcCLjYSvpkziLkV6VFbEU1BFabMLYepq0ryKOGShjVpu/pIq1fwDaLBdhJlOBCSNqlTxgvpcAzt65BCw8LTXIvogedm1ENGnfRWkI5OyGZTlFmRJG1E41DpLaikBiEpIIOWqWKCdpupHsgaQZaVIw5I3XDyKgBS3D3Y4A3xn84fav6heldgK3Epu9UjxWpgM9gZ9YsnrFKSaVFX4OGHF3mTIOynEmE/KGIxzbJd8r9LALo8GbDKh/R6XOe@/yHIEwnDAZyaFZcVSHjYxWkW6eyxg6jVf1C4kfCu9OORTm6I8kLGTye3yFlspi4aIJLW2iMVfwT4moJHwxe9BmtcsMqRVguoxsyWfZTM8ecRlR1oXaOg02Zz2TLQo0B6pXFnMumIBur/lwQYOkuJjabNliJwRDRSyGqhO46ieiiX6u6WJps4W7ZEKlvkGNpD0QrbOOoBZid7qkQaWzQvWEmt/HXIi5@/BMQalwS/QGH9RzhFc33DoOgJxffphoOvg5FtqlbFZC1mZdrdM@7QOgpJOkkyx2SwIjBCIoVmOJO5bPBeRTKu5SJpYFpHtmdUPmq7FbOEusdlQTHTm49PKRYEgQtxUpIsteYvER4KXAbKYSD/ZZA3sv7Ril8bNMeAsnW3XI10MBDiSAzLr/I@gWlrRWD1Sw1K9sLRyU8UHOTNMIBgcZxQfElpcKAlHkWaPC7ArAqFk0II5dUKblQr@@V@RoXUksgT2SRvhrKbFuVpLSYjM5Ycgr/4ZJHPQwwNF0/IXZ2HVRsiI9vgiZkGDXc5EW@ezJrWthvDWzBDZnT1S22SvqTVtZDhV2@uKFQfOxxjFn6ScLeh@kJHI3bAWxzKog5JlL06c6u@RQufUqkosF@XKE0yP1W28H7iGWJ2A4dqIocm9YJfmRCsxSxBn5lYKKXl5ScbQ1IrFBWluIuJl642oWWy8ycWC7pG@ly0sCGQ4paix9j//9n/YGMx04UZz8wfqesjTC5ihm1yk97kFMVETcYrMxPLmkfK3MBHtAypm85SJpIkAkk4iw0ufGtr9bbdyvIY210Zcr6HIjx4peiB4k5pWIZBhBECDW9AFCjmcUQuUQeuxpJyeKLq5lKXP9MQ4rdZjp1iRKF0jgGwARvxkVBzbjM0NFZDYDSiOZ1Ro2iOgMTMyJ0m7m//3f/z3f/CU3rCyx5Ji58NoZ7mhPWCiZddC5kR@JGl64n2YaT@kyyPNTUR02dt0QgKbTnLRlZBVujlGql7mQ2/6EoyYpsKxuJzSDEIFM2SZOCXfGkPIc2sXkwJuXGyJgGPxiPmhWLU80vkmkVrp8zBkmRrF4keAgl3iZI4gFCHQ64tQTUatLLfO7wMMIdCLz3uyIjkQdEudsua2JFFaxAJxlvH6mJeaXOnMEAJBZCNDXb1sophTo3DUV2a2ovUPJ5qL2WCeFdHKI40vEmm6RgHHOjuvRwqfhIWoJJGokCJdJO6xkNaX8Tqrw0OA4ddfREOtVZGbKQnxdTwKqQPUIRZ@j7Q/X2XnrweMxvXIeFFICM0pK0dIW5FISPuLbE6LIjJRuZawgA88JfsH64CCAWUEZE729kTUFpBHSydgk52NrF/G7JwkJjAER1KH1gHdkSjmOhDd2iOtMC5WKxINncEDGNJECO0YczPNK58eiS3AcGcVa4ToHaPJE0XsiUZO5IJQSCvMluKUqUHEqkAUsMTH1awQHyOQlRhGumICJ66vYlIdqsmPzMRpAB6pjCrLWVCAb8tXvFVGuYhQpDKGJo3EN85N6WNvT0ri54llOxXRQiCGBrZIp8ongSU0uXMzgQAFlMDIXKSy7woM8@EJbcTtxkwjc2fE45xyMMOGiJjMqGRMUg9JDYkiMgQX8hc4XYFZHfykImaRImkTtAueG8AIXcyBR3riiZmRpbWCEKPGbDYuUysrtY3d2@TYm/gZ2SMMurklpESaiOk0MAtcQYx4xk1EeOyyw2nKQPbXBdJGCMWBzU2WkCAGCtaChSLkLZxMRMphZItAdCZZXAW0ZXmRcug8VdzHXqZEmohhKS6E0RUrIRJzZyT02PMGUnKpWCButLF7xGaB9CVzQGUM8EgjjFnWhe0/UXzWI0faGNXUZkU@F0kDP8cXHYchHZFOfY6sgA8GAc@1EUbDq1gB1CWvYCRLCRtqs6mDXGZyxgHlTrhum@3HC5oqJuWdT6Wy7XXbbHwzZMJx3UhXABxPNZuhFmjozK0uAswKRdEM8Mxzdc70Tixn@e2S2tdAUSSDmESRjbQgfyiuwY5gwoaD0oijvdthoY2OnOafsOTOtCDpPIzYi4KfbpA6fAbG3IMN@V2k@YkfFc6UXByp0kQADi/MjQL@SOIAmcrcpXGAU54ukwK9tbRVEcvtWl3S92YU@8UKLDWlj3df3nVh1Nci6476yLq74PMtjc0JexISA9LanI3kKBJyG5G0K8CcZ4dnmuiAwxGAJW0Mo2OXpqJJt9CphJyayDnvu6TzOURkWZ9ChBV1qkv6XgwbHs3tBWu5QIuO2yVljzswkLJI2N4KDGkjpsfimYt/9S2HHwAr5CaCaPdNUj57rGGxPEukhQga3rRYJBQPYsRIALRYSLqesySTzSzmjRBp2Qe77IJLFRvuYn/OcqlybYRQrJiZpDy5WRSnbRlY4hXoklbH6pyIKtOo8mB1SaHzlc8CxIaWB@jH2v251wTUlnWGISHTjjQ6mCJkP4lYx0IyKqSftoWInFhoBOf4pVyaCOhznCfrYCDgsbVnpao2gthlzPr1iZHzHBjGHedd0uWiIuYo11zsT8jIbXWzpMiRSQAXBgvhQEsTERTppNIJzTbFw4@0tDFKsy2HTMjxICp3th5k@i6cp0s6nJ@qpbiNHYoynEyF8s6jAgwKYYeAWjoCcexzisg7jxOTxU8cWdnASa/zI7IoBJZkKDjRTMALAjsCCZjqkoaHoiXZj7SW8QSOM6h3ScuDewh44RmeQ8gwkftCMuLHdgH7Ayx@CuLewEg8esYxOszcjxw1zgaMdQ9Q6uMDAv7a7Qak6021FiOkHHjIEE9xl5Q@CqpfC/QaaMSWtBIrPgZkOB9Dl/TAKWxTPserT1ERYGk8lzaiPHKzhnAQU9jtuYj7UPtVuH23z8Y5FdD2CPpsIk6suWsiqEePic4ItOzD1Mt5t0Zm7g4oUgdB6CfJKxQpFmknxXb7gxrhl37ETl/kuDaCyPWX2gTO9sjlHYjvHrmFw43YrUkxlhoD/dirtJA2QshdPYHFUORyUhIlQcU858u1mM@EZRkrCfvrsnMvplFJZfKiZ7mauqT4zUBANLRgZrChGrHUSgtBNLrJnN0zVfgXMNz2SxofdaAWYiWSg1vYTcqeitiYABN/FvNREUFbHuFgUAd0YXx8RPFcEvBIDZ26byPxrSBzlwvqQ1IZB@DwE7pdNSl5riItbYRQoD9KXnSkaBgCBRpYxsZGUlDcChGlj@SeAHYR3rtOpIkASlBBS1HTSjdR1ZY@9BoRbY2IGeDUGBrkOvcEz9xY@SLrAVvHvgsSp4A0OFVdaCZ8BmLk6pK@h4kaEdunZi5xw4Wpk7bnADNnoUbGrLJQd0ndSzU5Cd1mjGS9G3PoJCMM3yZS1T1u1t1s5BeAIzCWnQYWTkoO95fYk9y4HWXUafbbqt@6ft4fDMW3@RybS2mk0i1GImdgjcVCVLioqi5pd2zn/a5QGRu5gAZiJUcgq3VwwBiOok@liV20DWh7WqZmYuMC9iPjr8FSErsydLgbpb2AfQZoWWXhAxlLJ3xIiCTPstq9AByX39MlZa6ZCKRTdrwhT9oY/t@WDSXhLTN1G4q0EdJpRn6beKpTjikBnmsjjNKqhFOFfTPDxX13Sa9LyFsJ0nTCRn9pYXePQ8j5aKwQwGhgSKXDBU6HEFzbul0euLbe5kmvwwidyKmy2JYjj5S6qhNu90RMA8hDQmCj8zAQ3yQygnCJC1Tsko43MRPN@VeiX09MYK3LoWg3ECCIpDzLgaNSmeO9NksaaAXMaxtOyAwR3Xtt7zyI7bkO5ay7vTafcmxYizgKjehT6SfluTitN2EgJHK3x0oedZ5u4Jznbm5h/4DyuYI6ghcIib3pkWonCkzDGiIqjLQRJ3GrFEkDa1YiLIjjQix6bc6xAq2Zct8ciDkVqsNRwEZT/sJG4LZMZMh86HV443U2WQdiTo0ie7yaibURP1hAK7iBkO45CAhBHM2PtLQRRcYgnAjohuCwIaCM6@6TPyfWJVqESVnUzj4s4XE9UvJOdCYJPlVcJLGAcrfMqSuwaukfMkNkHCuCtBAIHNFTs@f9iJPCrNwEJGVvCvJyfg5CnArk8Z4BmwiJndAoJvwDpS2wzv8GS91AeM3jLrJZXkVvu4dLeh@GX4MkZJu7M7GqJ0eqn1pMzMaPhzFAjwtk6LGjLzVTUtNRU@ZLIiuy1RUHTVRkWLxABhKCIatyEVPigFaSbgrql9hLe6QHgqQHulmq2e0cc7gcMKWJsM06DGDK7ldnW8gwOlMkwB6pg3MMSLYuFIG8JsCoYhB6pBWCULawBcsGjEKOrjAUWlSkCChmrBUAKU0EdBuy5jOMFXfel3lNII7EubCISQbOjWQGZbAVhe5S/QbEucGQrvxgPVIMJ6mNyROyMGnK@yyxZJftkWpYgQLOGBBIdTs0yW2c0VGfiXUf6Op38UjXwb0YDRMb/jriP0svScYZDbZKkrIR5Yi0cY@NdcO5amzXSLm9mpRCWKypYcBiImYCYDCBIJ7fEviANtGJpPvNjMv163H2Ww2aiL1spibOWtYjbbCBgTnCUxZ4ro0wkumKmJw8cPZwDCkxXBBpj1RCUPzgx0Q@Bz2CDiS2gB6pged7sSSGS/zokf4H21ECCzZXC57IFS0zmf1@TRCu1yWLs253pv5ltcZJFcxQ8RbVJgtBP5FgtR6pgFU4aRMWoN2lukiXo/ZUSJ4Hno1ISxshbEY6ZYGfoGPx8giBoP5LNrQTcf8zzwUA9EgDnJKlKHYhyhiBWN0PGzwWJubwHwciVo0avRxsUIZVsEEZuu/arHU4356IeSWWFmZAkrNkYtH6CJNrDbELMtrQX5G2iJHNsdsnSCuUo4DzKTljQZ04i3FvUGcagUy7snGdjbRyJpse6YWR@EspXQL/kWVEKqHLaMgKEO5kPabzsiIQ16@zFzhhkAUtZKVVKmSP1MPzxuClhIURFx5O6m5r2Ay1B9m4jrZ3BKI43HamyTbPShCS0kbEZhXBJvHBukiraDYMIeYsU9Ji0N9WBZohVT3lYeecii0QZNQQrxEv1ZzkwENSUGzkX4gEUsXYAKsRY9Mj7bCO41g1ojg2VgLhXSWKOGRkEokwRywny5GemKR2YjEo6ryjg9iVp6M3HNYGkVj8bUjGzt3WI21xmlramyNnPQI6qi@yydKVzBJoyHlMaiLmfqBmccrmieJUjBM9zpvTnP1YeRyoLQAcXFqFOpqyJ4cb2Nel7AYYQNYRK9UceJF7wKQlOpMEqpskhmFxH@knuU/zgQGSbjaVHDJgpRJd0yNlUfThmZmpzOnDjkDMUCL40LaDyhLG3isXy5e7LPjeiKVsnfmanh@sYy3bFHpoKpdCjzTGqTh2/Mi4wL@5qdbwpjhOVDNrHelkLguZlMWAnQVhkfLvR5qbiGB5Dy0X4kbAKkfS1@XUhbniPGVdSMy1r538QypiI@0UROLSJZy63IPeZr@qgkC1PXgT5AZ2sxE6TXhE3LYNnHrTZgWxwjT3JOLWexLpiLnmtFBxFSAp8ghphgmle5tZ7PLOqybmg7dJoxXN0PIGBLSV3adPaqH1NW3TS8Xpi9a5oKkolHXJ46QdBpQrUSGArPvZcrQoOLCowhCrRtEshhnJc0v5YaokGT5PlQOxoS735wHFL7P1ZM4RlcS3M0EO2EwdmaTI2eYqZmrkJAIacjxkINYK4xZGGhhXUEXCQG3BO0PMUdVIC4GYzVqwhY/IsgseOdLGHHvahw0HQthEiq4AI3ElV/qdjjONqHhF4UWZmknVgFiaCKP5bBaGD1GBIKOB6f7gUqIq4KW0e86kMtaXEghdqsb0X75UIvGCwEhcuGCfU/PcpRwEGQ0MHX1Fhmcu@1tYDJSdo98Z1f0Ye6Don/Ng9AJW@M26UgpK5ycy1aWFpQva7BOLKS2mkSvjeJHgOL55CpsvLSrYHDOJQgSuXimxSPc9iZ7LV1xIQAxhxIncl1Igkubg7tonDBwi5OZJe0SDJcYDxv/zb/@5BnNfQhZTi8XUUhd12iftcWKLiGVVy5LFxEaBTd2XkgMRduuNpi8FGZFzpvRJdVzaRrEMIFzuSJ/Lpiw5F0j6s3MATp7iKOVJ4YrBIGfiHjFpi/rUVyfsYqwq4yCvLo3TJ4VRFYHBm/nErAUwC@wntPcCU0x8fVIZc0M7FT40aOEy4z4JKJeQ@FmRBnUfF5@J4cDJ2efu6iWhVTFqAEm8K3FuU8KJCtCgx8GEC2kijMt4RBiIKNacKneCuFbCq/pd3sVBhaYDxaGY04DRFj6XEcSGq6lB4rTzL6ql1MIgvTCjTTZbqkDKFAHDtRHTYX9qEEjFgyooDXiVjaFPGmKEgf4k@itnGwCOcsaBfq/bKCqC57hJNAthwHRtxPXYo8n@kCaOmE1knxWpyMIBF9DSOIfHriacQxrz3PLtcVO73iF/7YKS17lPvnSRGb86VUhtTMSZ4DyRQIMmIPOQg0TZnwlyykwWPR0Us2rVk@ZIXkUyMPpFJCf4RAiBderCQ@eS5JDnlJc@Zwo2cuScByNMLSiX1pVHEaXRhi9fLUSmbVywxyJQIdm7IW0xwnHbDfsNHQirDM2KnCWigGqImdzVbuHKK5iJRiUJxJfPAZ6ujTASqyXmLtHOhACcyaS6NZYFOWYR3adSVQg5FYamvA/C7YzlpqqJRWDajU4y1U7zCjXNHYoGHoRVchpFZcLxaMjgNmI80pcWphElhkFVmSs3Q@NNWfN0rKa@TeZkE4OZMUNZ2PIoAEbNUjNz4zBwESDFjP0dJsWKRTLuA9HZVcKhfD4oGS7oBUZTKAQOnCgK4gGII5xxggwxu/ZJc/xxhPPr9gcSBEIRAWkxmUjoQF63EbXJdpuJIgXTBtYFIU6kjdV1cOhXNuXwUGgUcqekMnIHi9rSb7mJCAlWCjnGWLw3Jvb9amsfioQSw/8cbVgB/fNAskOhIdsne20kMXPEcoPHKqMDZfqf/88l3RK3zsDtSzkWQS5An1ygwyoS@xddVChEDznsw3LRE1cKAzncRAzlHRcImRYufRboKne2L97GQvK5yRdXiIoFTD9yU4l0yYCTeOpSTZTC47a0kezybmevhCdSJGELl9HEsD1JbmZmJf2TVnkeyHNEcG6SjHov44pTXeOYQBznsLAVzZlska4stn0uzHJJXVpeyi6R8FAdcNmkKvhECubCYiyPYo3EOi23z2mHuI44XEix2T7EReQohFFQnksTwkV2goECrOBkDQrLPVHiZxGL2XtqbVyt6U1O@QTOmmiEC@52/ZRxLKLQM5gvpYvRIWY1hqRf1v1sozJTQ6rxmP/UEQhnF06k1hYs@32gIosj4gTBzUZ1glxMW0gaGUJSNEHkw0e0khwKTO/li3GHUIgechp2ymZACuTmHGz0m0lIa5/UzRqVuwohxMqrIiF90jtBjWfzZhi52LYBqZt@JM7@MHK@/gF7HyPZJ2oAMBogkgFL0qyDMoYHweKZtBBBtR44SC@qgimRo0MUuAXV@yGqEWEgaBdiMGCH5KXZpcUltuJhJWDpIs/BJS1drjqwdJJtlazvy8r2mEsT@8k7w0kR8DGRiUARJDINBlzMZY6RFhGb5aIirSqr4EIUqX9AWqU6pUiSLGTHKJBL6aU4JjqzOdiE1y9wTusreORxoC2HL9QIBZqrU5vKmhiwTknpjqRqWymOI01E9DjhgWO1fAmtQoYLrRqwNpmWFvQbegBiCpQAQewQAsGDhqcOPha68tUtJGxqQDql8jFBR6Iam1mC1DGTE23A2YY5ZYe6oDnDkgByp0ZkgQFnHRrOc4IdYm1a8Amm46n7sV67xoBSaiMJvAcOkgLqNB0EaYHpkqQyQcu44JqB51Ulwhr7PjJk1x@wR1IQ8PhdtbxCTtyBx/aTJSvfsRH7AnKMMzAMWI2EH07J3RRPyxEBromYAaua06lYX7HFEXfMjZxUPCB1MgUeSbF433SkEcNByDeG5dAk5IEteJO0aiNok8tKyiyNCjhwOK/tpGpiITyxBQbGpRqvXO1a5rpqNgNSLtG@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@7KBRsuc1lIDVSZ2wTdxETzMkqFB2oEZYrpPwwHVQxCsytRN4B16RxUCnWU@FMVbJ7QHpnDrsIp5yphZRJizD8Xkn5rwGHsGLSjdwgB5gxgylEcZ6BljBjSRHQy0SGgnTME3NiqNZJorDItlvQJ66NOBFickncsyLGuJDZAamZSckpSOJAANI5EAYDDutRbAOd/PO/4D@pq1IRWGCUa6/AJi3LaEqrSH7zkEdbCnnAKT7TstXin8ykNNSAw1dD8obAv5Is4loI4MNzZjmEWA5XaWE/n52YSHE@4Qd4Vb7PgFRMh8IsNvxfUNJE1KAuRQTbwwb@I9WIpImgYVUbJGFTJFLOKDkYjlzBXdhXysxFqAMjq@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@0HY7TIlYhcVpD0julskGqT3QsonHeILAOM9XAhr8KORlN63BDbUz4tomvJu7GSQWd2YKcrAmW@IONWwpcItsRCKV4bl9PAMJVDyOssSQ5MMCsCg0PSRVFYw5u0CSXgKBDswB43EQUl3ZjyUUcWkA6f9aQdFHXvyxPuIgUck5cPakhqaCn5KxIY/RR0bZ1ilWoJC5iSBpoWV@C4mbzFWu0wIpy5QpY41NYfSDZ3iS9lq6J3Zvnwj1AKzMS7IFv5pGy1hyNKcVG4FOePymatXZQyenEcYL6kBRNV73WLp3G5lqI6LKbIBfX5ak4CKSJCPI2aN8EBRuEJOOXWS7nd@j1KzsIJa9LjQVpIYALvaUpHdw@Px6kle8eECmYBn587HR7J2sI08kbQ9IzE1ZrtVpzPx84SSQxgkNSMycpeRwzrKMUiw8Hc63cYiYlk2rJrwU2jpVE62p5yQN3VW98GHa5rpDPsYRaqtyb0CRaVj67MDGRU0uGbij2@IW0EUQyoC247oCPWydrY8SK3eMjxbO0BWUGNFMey4LagiJbeLEANV@/hGNuBZSc0wnZwdA/ELu0U2wLaCgvi5npWu5E@plyYuewy7n@Phc0iNjobEIlbURs1hWjQSZcip8bORWFZdbbNexHQgblLxxf/qbDoaHWRaCm2s5SChAiP1dupVA4ho9aFzE65OzJIjd6gzU@yXUllqvKMWSF1Ex4b4dvnpSRMYHSdfw8ZtdUEfTDnvPqf8CWEF5ffpg6EWbISmpJGVypTZoOQOICIcABlavI5uXGEoSxkstVwKaAlOzrvWGziOBCw1rXrsChtBE1agSXqkSfSmypNBHBlc4Dfjyl1HuZuPSLIRdEpX4/KgOdBUry@IvAtRHWqWKBQHcNqmAg10aId77KpfqukDfEYCuWMkdD1kwVJYRQcSux0VdtxHBCSarPYSKy41QYyjezKdl9I0mXJNrlSw77bGU0JufwLZfCQvXORfjG7rhKEB32hy9nw03QApW7bDhpI3L0MjJQq1VU5c2tVtXYbbJxcjo9F1lCnEJulbRUMbAuXQmrpZJwEL10QTtDUlQnsFNw@ZCl5p0eOY5AFIfRwv6AaW@xRLe5QnfO2z5kDTXjba@RFYIs7crvDAccc7GYcnFbI7klUykuNSTdtPY7U8RGwesSeWkhMA61IFe7hBORjpVVBILI/885ZCaz8v4nZMjrn4aSYxkZRdGoNQh5jkDcprjsyw84v8O568uZcyoNSUtFowsPpgSBAcNmmQsCG5KymhShxFqt@YVfuLiVpCzCYgH/C5Q9Ggn7AiUeCci/r8XVpOR8SxNJXbiINydkSBsxPfaykkdb59olFMQuUnBIOis8BKphbhV7gUJMu5aHxrV1XOpfgC9qcJV4kVtRCB3WEcmwvRQuIjnQQiFmxJkOtNFIPXQkw9IB@AymZe08Zkg6h9lw1G5qSjPKuhJVaeFknRHvMgsW3NAZQAhsuJoWQ1Jan7m47YX9hI4AZCzshhwBI36rQqgaCCQbCJnTCytRPw4WIq9CcYx4Qu9esiGXFUN6DSiHGdSYpIh0pOe87xEOacENa9ykiIoKIgRCRjVkyiY7QkxdNOpwxC8DyBak1E05PpJoObA5CdMB9GKSlrbCuPeTcO1VKXng0qbRI@usQMNNr1E4QWYXkm52bfL7q@aoUy4ojEJeXQUcPXMXIQMj2u4p3ExUbKCXLvxqSEoqJnijb1hzti1LY8zL3PdR0JBJ/cJw9agPTosUpE/3srch6abNAm9V7i8zta5ufUTJu7mK5aU6qTSxj6y7VVkrqSxCDFdaZEQaaIy26YxfTpRxKZ9Y@6ldSSmfUbsj78/hE2emq1wAXUU5jtq8S6d4y2simXMtAVdzTQjEcpVE2OHYEcSjCYwqlm1EqmisqMR4rKTGA9KOQEyfs1DFSw8Ho8pdJNGI3Z/yKj8fyzVGdkNKyAkpb3shpXSlUy5Dz3o6kMpV4R1JtR12ZyspshO5QKQR6aPSzSnhDHBtfC0N11e1nJksScOcmWzde6JGpITm86X8Hm5Vnex8SyXMYSL1roieuIpXI66v6ksZvso@jJxJlVM36nDGNkjPOV9K3sw3ceXGR51zpdslgZ5pJcnpI3Z7Wq4r68KqMltFVY06XAzfyAxMUj3XcSYWHuKbCjoiFQpDWsxMszhwrlAF9Tm7yIhr7@BLHlliwowePhLDpTTxPT886FrTqYmuErYTEMt5sUekkuJjMFWpQRADJS3XujYCpezqibxWDr9eUlOBV5GI7J5D1vX7iVeRiOxxnG5SKy1IOZVlxPmYVuqM5lV90BGppTaVBFkRwoB2bYQMaVvzpdCY78qxjbgCD5ZVZptE5Hw5xBMhbkR6KIhcWZlwHvI00hwtjUzjKHxbEgXTStBv/RdjDmiduViFEWmhS3nDFX6K9WUkhVXFCOwQQTFZujdgjSTpkt91UCX2I6P6vaR2Urmz2JLvqC7rj4XPXFX/ESmeJdUfynyqiCExdq7SzohzLjl8hUvLchhzXogYNepyKndUbmBgQKOeEvJ8K6LPqDs6Z3Ozrr5QGla/i89AFUkFQxDVGGNVReDbprgQuVR4xIYovqMeex/o51QApF0JyBG/RINociy5K@i8cNcQKQ4UT75PeUcbs9xb2kakNErcKGzDAJbqTuhtcBTiOHiCipDAjMeaw1XFn4pA3KBh5plQnGERiJaV2rCorjdkI7f04yrXS35qxEWywjZ1yJdqmAHbnRy9zf8VVlP4Mi@y0rpd7Hw0MHLrcOCRVGZ1iItuKx7L32FWplRZGrETNIL9koPlpRAzv3QLNPlErMQjKdPqnmADyEwrftoRl2oF8Upe5JVreYrEkQEiTbNp4axwxFS1pXNEGuecLV7woV0M36g/PNeRO@f0iNRITvrNdCrpVHNy/unYjREOPetEKeZEbwRiiQaeCYwYeUekQ8JswVLGtGUvXOQK8KovJAUSX4VGeZoqjdyr0RaOQhCOtJ1k7vV5jWqqxK1qro5IhZQUGXgs8BtCV1gzrSkE8vu3@PVOdQnuoi7BPWInpyEX2/lXyQHz3Kvk@AWH9G6ldF6yYxXfqpS6tyqNBhzCwm60ZpAv8uoY3xG/6JCrvWYw1aSaN3B8V8t7RKqkiuBmFlIdS7GhH3gwrmKMGbE2OUcrAZXCgIfEtg3lmghiu2IMamQ2Z9UDlcoidS/2wKJuFYV/4NVpuO4loFnspBfSJl1@o@tGunpH6GjItbNZvs7sM4uF2qTwiI1rEqF9NtTDzU04xdVkfuF@HnvoAokl5JY76Ycc4ZkWC8vvbMVXaCQ6lOouqTQRSRt88VJFcL@YVpvckDf4hAt2puqZkhppyBEK3@0nCqVvG8ZJolfOOjliN6h7gZEDIaMJ8hoXcror0SdOex2JN1Qu5EB0oQaoJ@FHlG7dSD1nnks9H3FcrVOFqdiaBI9JCzGDc5hI8saBE0YubXw0OvfuJF@htliNw8wRCKRBL1kQx/fPO0F8JFX48a2Y3LdQKyHwNYkkp@BbZfiM5SYlCrw6fvXS1KY3Qce5cOHQBBfX1MW1VGfj9bXLV/BdD7Cu9aXIzi6Y4FJut3OskXhh/VKigptxcKG3vvbZmuKXt39yce2TqqPrYc@FbO3y2hT@dP2CWq/6OgPXdxm/au3q2icP732y9ve1T25du/vNzRufrK@vf/6v/w8)

#### How?

Each name is encoded as a sequence of sub-strings from the etymology words, with some possible hard-coded characters in between.

Example:

For the first name, we are given:

```
n = 1, a = ['bulb', '-saur']
```

The name `bulbasaur` is first encoded as `004a114`, which is interpreted as:

```
'004' -> a[0].substr(0, 4) -> 'bulb'
'a'   -> hard-coded character 'a'
'114' -> a[1].substr(1, 4) -> 'saur'
```

But the length of the sub-string is omitted whenever this is possible without resulting in any ambiguity. When the length is omitted, the decoder assumes that the word must be read to its end.

Both lengths can be omitted in this case, so the final encoding is:

```
00a11
```

All the 890 encoding sequences are concatenated together, using `/` as a separator. This results in a string with a lot of repeated patterns which can be efficiently [crushed](https://siorki.github.io/regPack.html):

```
00a11/00211/00412/00314/00313/00311/00514/00210324/00414/006e/00310/.../za001z03/005tus
```

Comment: Since the etymology often follows the order of appearance in the name, I wonder if the etymology index can be omitted, e.g `bulbasaur` is `0a1`?

Comment: @SurculoseSputum This is an interesting idea, but I was not able to successfully implement it so far.

Comment: You can save a byte with `++l||9`.

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, I actually have a pending 140-byte version including this optimization. I was waiting a bit for a slightly more significant saving, but I'm not working on it anymore so I will probably commit it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 100%, <s>3817 ... 2463</s> 2351 bytes

```python
import base64,bz2,re
def f(n,e):
 s=re.findall("[A-Z].+?(?=[A-Z])",str(bz2.decompress(base64.b85decode("LRx4!F+o`-Q(2lYjJyB>_?>`2gMW}e@IU|m@L&gzfB<{l>MaducV>;xcV1v3r}_v9qd}l1g$bb0WFnp>O&STHDd{yaqyPYlr~6YAQwdMh*(7?5KmarbspRyU5D6YB>Ux_~Kpvn20BND4Mk62^05mXaen^xm000000ENyXhobxV`;X?{ExyPLkgLKDP|*Q^?o*e5XuP4M=5UaiAd|`2;!L-!vGCJPj#;Mo=2>TVCBV{l6DI6B_r0dGFBRQ-O|~`xNM7ayY%9|*JDHKx)H%`3m$P%bfxU(EeEGzleQ$#&o^1*0>`mQyWinz&K_h&|r)n^J<>jzrwUxNpN$qXir0}FVs_7L(Ks|=pmD2iIahTy>RB*k9#U=BSIWVqS3gGbVZpVtyD8dEs&<v#@cP}dhn`W7qib`>cvCEjl7e+vZP!cd9feP7KUJ||~0FQFad}w6bGbS;17~RfNW=AZ-?8t28AOz_wt~OR85Loar%*#lVF{BpPkTAlKBBJq&5IIzogmT3wP=ZP{!d>aETG<_DSc2Oj4duuj%a?ggAaH<lR3|AC9N>Wyq;np^W5Gyus`ED9MYY}3laCeQ@R052^8Lt6chhHS=PKG_o@*~ICBX~8XnxM69}KpBRk}!|Nkn*aP*I+cKKWij;l3&FfZofSuJl}P%9C^dABC%JEw(S#R(||vwYR%OltbAF<bRs2UeKzeXleyw=czoWGHjSn^SmprWPH?|!-=07#O)v9FyZb)D!mGeg_aEbQnWd~Sv^0$(U>TLiQx_d0ZJEj?In+L@`K%YQUM1cbI1*C-ukR(DngIFmkJ^qE)Dc7>Wf?`7`YWLwM+J3Hpu`;F&p=WjHW=<cygYHc+}GOFgXO0=*q=k*RxL<?d{EH8V4g`oTFz#A1JX|L%1mW4s9(}kh|5%etRW3y*^(Q&Mub5?StGw?m&hT`PpTVGkv0+%N&w8d?ggL)Ky9rZ8uH0a~(k|k`(~|tJR@r`Py({Cly12W3l@e49in_AV<B$_48M82_#A8ioZF>x|_<d(GLXB%jJ#EoKM06qbF(%n-K(Rh5e30T@Lbt{U*=!(Vcc#m4fBN7PDDvY$Pv4VTb{T(kB_s=w_u*#yj&@6l`rQXuD>`3P==#x=l$E<$n%q;IJ`mp-930B+gn;Bw~$S@uKjrO%gEn=_!H>jn55^PfqZnK$wh^Q%|5gfsZ)n9|~pWd!n2xtMt2I+?2ybbWX#r;c3lwdR<%>6el#lge`*LM&McY@3Y(8$TKqOuoJnn4{kGvOY`c!@j7RIPUnBgv;NFWAAR3qb%r^dGr@IwwatK&meM}r5|G_r#F3<P+>Nzy0!bbI{4>gVo26MfTFI`C@jc8zgpXx@Eu<fGa<wX6eL_2i8;e3I;@L&r?bvJ&n9*mM$TElv(p5-@<V|c)7Hh_mrIE^YW36V^x@rbi>N9>_?WJ(ii7B=8@~z_)Zl+NInDcLe&b(UFUJoeXew<(w$4#fgQ*fF{D3~kj6vA}cEN9}xk}Ir+0Vg_L^9n-^vcK5|CIvx|znAi67u1Qo_x6j*K7CT**02u68QTS=v(l;tc&k3OHuc0|C|js)<DE)X04p&I%}|W-9UO;KGP$#5p9i@xrhM?-wd^{M==!3!eCtaBfyiZOyT#Z^3ERpfx}!MSu`4>PT~-A$yuO=4(hifs0Km6AkP+jd_0jSi3#ItzIy8y!Q{W$crxZ*Z*)QlMCV)VYI@mq{>v-ooMA$^@MqM5!5Gp9(wn0o=t=X)0EVIjJfhjdmfsDEjj-ge71G&1nz{?F-UqFQ!Ui_ylWX9VVX~g9$*qLc(M;YIknZP~9Iqz)r`19X%(%&7^tyi<i09Sx!2&v&7?OPu^wjVl&4RkTK`0EIzahitH>(Z=jE!=0TrmYUTXk!@-0EVT7Z$Dk^k?mU9s=n!;sXeJgsmArC7?v`d>o?r3z7o;iEO1Fh%AJ{a43j`h@{VSzjQ2rV6BP@&gj9>5W^oRe^l@a-MKjx!_Em$F2!;9_1iF}v7FOAU5MhebG!cm!#tDiAHx_=BBoyR~nT-<02#y;N1qH_>8^t3Gu2k+kP#9cRS>VnNLqLE|Fyulvo#`c=FH6J$2A-0V!(nsHf$#pb$SzC+bx%8>H$mCL5MtK&@WCh^k#Bi<=$%9ljrqSIqYVXCLeT0UO8{)!sRB>f->^P%M|mf^+&6ALwl)hsRm$4<rgGU<1DfY8|KjdQrwS4iMiG~Q"))))[n-1]
 return e[:ord(s[0])-65]+s[2:]+e[len(e)-int(s[1]):]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fXzbdtRKsu27vsI0l2VA5rjuqhY2YLDBgMHczGWNZTtLylLJuqJLVakwjB77fb@f/X5e9uP5hh77R/aP9JkzUmVYvXucNRaVMyJUZV0yM2ZERipvqlmW9v6xmIWx3uj8VS@1t/nbb7/9I0zyrKg2JqrUw749WXXtQlu@nm5MN1Nb3/6rtVHuFPreNEx9Fcebf/n90daXP@7dfbD5YEfg7b/YZVVs4ov3fO1lSV7ostw0P3dv4gyo9PXmX16@XfavHdzNzrfebHbjzxfPm73dswe7593g6ON3/fDww2Xy8OWtYDXdu/8t3j1Sfu2d7LpL76Qz7xXfz@bjr/73uBPcmEy2Px6k@e7rW@/eP3vif2vU1@b4c1z8GH5@9GbhH83ubI4eDF4kqpiU@dvmw@DJ8PPe7ofl2Y8X@Tztbu@9etI/iobd0@1B8knp9HSZbMt/@6@aT7Nssjw5dz89@La/bI5fRsHLF0@OL@@8OX2Q3dGDT/Vx/2hn8EGFj/zL86577eXWtfnTx8@PL667R9lOd/f9yeO9k2/x8MnhcO@s2PafHuy9fbP1@vLH@fLV0Ug1n2@OL@88f/LsxfL2s5vnveTG8c3JdPlhc1/vP13F@s2N67ey086d7d3z5E3zMUxXt16czW5dFrfT0@f3dy9WxeLD8lX@6sbXT2Gx/f3gpDwbvdx8UV7u5MmTbnioZu@b3bd7d6Lx9Q87e@8OP558fdcLnk5OvuQnVfPE8ffLW/fn1x96x9/9WXr@cfQ1nJzvevPH@xfxSN@dfzm@5vnjqT4evfjw/PLyx/bBmwPlf18MJ08n79zO6Mfb6auPO4@@bD1wqq7z6PXqbFH9eP3WGbzMVHHzzvX45ODbXn4cvX8Uv9jbe/711uDwcJUFyfve4njny/G3a/6u2n//9P7Zk3de9/VF36/ri5vqQRA8Us/ux297l48ej1/tfmy@uml@@nHwtKnL8/0n46PPn7/3YvVYv3n4dnvQPXVeVkNvNnv2buf4xdOz7OGdH4eP9z79cD6ly6Ph@PuLfO9t9P3a5asovaOO7xze9V68@BheuHHv1sH0SzZ9Vz@Pvx/fHD8@9R/tPb75fH@x@e76283Ly/ni89ubr@Nq8ujg/uRt2f2gX6z0p1g3ix1vlX18@uziXXr6Dh384/GzB5fXtna2R9df356PD5ovk9tPriVPdXCm9idv0o/@j3fz0@0bmx92378M3yzP/O0vz/cvHhymd18@PH9x8/ObD0cdb3LYufN4q47ebj5Jg8ODJHp@@nX/9hNvtPtx@uB8dP7548vF0d3nvWd5fe4e3Mp3Pl48@7hz32uCz8@8u9@fvj4IPr3e3rnzdSe683b58v4D/9v@M@ekH5xn7w9W1x91nn@6fHmzk3zsl@PN79HscnBTV28/9po7p5tvbh3Vk8GDd9XTxYPk1uz9@XH@/uRpNN@@e/PVrYXj45m8vP2iGRdfnPrZtvqxGV1G55s/Lqvnbx8W58fN5rfHcdPpfuzFD3V/HKZnj07u79046ztHTvfs@iMnzL4c7C4vz@77m09fftq7efH8@n724mh7@HVysHkz3Xqx@XY20L3t9w9fTqpvH@7sXNs88bzrSX@692p0/OTJ/PON43n/5P3k2/vNaO@s3Fmc1XeuNxe3Hg7j8@LNp/rJ7nnveGfn@nInvrF//0Z686t7@Pw8ybfGve29u0Hq7i1@3Hj3sH5xUby@GeynO2fXnu1epIPB6fH065f0xY3F7PTNzctBMC2/3E7Hlz/yj/61tLusjqru4d0H3WYy@fjpeuF6vXjhv71/c3eo4@txoM/vvDy6deR9ftj7vOnceP/i6@s6e56m/W/R0/nrz@fetYcXo7eHxx/SvWDuvjr4@OjR297Xyc3i1H9aPDxcLFT14laij74Xg8unZ8X1g97947u7r1bN9rXJ5PBbfzc4ybrDo@n7g8Pzxw8vPGcV5J@WD/fr@9On6v7i01C/POuGjqt7hy5my@LBZP78Vjq@kxzdeL8fzzfzwdbD@yeX3u3Rs9lZUhzun37@2BuenC4fFpNw99UYM@7H55thONrbcR7@WJ3d/hLffXWYPvFe6luTzQ8HH55n@pNe3N9c3OhfnwZv7kwPvj3p/YguhvNH3739V@Pvy@j7YXF3@yQ4e3k6TrdO596LweXjw/nycpU@CoejuvMmO1sOL@68GD1@f@fOdrceOm/ev9uZb8Zu5d2Keq@f1d725ePLi/L2/Sf7tz9t9/Nbhze/X37cGn947b54enzj@iAfhw@XxezowdbCP/12tLNzrXdNP67U3rQJv7xu3l//ctrbf5tPl9@vHb2rz/u7x@9/bD260dSvd/qbs3Babr9Iho@i47sX/tn2xbuwd/2wWh02TnPtzbePN7xi@eXOlzu338RHj09un3w@fJh8/bY738qyo0c3Th8efT0aXBs8zcebi3Q726l2Pt3e3j85vHg@nV34ybR8sn9xsRXoUefprU66@vbgYOvD14M31z6EZ0388dP45OTTj2B8487Xl97mkfv5MEq/HP8YH35d3S7OO@NPNzdv3hqdVk14P9wev1te696a3xo9eH1cny4uTuJb/bfR@xfn2/uHKzULq2e7m192Lvav7Wy/L5LPH95/iq493MLJvB99ufEkOo0eJB/G5U56zS0/6edBmTwqHo8ezM/93exB0VuNMjfcf905mN189Pyb6vcuzmcPv528W1286RYnw73jh7eCi/Hu4ONp9lafxg/V1tGLi@W1s/3kxkH3mjs@64QH3@ejg9ePPgyOZnry9JqXXLtePQkfPVue7eztZc3bH@n7rfvb3euN@6rz9dnZrnNa9Z7W3ehudHx97L19t3uSvnr59eX@5UFTx/Ps@rm3c/Bs@PxG99HW9sm1zbR8Nr1xPZ/ceLd6fHeyvOnsPruRPH45OMIgefjx8ew0ur4X3t@5cXMcXxRf3x1@/Xzy6fFL/X77w2vn2@1r5du93enW7unxzaPLZHp699bw0ctFfHtWvk1u9O8XwdMP9ztPpp@dyxcX/pti8a4fHoVPf7z5y23893u61fnD2ih0VRfphv79r1nhb5a/b/9xe2s4@ONu@Xv3r3/c1b/HOt3Ut7fCtIKx88ftv/7xj1wVpd7Y2QjTvK42b98r8zisNn9zf7tt5QUPlAN@7/5hg0H9lPHL9oaB@J3blipLXfw8eGNn5/97OJja7X903EkdT@ytUtWFQEVkdd1w3rRaINH13LlO67LVCqa673ozVdililWiUl8XIhtoDYwRH4mOdZYam0BraGxxuFKFL1iQNXLLr3VYVDbuYxXrVoq15bgLHF@BWmZhqddm6KiCfexOYlVWV0cYkcjqbLueqnSRh3GsijWGvuMmulJJVuSzrAxLO8980aC1Ol3ckQpHTuPGnhZar0VAq9NzF1mR2KnWPs9CGquDu5F5GS40UlGdKqszcCda236BP0wkwOoM3TwMeD/y0A90Y3VGf1JkVZVZHeefdFZn7BaqsvFvS21V@MQ/atAoq7stRl0oP@T1URJgdTtumWs@Izz9IlsYKVtY3a47/VU/bdU9t0xVpF0dqbS0urymSaFc0N8ssroDnE@k@A/PtRYBrdUd4i@GokIrGjxJdAO7nBV6IVCQ1XVaPR7PzOiJrO7YTUM/K2q7mIVpZv/3f/zNKFQKaPW2/2zeUkYOcZt7nbXta611KoIgq9f95x/9t58/@m9Wr/dPP5qtfzSzev21LQrTQDCB1UOvjvXUnqqwaAQSWL3hWj1BhxA1gNUbufM6zsNU22W4NHhp9Rz8HlSVinUpUJDVG7sXYRDE2s7r6dTghtDqb7sLY6myOpgZoanE1HFX9QT9ILPxabDV77pBFsdZLjpAUfbczPdt9hHcekA0Vr/vBnGWJfaEnwZb/YE7D3kacZ1ogYKsPrquKlQZoocJsPqjK40dpqX2KiMDWH2HEwV@OkhxEoQpz2LcapOsmhkIYA22XT8M7K1YVxURW2vQcf06sKsizAjYWoMuxij6Kz/4vZ6b66IMVbpurUHfzcvGm4WejaAvosDWGgx4J3yjJBLl0E2yNNKNjVkralx@YkwOcF1FmOAW4BPjyFa5NhoAa@C4AQZLjPmrmmmDiazBGAPFU3i2@MBzNRKANdx2czyRcJEF9kIFFEK01rDzi34WFrGxEFnD7i82jOiZsRFZw56rMC495SsZnviwhv0/6SLTWsOBi/k5UiuVXAFriOvG0M0wZrPcwNwajn4qMQUIjnDuzpVaJeZgtNYQc66OY8wgRVZXgg20RtucE9HtA5vaViC0Rh30Jw@zdIPHislR7NRAALZGXbfSaaUwhGzMpXErAVmj3i@motZrG6E1Qj/W2RYerq@J2FojPPFCzXGkaeCURkM@ep2YT2uE55yljc2PSoWxa4A1cjCRYeq1MTfZPqcqETlTjcZuGWcL@@ojxz26Au4aWM72L8dNioz/RIPWcuB7VICBbyccTIKJLKe7NlSY/A2Ev3R67lQVW1NdeTPtEwv8zbecvutnfoYLzwhq/PbAaMywyXyOGmfollrF@MC9ckYcTRmejo@5Gf@ILYedGh3cfBaWM3YTjpSkjqwxrmUmzxqf8IJGopMfdzDbqcTOmhJ624vhcnkAgGisMaYiVdrBDO44bojRWOOeO1N1yiPb1hrzQvJcx8Hf/08awBDoNFDQD1w8kyU@MHWOh66P0VY29goumRCtNR65syZP6cQNsMaO6xVqYvNj0riRNNZ47HISt6ehD4ddiMBO0dnedudZXNlZMRGAFsqOiy6Dnpn52tbLPEb7UwN719VBYDPzVeMZog0CIlh6v1iywpiIYIJDrSf2JMPkAIAGugEeNJ0wZgDFO05PrCIYhi5YO2bK1I5xucCAMQnI9ujKgsGYtiZC2Bw3Dr2IHSioteCwqvGEO9tjeHP4D3q0KJtO6dA6oEeLmdYrKhemhbLjGp84y4oUsGELdbdV@5lo0UDZI4FLPS1NSUYDKlQp3ltpdAwuBDIERoEHmmU2n@wsLDcinrpoy0hOvSPdFH8LFI@fIS6aAr8/oglkSqG3EgJB68hMPoUra70/Rfr@DggTvyDuG0C8dwdEqawweHh8k9UiNDX0nZ96DAHihBQRLCkp7mGQJnoDXBN9m/IGZRjBlbyGHsA0eLzgSxdhunQvmnQJadD2l9ALq8ae1KuVUShC2DkJB4mC7ykM4k@QDuJugpqFBSEaaB3cyrqoS2myEpoxvwIn56kiFxgBgJtuu0FTYBg3cMQ@jwRBijNvtpHqsnRjldNxd8CN/BCswXxCRp/dmrtaz4Xg9t05eHBhk4IKImvvgP1ccJxQS2CUQ3cKYq1FK0i0nFnjhg8L32YLneOqBP2UbGGL814Gd9twxID6XFl482lhC1K9jR4C7p21DTSdFqKH5y3McUUgPUoX8AE5ppPMV17VxKIxEAeQ2@JK7FgtBaGFtk8vDbps12nm8iF7ANAP3JXK0dNLtnIj@yQLuOqUvqsUjBZ6TKjSL@0qTBtitCH0zloPkthCxacJEtQaojQMZlUr0QF0wIQSvbCrRcYWDVSMVEh5FsBdl9SGDhS3UFGIQFkrhhs9d6IaTBVqSoCJYgplH98LFMYcWG9YJyIRwAQuGzJUw9BhiOI1qa8IYRq6osOtmiuBaKEeuVWDaAknLhNiGeLxUmMgDkA3zSpMuwiE/JDjP6sEwITJZ60mJVwYEQAh0Tbij0LFtgLdCRTnTJGJcbtAkkq4elwytIixjaQRFIEiTetirQY0WniXLKvkg/@gAZ3PPAbn@CNgayKhhWWAIeE3kxBxaKwBcJkgR7/qSCo74EYlBmOq8RdsjCxvhphAVBAwV4MkrbXSZxDRmtE3lOsuS6HiQKTiHTAkECo8O0bFGO2zDJMQuFGs6AtTGycquOasC070S8TF6KoDLsQgQz6mOONRvw0X/pcJDTDXIIIQSIQDBngUQWjnIVvQMaiGRoUOLzq0UI5cVdUumDr/iuMubYpLI3LGwUOA89eccUDZMN@A50xj/A38TaU4/hUw1B2MaFByUGhE91kpjcpm1IoCh3QNgUToUZYIPigIgqnH32eQJMEzMUNnkB21qmP7VxsUV2aEp6WufcwBiwzBfAlIwHh6aMgzqHSVKV@EKtMI9MGGwH1xY3K2aKBCkBqFeRsTEUpY1AEluqiT3JbrFRjLzQU9Qlhg5ypOwCSTLfxzVZjzK@BHZZ1OQfswzCI8Wg0SVSPGSF1p@HxBkX4egwbc3cj0cGBKjUoTZT4h911cEm7sRixNK8EwwDiFDwkLBptwAJQIYBq6usxlfkYr0zMoU50gOhAlkdGC6ddF1HAAL2xApnSoYWqgM/6V@QqRMs4VonjXLmhUEpbo0Hqe1SV8tQYzxMdcU09xXpc4rOPi0tNsgb/MT2i6uIwJImbptxjJlATB1nODsECn0qbFs@af6tM16g2PRIrIy6AcuNOs4JxcMkMkU0LGhhqYQR7rVDIepSYk8jQMIwS@IVge6EmQYeKkSO7ZBZcCi8UzEwoqECy0CyJVpqRxNVhwFohAbHXBphBrpP6ViVJr6rRzKlmG@3URxgTQ4/F7Ifp9sVneJlyBKHbBqspZTRrXZsIoxEzo9F1QDa@OdWnLxEJRCYJxgHMB2WnshUYUHouEFhaMdu37DaaWUgkMiWBATwDAYMKzJCrkWYJZlTGCb6ElAhMePG4Ziy493quKoiCrS2614LDEzRBUT6BEfBtiVKNP0mYEIpjgyTJO@mUmeTkQPQDoe26hE1jsQmGKNTj0Yei7nLVzdC266RjUvaHGINgR@OD5zDGKlP/3/4xDdCdO4VQS4AgSLsSMGwX8ZMXzoWjOBvM7bht4H1wroAHQO5gW6pSTel0YmDFJCvq11mO0Gz0GfBf0S4ZGS1SJyVS7PYkmMPWllZ03QdK4xDn@ApkYHWprpUAAQ29NoYQNtDSqC0OfDDWwcTTDGGABMODxJ8zqTbQi@xYhYK8BSasaBKFFxpiAEC3UP@MIkikTRgDBguefZHBRtmk2/vtv/xthsxFqXuj4T@Q2wqOCHPFBgbOZXjJRE6ZUAsReXdC2JIzRn1UaEbGFFj4gRuc3n5rH9SSXGGWVDokiuMYuSBpcPoiXUROH0OJyaxxaczIlbcMV9em7i7myySKJQtLILhNVda60qIFarcNboVKEjkKuxSqa1j5241oHGT6DEA8R3Gz2X//@X/@O572VYeiCmHm46LIK0Y0nmiOI8gTnBp4mCY5Ae1EmEC3UPaaL5vBdOq9IkCg1fEIgaqUHZfHTJnIoRrrvAg@D3C8yGO66C57mZcmkxhlIKAgjPItRAeGAETPhK31loxQaEyd7n94tl1neB4JWnDzCoLLKJNkDTGR1hxzf8N6kfrqojAAAC5NY7CqzRqfKYCJYED@R4DatyQjG1HNXYbBCN8bsJWlzIwLB2EfcSg/fmiBkjJW7oGuSeld5zsx7XcAHU43AkZ2rTcADe@Z3cPla1VU4BWu4SuivdTG6G3ibh/Bz/U3g9pug6LUsKCzBjwgzTPzgbXFWoaPEYdxs5CASEBW6PLmbGEBf4EwLdBkBsHTRe3zGaRmisCatZkaGBGOPKRkff6USAK7aBZdLER7CGQqTB2YLPXr7LJxWJnNmMGco8jgVYhpdgD1nCxFipvLB5cqFZG1ai0hicdwFJ6mgZnYOSBwU@F2OqdJTKViI6RWUCawuaB4iMk7X@LFqhZEZV3A4oHlRWMTMv5oWKmZ8wBzseYaoRyARDLjYupgqD84gCivJI8HhAMKGMEWVCOERs/Kxh@mVHOJpOLz2gnnqLTpPg8V7gtgJfYljhNG1MbiUZTYGuStjBS8KkoIbDxwx29wFw5uHAeJboxdsDOP2Cy21MXmD7pjrD@kFOHjI9CoFtjB0WgPONjKwxLRGSjfDcxWFQALoe@5iFoKDFWRX@F/EhA4FxC7Oal9Yky@wAD3tgta1uSebOiPUNNCXRbhiRoFEBFBjRocLbxS89hpA65AnFz8psxDmLhhdSt/MOiuFSZgCgdUDlZNnxIkdn60AfUfcKdeWbHzAAlEAbLhoLnvYutEGNRpaUvmFveCEBsDprLfNmBv@1Q4LjDlEAyl0DMRChBeiIxTt0FVBQP4Gv94eDllMI8SyPi56nU0QiTF0D7TtyiTJasap1FCA@c@uC906jNapPSCr16EDw/Tzy1GiEAFmzHdxXcoHL6fDWS6Fgp84M3A3SSdimqmI2ELbd3HTaxzDFToDS3574BZ8CJOaWclQicSR1ANnC2T5KGhbqDimZTTbChGAzMJoYOA8VqThnAmOHEQ5nSlq5gQwo1@jOzArWOSYZ0QisHpdJgAVHluCaM1dYPZg@rcH5mbUiEN8UaOFuosZKZng4Segl4Aglz1QNpFtXdR5JZgAhr57tWbrZSqmFKGFBSOaC9yBnYUgBGXOBmpccoHAqsE1BAaC7ve6JvpGiJVi9BFi8PWYFCsUYzdE0AIJoB9jRCO4qZjqwR0w0hzfADszxIxeYCrcCkp4ceVx8t7SvGceODO03bX2KnNgFIjhYO3xziMCAD8QFNdQolvHVWYz9idiC@2A65zkWPBtCDxWygBYmO4kXZ2HnGyB2UI/gotIuThbMbwhJoABpIxkGTQOLACQLdRjd6KKCZ6Uwn0gJLB6XDbE9BIxMa8qCTsoe1zG6IGPeYVaSMpTTB4XwkMxdX@afKbnRRQEI7NMMfO96EsNMRqo@1wIaECH4XAwdSGcikUDBawY3PCYCFi05qVCYPKgB7aGn/bZy2AWjBb6kavSLEHXRhcO8WC4vkZVgRZmp50/WGzg091RVjG7MzjbVGuJJTmlEStMaKBuUraw4esNsM8MLCZj5oOYmY8euByCRe2xigAgIRWoCGDqypI@3Hr9SzlDpD2pZegNGKopH0MSxDJnemomLSx93B/MI0xQ4AHC5YlccY4CpQOrgGeK6IQJ6YR7g6FRe40XZ3lJQQAsI3TxLMfcG5s6DCaDqahpdJhISjBlebPMQADox66aoKPUJIgGWr0h@0WzkWL6WDQpqBBUHWZEF3bBp83cqDxr0LcA3jBEBwowakMGxmxgwTXnM6Z3zLoSMEc1eBtlMJdMgMYpkLKpmOwavSJIRdCcy4ZDs3bEioTYJsxFgQ7Cn4Ijw0nYsixHhBZaJvzxVxFY4OESEkA/RqAYC8vSOGMERLPSaAitnhA3eBAf3R8Das4W2o7LEGUdrE2UzAejbrvatV5sgGAMuOirUhdMlymojNFoDAfY@3hcyUTWNPEBDN1Aakpixj2BQFYRgLMZbSARPLEgWEY47SA0I5zIDHEuSFId4i8SyJ8bG52kJQQKsnrgajEmP5ZJMOGP6AQ/7HTWyswoMyrZs0Mb4YRyoyaDo4VOQhQT2qYCuczTA0Nj1Py1ViWCJECgFaY3UjPMNqF7ETL/GUKDLqyzZVOEkyytMUhCbwOdyDda/lX0ZMlqIK7FLE@84CwvS5B8Sm3OAwJre3ogZT8rf3RRKBEJrN54W3p7zoFZCCSAvrNe2A/TqS7SjKIA2Lpuq5R1fYO5sN8DP8vDnIUPOQEa6Ppc@ed8Z9TArQHUjJ0V8xC@ncmkAEVmZgXwM65gxMIjCTCtgZytdbaakzRTJILN@WmDJ2MOXIxEsGKKDyeaJVAkrJPQzzLWhWy3akz66O0UFFoYOLsz4qsktogMBlHob3d/WhAxr00MnvvbnMkYd8VNuhS4hBLEtF7KkEYbZtAMRLPcQi8gQgPl0J2QvuoFW72AZmSIzU9iLzIBjLJCy4UIe4v5chGYMO9vs9IJfLSojMUIYupwHTrEyKIlbTFudr/DgWyCYLEYwZi6HNcSNPIDHgvEG@fb6V3p4UNUInElAUwIRnCXbXQmASF1AwT9qW4YW4PYaQmyNS4EJG2uS6nxMSuQIgHyb7M8Bn1SPsC9y9rIRLA6OJfsKlU3qcMVHx2o2hSevFrrRRBLl30d3R5@FE09wem1ALbOv7QVPPfuekKLs7IykHcTrI3L8XAhWTvWRZK7BuKmkkm49U9JbaiY1u4z1VYg/kS/w2/hq5QIYBquTTGGpWAiGBCL12na2JjuidDgMYDDwb2BeCHascVOmS1s43U@eco8pBDskiud8Hh9ULkZl7wzSVYbLHnqPvgc3FSS1ZyjYaKgxdB187oo7DoA1wBiC22vdZ0XLAeQHM6sRTDCoUV1CjddhawPKjFQIn5p0OolnUUo@aw@KN0E0ckKvT4sMDMYCSO4D1LXWnCDg1YvfwLdIEtLTMMlUxOAcla89qtVZ/uiTkP8mqguintWH9xupvK8MUuOhCFvGVndTJlBT8ARDzqHHgnmBG0yaTEQLOwBJuWNUJUJeDcIWbjWZ13Y2jJhcBUoNjAMfhpw8/GEIQqADV6txmOAo@cSq2CusfZB58DccD6xVycuuBDYch8k7hdlXJPpYXIBf8OAydEpK4WA/qeAZ8782y829MsFPbEMeTEspPOCypVks6Q8ZQQuk2OAgMS1a65XNp8Rg3yhx5U5FdkBHqlAAugZvizJKmg1mAiWwS/h1pyZZCMyl9wHh5siWEllQZxrhvI3SOoR/HFlRCwiGZPza1q6iUxaGi1MY8PLPLjFghCN1QeBU5OMkSQe1gYPwBdstqJXRDgKEZxMITZL@IjZQr@uMYJfXmVpW35EBFtPCkZM1Qg/0KdA6kzVR1nD27EbFrPGIBgHbakHqcwCromSINiGf4qzF1yVEgXuU8E/NlrXP8CdtyUQgmByZE3SjpgbJiKAemzWwWxZxdZ1YdbFIFh9UjytprKiRSC3dtS5YrDUExt9t13yueoMEIlhYsIiEQdg1iwgtWsWfTC8dUp@tU7Ib62g56iIuWKLaY@OTiT6OTC9vMgmGZd4rvIsopFES380Mnw/ZbKMiABqx53CWVYIYBnEAMbm8DE9Eh8BPjGpguo1WY0IeAlyDu@Mv8jaMs2qPJMTEQBt10XH0/HUVfAloA6geX6IKyPPMzwXYswbCaZnKDmoIfxVHIVUwv9pTizw0@WUdVuQgGEZGhoahPAfAgXBMJIVO4QcYE4siVAiE8BI/69LT@OWoYtqjiCmeSTz0Qfjk8JaRAWhrPDNQumeY0nMqLb8ljCfoYeC7PlMbiBGwykTooWafo90nU2D4QJVj9UeM8XiUF1zmd7T9CYgeVd1iXDijUgs4uiPB6Yi2g7nmP4xxPn3GLgXOc9dxj4EM/JJ8FrD1WARhRks4HiVZlkhkxtEmP7B7NDaiIykrNa01gDMTifC7DKMDEA00HbczNMY6wtWsduZJFEzXN0iY70suB2YV6sGMkpGLQnvTGsQyZjwpPEU@YCUh3tWiahoYdBWeTM/C2wTDcyywKiyAOYhQ/g4zOuKQe9ayGEZcT3SF54eSjcp/JC7AWQpNavZo1PfQCIYxsYr4yPOwlQEAmsAusdFPDBPEkBittB3DOdX8Kbo6SpgOXLKFjY88zAJOR1ST9waen/6EkkIv6R5W0H41l@iXr5kDINfv5RzCRCYLWzD9ZdET9waMK3VZWZLDodeEP190HGMkjlqJR9Xdqbi5JBxW/QPhjBnV2BjDcD6ONC4dtwW6qzFGEaupU8xpNGnMCJLLiBCoVcAsMrqWrVioTIDKhFi/mbPXWku/7e5TwiCcBZgfgw5ud6X/vff/mMDvYOLjEUWBDotuEI7APubZDXrPxE54lczkPCCvzp0OfS32nQNMQEMI5YpSAUMWlbADLgRYMFCIirLKy0Lo7hGDpJOVkdhwnsKtqeXnpozp2c2VFA0OyoGIHyq9sPM/i3c8HG7s99ERqg3AOWrQo4jafCjUElBASsbgrrwjYrbHFLMPxVzvrKPhbFj3Frh4hr2gRBsz2d8J3LGG9ljSXzM5UQJPkxtiSiAYOZ8AM6K6UZMRmhtmAxmvEh@spIdrl7SemoRWQPwuxJDuVwoZoWJBcDQcVvl1WoXROHeAzC9mOUWYBhKmDQEAlh6bdk9J9ww13BRkAXA2Hel4vwXo8hr84B0Cqxcp/AUvxxE7foYLkRWVYY/alpN5Yi/k5SYxkVnpNCTuQf0L5cUiGT@AEE38Cy55MpMIVxCwM4sM0sgvRnsjyk9xpNezeVBioJg65h9JT8rzyiS7gxYMXdVeCZpFYQJYIUZtwQI8cuiX74XUc7ar/bpTGqp0Iwi1QocJczeGQt3kwQ1WA8Viawc83y4OsNafDh9ySIbEQA2uHxZl8u1UG4IbGGgT@SiI1OP3EdCQQzoGgiQg6BZt9aAy7EGs8p5WhkTWphwM@CEY5v7R2YGA8DQBV1KQrNYxZWhkjsgcA@kGBgzZuFl@YyRlq0DenKQVRpVUIQBT31o8vl1oDCeCm5Gwb0YChdWORf2PHAWWXfAxRLCOjQeF5M4fEKzFAnB8QDs718YmOocDCWxXyKQqCcT5qarFsA0ZsCByF3biFRlfXFCYA3A/xBoFRk/a/xhUD@RbfIBQnhQXO5IFmsiLogzKRSmniczxajXluJxm1hr9X5aEQ8xE@Ahho654iYSr4/Uz1hK/ff/K6WYojBFmQPZcCDmBHwwYQ4rZpglXyfEISOm8jNuBZASdgpoYXDACDN7WkudJaAUWQ4k71dLrayk1@rSyF7MRwRGyJ0t6600UjXE8ebIvCGzhTgkEELMDXKxXNFjFaqRhX6AHf5qxSNojXwGTv9XY73UrQgEI6twGJRJKE0okfSAWxDuqXuLe@U9zO5mnisnsgcHRDHJuD6iQHQyctABS/DYqbjCgsHgRuxRAmEbu@vyI5suISbPoMZAawCWOK1T5gumGYvgcVfGLEcE3iDnS4yW6i64Nf3NBR5FI8sgIstlgiteqZl/SMNpyMlPtIJwDFNFsdrgh6vijNdBFzluK6UrBlNEIa4TtBEekfdqJYUoLPDE14yOEIeMWPlaMEhkPYARiGByrkyVlOWLJBDGsQuqjOA14qc1BH30YmacI35C7hi7vdYCtxZ4SISatt@kuDHAbKDuuax7W8dvFHREigBT/0@mNofdHsAk9pAJwnvBveQewr2g0Qk0Q3dyT1Mz0TOtjQ4RcVghLJR4s2ILpeNyCQAsEV6b8z/XA3Cnh9y8MGPmnc8Y3KnQaxnQGoIrqqW2MaPpBdECqg4epqzYQY9OCmFpju263GhB5dVKykwtMW3g3MkT64ktTDcjZAt1n1UjXHFirbhgLhsNyRCLBgEqxp/dxoZcKaSOCEcM2@wbPhJt8m9oYcAE6LFeSFYqryrqRBdgRhuyBq@qU9ssxIWYsylCwn1iJV7Igih09I1pLcKUJ9rdNgawSsxUqQjEsHTWGZCi9n3WqaMJubIx7HbNhqh21iDGnDFkhlDUuMeyZw4NtIwaFqS9aUheToEAFhBDnGuW27K8LAI3JQzBDMEYp1MJkNnGWatgzAz7yC0gwUHzBFpMveNy5VZLthwR36QwAJYxt1PKs41rzESThjJba9iTKNEPTUHpSvYYGwW3XQxBFxm8YsyiDxElvNksw6sLqV@QKry6kDPjvgi4RrJJTGb0BUOwxdVCh5gzcBnoOhQIYGFaFJZZQ6LUhtUUtLnNvXVxGiga3AQxAQwj1gl4Ks3gQQv0GyMSwehwE67CbMJg2OBQfm7syioICZUyRpEjsYJBzsMiZPm6sVFaGVOHbjxVfmZvcRVRMC8ABLKa1bK8JQbiWoYFy/IQNoEWZgBsuYsQzBFTGcJueF0N5kQV6zjAxPh9AjOqwA@jpsbTCtkWHP5gh6DYeUhS5uuMAhroWbwRZz5LADDbyaopFQDc4zjmxjDmrtYbTinKhtPhQPLjZZUyKs0Kr84lMTeT9DzM6wJcEHSFB2okIti6P796USPUwR2p6ROpNRAH9TDnpqn2WB1kYCRf7rNjcnVqHi5ZYwcBLQxSkZrD@2@AJnLj4jRbGlW2hHnIzE5gsosNMR4d5icQRNFPwLoUo2cRBcHIRTJQeZ67bguMqJACoyGYokmyY6JIZVGBDQfFUHbYBswoSJbdCKWYMFHG3E9oo/FNDtwoxHUPucvC2M1@kVYSDGvPBY3PWDSmEm2wQJhY06iYdMAfDdYYECbWf2hZMleCcpw9uOI8nIdTPHrF7frSaecCYBR3UUldXEbI1eUhqGLesLCJaRIgpkmGQy6hcPOrPfn7f@J/kQRZwxH3K2Dks1tNpVfhREe8A1J/j4kXITipQ0yErsvl4Cj0WeHKuhlpoOXUGGRcF68EIXwdMj3ICpWfRUcQpeZoCJpoTKw04z@KbGEamk0s6Oxb/KDEFpaRFO4zI0LAaHQ4cmTvs500pdQvAJfiiUZjWaGy8QS1ILTWkHQwq2UmlMSkCMxMDrlDg2vG7V58wbIXf@h0pTanWrWN5tFMnGUJ3yvAGrxSr0VAWPus@C4YzHlRaXCIHs7FYTiN3OxoF8gdE0OQQZKRLFINgUInJAlUpFXgdFxjl/yeANjgBsItLnKmHEUQpIXBVL4o0pCfVtGYA8YSJWk6Sow6PL0CDdRXrpApTy0CEL/QJXFagH9w9YKYLfv5uGcss2zBe1KIJAg2FuVjki2vandFNNW7w/FgbUXAijAXjlzkWDz5ePhPRchSgwEVSzCG49H/KFFOEQ0lRkuEY7ivDuRBtYdwhyA3hScAGFXj8b82s8HcPGKtX4MpSTLkQHNmyEdgjDO1iOBdPRa3cKPuQjBMTDOmUUhHiUmQ90/7nA1hYiUYIrLUNnSUAgnpaJsBVIa@FiYNUdJAx97BlTfIRAFaaIdyZOs9AVk/PwJZlDcsRLoBe9XTKITOkSL6KktsEKMkNxIATGNTfl3ouU7pz6s1skagijkOilhPpnW0pbYm@PuiUhOeAYhjkNWFTz6H@SrQ3PdJjSDYuy766QQWblaMuemGlT2QZQ/3CBSSsQiHPlwCvImIaGHiRjR6Cqa9gJj1GoFDGuWimcPxUGALw9Bd2h4gk1qlu@T@IYUnBubYtAdz0blagXFCinEyMDruypayW3fVSAvd@CrZD0oWUkg9uJpRl6uorPzHB@4yKOKahxjKIAI5wwgU0WxSzhZC0aSBuse8RyWJxKVAtFD30Se8EDErcwmNbiVWhI66A@H9UgKcypyu@fvcjlaAr7BWTaDyeHNADRGFw5ELS5ZpvpU51Y/AEHPyTa025Iwh5AAwYGooQvQ4bq1JmSxiDRb7KOihvNZhw4esZAlb800iRivvFBn1uG/F4xKj5iskwijMNXox04msSdRS3BmJQAALvGBWs3ba42BNWynlrQNhbDLw9J81gE0tAKaBG9QJKLP@aTQKsUo15MQOJP2RSkEkASwjeWtOoMWxEl4o@tVRj5XNHouvYwT0YaQIoB6bDfHwiQumcykYaI1AFMX2P5cURb9W4sAOV2wzs/Jb6CwouPzCDFhFvSznEuBIzKJ1Feot0jvWWorEgvsRiWQ44QyBX540cRj6SktFBeuFpKZi1Dc5aJtxgCACqNFxGinoKrK8zeWJAgjWobtA5262FnBijeCQEBNFf7TeTphodGctmxcJYHLaJV6V6yUhW6j59gOft6shYGuNuDUXSi9ufF36igXNtS8Ato4svYBp@mbtRQD03Z/7QtXXmm/SYQMRNr7VoV7asgmJyQoDYGDJTaHXhlhiETEMXEYtscQ8BrJqcDRgjBmGFdepTAWPvAeBBIF6QThq9Gv92oQRUSUaApidX82@4h4E0RDAPGb4OZ2uFxNEqPHHwSwlNF6YnUcLxTUBTQm2DuM8Fk@VC41pg4IgmLgMjS7PorVUVt1kgx0zxyNyStmJptqiGkqa@0ZGQ@bqkyn3OYeCNJ4M2ORVHtYO4OVasahhY4q@BM2RxRrBgmAZoZckOaZElsAIzvBYpMYwDlU1W1soCoJxLJnlxmaxjIFE1gi8knEFr5QLXMBZSQQL5pI6kjWnDa/2almOyJs6qhP8g50ZmJzJPK7tAP11I5WnynrDMJb9bDHGEDEBDH0mLkP05kpLVQiLQ6Ae8IYomxXWyo1YP4sbxv0hptrO57tEZHc1FQbCPjJL7RgTtSBfE8LgsN4EQ4NvSiBC5AYt51V0WkmWETFXNnLWhdWYq1ivRSmhR3E4LricJukP1@cny95HIJkXpnAgyX7LBCfZFuYOh@8GiZRRE7Vqee5JJussYosoiok1CHmN647@698FbgDSMDSGvI51rGcYfWKkAOPIGCd1XBs9EfSO0U8R44l6ynXgkcOXZ5QJSNw0CwzEdMvyQ6PVyaRoMiPxzTLc@Su12lILy6wm45XRuNvWdvMREfERjfkmqhmZYWJzu5kIALAgtKxXK4weLjsREkCPcAKslFlTzYpOtRZL/tzQ9UKEv2EFEr2sC3havrZsBC75c7uaqRo1stZyFo4bKQwgvjqoYAsVou12LxJ3AQjmNgAHnDFlwF/yDUlloiAhil0lCqaOvCKIk1CgTVWHlgVOZ5sjvuBf3xDKIEXTZosZEQ7gjkeMNOaWcLnAssrmgDymIOh2qlhVTigIhgGLJJlMxtSn@A@6YfsuOI8bKuNsi2KLU5hHLig7Xx4BDgykuM3akR0jzNeqVIDikWOjk0pdQgGWI3t8M9apmgpTkfjWKAfEsZoteD6mER1Ta4UkyyfcmySQCKae1CkhrjYhOQVBMLHaFq6@4pf4ojc2UF@9soGlxwYCwQAHkHFDsqwolbKZGlq@mCKU55cXeqbTkqGJqEKxO@BSXIUIA1Yw/1LcLmrGAQ53jvAtfPQ6rELCpBct2FpOlzdCa0yGzOCAZIvEbK0DIsmbErYbD@ELtVEAwCpbf@fyXjT@tjaiwTD3rszt@zFENBjmPheyc2E@BOQ9DisSM26erWQrrAM6iZtJXkFfBSgA@hFGlxfJR8gf4ypsiNjAbt/UZkT4NQcMEt6pbHIWqU5jXRcihwIth0vSsgZ@dZDIlGDscKU7lg@EFI5s8pUwXNR@PWELPVed@LoPU/FMLKcJyigbwVK@r6cy78vghjC@LsMBaWwUOK8ntfJcyOO2EYe1h1xzkM3IAtFCzTLcuNlictpswqHo4R9szlW4lsn@liKSs@Jcp2LZsggnFoskyHL6fNkBN1/yE1TU6TN3gtMxWkJuyXT4OhYiZqIMAoBafBp4Iv8kX1NmJL6ozAHtk0VcjG7YudGHGROBMDLRrhLmR7kh3GxKMQjGYRucTGTlsfaVyFEt3xy5V2qb6wO4Z6IglgPWHPDX/V7QcIbpj/@1rYWWA1JYmiH2y8I4FWZl3JE9wq3BNsPdKFiZ6M1wADMOGLCspjDb241MBCur8c2NXFuNDAlWFq6k8sotMCi1FnBNYIq/RK9iFFmZGNYBY5whzsI/RvCQR2u5YnbWARlkHWmpC5ZmzSRxBwTD2CVnKlgOu@UzxocY@viwHDBBPJGgZjGgTmT1AaL8HoggXyxml/B9scBEICxdN5uU5r1u6/2@opCtwA6ooJQH4f7gZCLZlFq0EFa@T4uvi2pfIlCblwg4TC@Ghf3rS9MgX700ja@/K@7ZxaxJtLzRie88g5rLEEyhXS1@UzRr3w5fg8c9xiUeG988AIEtDGNXxfgTiexvUklDEReN8MIhK5yRYS9t5kNA8pW0sDDCTEEIS9a2CTmsC3kjDHexGYijuqb@U96WCIQ7CVZoSgNFRyhvUHRGfCsA6UCZXWTcpVaI3GLYB8xa4A9OtIs@4NU8PebhfC40moaT84irsYhrWbJh86UtiHy5e6JgCzOmjPrn2wq8eiojcMQpg1uF8Qwv1KwVCC3HkEMvM0GpwBWjUocpSPPuJbEQry3d9itCMwXOSTQdyUPKV8QiX2ktfVm0kbJaUxJsRJYEO1yVNvxUtqBx8YsNDMMrQ8waXwgRASxXb3XyFHmgOfVAEKy4DQ3Iwkp5jCUcR96MwRcSQpWoFZHlgB5qvtAHU6hpq7r8fw)

### Explanation

We could print all of the Pokemon with just the number, but the etymology allows us to improve the compression algorithm. Take the first input: `1;bulb,-saur;bulbasaur`. The first etymology `bulb` and the actual Pokemon have a common prefix. Most Pokemon in the list also have this property. So instead of compressing the entire name of the Pokemon, we only compress the right half of it (`asaur` in the example), starting from the longest common prefix of it and the first etymology. Then for the left half we can just directly take a prefix of the first etymology (`bulb` in the example). We also precompute the longest common suffix to further reduce the size. Then, we will encode the string like this: `44a`. The first and second characters represent the longest common prefix and suffix. The rest represent the rest of the characters not accounted.

Comment: I think changing base64 to base85 could shave a few hundred bytes?

Comment: Good point, I didn't even know that existed! :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>2526 ... 2485</del> 2477 bytes

```python
import bz2,zlib,base64
b=base64.b85decode
p=bz2.decompress(b('LRx4!F+o`-Q(59BF!%rhj7R`*0Ds_61b*t7X+T7%iw!XbsxUw_05wnA5{ieYKr{d~PxKN}nvw5(BOjwtq%XftFY)%vlw$tuZI%9;4^7W^?|qN$^KHzUfTa1Tr63Y7r1jva6}^`q2S@hzE%f$eIEbHP$OqG_3SuF>V&&a2$k(oE#{VBmKW+Svm$v*~C^qWuF)k0y?|H~yTPf~!?wrgjhb&<eM^-^OI;(1`q-?Z<qzNrohfQ{Dj81Xiau!gFnMm=jU$kb-uz}rmWO5((Vh03kk%%mYEuZmlvGX6_$^WzTJCh7Hy+7CHc=YRx{QgoqG>`7FyT+mj+KfPl(=}z5nkicW9_jyi#oUj+1pt2Zy5~V&)(O@NB3@G*YRp{Y5yh8F(mPfTzhcqIpQWOApqcBDH-sdIW9L_on;F8Z)_fm*IYekeJSOk9WfqRg+zu5(LBP!vy{<xI$>jOvYGP%sVU+fDc7*izAgV1MIwhk+37)dQtR$ut3@6&%$XyH0BBLm<c9>%GPa=!bg{V#uL4%RsD6#`A-;@5%7)~}vs<Cp)eUFlBHiXIb^TiL*!_9AEc(vE!gk3-ylSFvc9vStpc27mncv+2CeeuQ%MU;U9O-dsn8Ci0wMK?I^3jC_H?kx3)h>VA_!Qw8oGiG|0{qDzI_ao-fMT~Eq(t=11(jj~sTAf+6HxA=oo9lM4X||FImXnI)Ec3xrnEb5)&dqGmLA63lR0gb2;&FLHyOcyVeFSa|%FBDJbqz)`MO*^0^yx-={jS1pqP`l6adD$JFUKx0o9E4AS+)~2vdwIDIO4(M@rF{8{Pa%t<<&k`uiatcw!sYaM2Dk_jjI|#ZFbtwNHBtD!axZ5{r;2nc)gx7J<4#**_%xXq9=l^O%(e%P}<T!l2*mtVtNR28TAS<P1US-rrh{l$rRy2Lx`Be-~')).decode()
f=lambda n,e:e[:int(p[n*2-2])]+zlib.decompress(b('c$`&LLAIkf47^G<db8?T%yMocKrwC`L>oK#<n&WzC%=10Fg#-{RjE{{jH9}U@g`|%yNWEqE)HJts9&XORW7ll`zcx`PyJopCGOuB9+zCT-S6_pQP;6F^(e9bB)uONv#HNp!Ac#IcdPUI7bnG@!S^6|xQJhv3bqI34r7Zi3t<f6PnFI0e#YAHR&r*7l;i{?%POa=UQSb4iuP=`D7P(ch6tB%%CWB&T^u+MF0zO91dI5l`^8b@I0-DyecX{vtX!15NapfuU-Vat9Zd{c`;9Hvq!=UkLWm?0JH>roy%97}g^(|T7P6^&zhAOyaRx)wvn~E~UmP`ibD2onAkv@UsF*$)murbZW(U8u*m=r%XqhEw!An!ic?{2(<%OJyoXO5w0^}g4XZ@6qOdYH4M<1nJD9As2K%QI2bpbf;=C<3rz5&quhp#e4vMgi@*~Vk+>5i4HZ2kTVTTR8pGeehaz|mZZ<4lp{;d%Z;GxEP<UKKmdwIE9F+?|p!{{XI-H&CSCdI8Uw2(YRkhm5pe1L};7%R#MzV6%f2*Svt54J^%iR<ZdL^4hhHnnpRS<SuXsy*)U$%Vc?J+gM9JE)UH5S5rj$8H=31(}(UJRKntZN3;YOXqERx;%8ZtCo47khHWtal9x2n+vOosj+>a0zD+|MXzNJwXZd?1Lh_;mbZ#hh1m90;wjJM5dJn{m*jKMx#}inH8PR=||HoT#6}dD>tDr{ul8naGoPeb$1$<hL)DHi0ZS0c$6X;y^34@W(`92Q5_<PvlM`!@LlGqDxp~guizyt~<it-S8124NnQ1~wx6WQ;Lv5KNC@+cL=IWrdEWyukG&9tpl92_{Wv^6yOHyaw*MzO#M(FLfhdGGuNt;jsHdAkKrJ_v$5hYuj?DYiK@tA!@wF0irDnb|iVwMhISheT&3G+y9S;WE^6HRF}X7tnlpzYQqEUGCTr6aw?IM9P^*h6KA(UN1B!Efcw{7fj(D4GdzVbBzTJ1GpO$k8VN?tMuOE<KmhkVOXAEozrirN(r1F4JRK~C4TXpO-XrT*92*>wU0M7M1{ysG$eGl!hCIKpwPV~WxJ<1lsAo646Uj1uw0?ReMT<IZX9clOx@B;m<nv((E#{QNd70bBimctb%GVlyr)u8s;2_@NC<7XM|@A->A?q$xu4Z+2Of+{Q|kwIzFKM<PWku7z}ykcCN5YlZ}BwH{iC0F$jdE3QgX|N9By*Ecin^Mpr3NW)=Ccr6|<|0zwl{$OC2Dp0?2Hz+>GjukMD)%&ELkHp5t0GNkaz$2aMNY_7F##_{F4MWV*9_f1ndA)t(CgvMWwV&*w^|TcpFW<0>VAHd*3!ba^0gexKQK?@#lsL}6?2G0KB)*DRC-Hkn)31U|ek0jP)gqlbmh&Jn`~r>GFaf062$Ap')).decode().split('%')[n-1]+e[len(e)-int(p[n*2-1]):]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bXxZc9tMku07foUctvxJNuQrriAb8m5rsS1L3peOll0EiiCEVVhIgrIdE/M@73fe78s83t/QMX9k/kjfc7JAWV/fjrBZJzNBCktV5cmsLORNNcvS3j/@ESZ5VlQbk1XXXsXhxJ6oUg/71uS@Afcmo4GvvczXVn4fB92jkOSFLsutydYfr94u@zf272bfd95sDcZP9m9sFrNz5@33O7vPym/DzuRO5Xy@@97ZDBc3Pk/K5YfFt93BIn08uAz1l5fFpf/rdPny9c90vhhsPTk5X1QXm5@n1f6X7c15vLhV1V@PNsdu/8z5dPbwx8XrW2cvD1cfpu9V530x7H1xis75XA1/nn2/6L57NFs935ze0kfPJ4ent04uDr713tX7Dz7evq26t6Kt7PnNy49Pkpef7r6bJ7fmd349Pbv4VO9vR7vNwx@Hv5r3p9NfNx4uiuB8Nrm9p4/Pds5OjtytzveLnYdf9y5Wr4tsNn1z@ex81PkcqvpGsJ8eJ/fPP9yKJjv16meRfDoZbG19nO32omhzM/nyvP6axPODz8Nvt84@rd6/eDpzDpu7ztND7/6Xt8vLN0F2cfDgu7PfvL@bnN99OT2Nt@7/XA3SKPQ@jb@dN@HN7MP53U5edb82g18fb29vnTx6/aT36ODOl7f55ZdBMxvtbyWn0/ermXdxlL/5dPI4v/CePDvcKf2jT@NX37LU3R993f42Te4cfdGRfvHuJBp/ml68De6u6sHWqyenN@bN5d7y6NaD85P5l4PTzfLjh7vTZ55zJ1w9Dj52jo8Ws@huz9n231Rvb9VV79Hw9uatz83h7pMnr5I9b/xg8@BU3b8xCS4/3qxf9Tffls@GN78/3nEfDTad7V8/5@Xe03xbf9iPnxyGn48mZ@/DV3dufBs/fu5tzZ/fCKLeThO/25974/m7Kve6TpJ687vdp1rXbzaPP7gfxic7fpmOnoa7i@OXD4/OeudPvx0@jJa97dmDj4@/3XizGGUH4cGP3cuLZ6ujbyrbmR6///X8Yqu63@lsnZ//Kt8/nt4dHi4f38@ycXzc//zjx/5R8jk92n7u9ZZF@nwy2L7tXxwkrx4Pe/Hb3WDSdW/vvzpsTrzmo95/p35s7j959mJysdr@fnxy52z3rFnu3L88f9fJL06/x0PlP7v1Yv/Dy@VuNn7ef/zu7vav7txfHD07OulvHT8q9i9Hl6dqs9rbux19r0NVeYsb5Rd13H0WfTs/P/px8@v@pFq8PnxSPbuhll8Hl4XbTb3tYOm82OvfvHPn2@by88X4fnx2srmlN09/7r2/EXfvJNXH6vXb7uj943d7p50P73aKYnYZ3yreNt1Xy@9P9M6vP7a375kxu7VtTe/HKpn4aiO19V/0X/8SptVW/tf0Tnen@7ftv93lmP@nMe3d@n771avHR9G075wd7PmT0cP3m81x5r0sFk@/v3qQvby5l97@tHq6eb@zux/c3Ll8e/788vL8cPzzw6Pg@4/N5vWn5xfPtw9fVOX49ueTt5@cOP6@8pbfT5sXWf704KR@Mr67evp@593wW/7m1B3un23p8eTJdn3yen7z8HV@47F388jzTz8cOZP04NGNd2fDH8s3L2bz3uTiqNcvnK9hr9qbDk/T/aNdffPL48O3t4s7TuyGlw83T0/U/Q9v3k36YX16//sz53TLmw2rJ5ubTz89uf3@rL57vL@7Ohl3/KNB/P1sNHl0tLvzrNHe58t59flGZ/Ba5dP6w85HVY2/@pfed3d8OL@4cf9D9OpT8nD3xeGDIms2x87P4Gzrx3vndHh2ezV7fNKot8vtxTz99fzXh@T0ezh51s3Sx9H80Ydy/86t7aQuJl8/bX0Y1XeS@8Xm54vZ88WNx@mN0Ht42d3a2zx50WSfTwaL3bOfQf/z10fDixP/y2H/eK@Tvng2flx2X26@OepO8snUvf90r1esBrcv6ll@U/fnx0H46M6vj9HdB4Owf/i1G73/@P7921F@oPVMrX4kX7/u9eP80vU3v7oHy@enex9evkzQS5@P9@8@/JHfuLz8fLRzePvpu6f@0ejDorv15W00Swa57rz66Tqbb28erz4ON6fdO@/m1aD/4mwzfLv31X911p/NDtM0f/tu7139uWzubH@4tfnRe/jibnA8fvF8@8Ph4N2gOL81Orzf62z93Prw4u3LtPr6uud@Ofl88fzt0t0cfa2eZn0nmh1@qlQ8XnbTu/OTrDy/@0Dtrp7d/XH8efX6xeLzV/9h59Xsm5tMvt6czTrJeNddnL84Hvgv0svkzvnL4@XNn2F6ODp9e//Hj8Ps/c3hT//Zg@pZcVnHo1QdZKd6cqtza2/2avvZYbj79d2ud2v42W3Oev1Hn7a@j7tvBt/2Tufx8fcbj17FBxfPlvmvoA5XTfVrL6x23o063f7r9E3n12I5/PTGfTUfvHz99NFd79X9o0@F//xTU0cHt8dVHo@73y4/zc@GzclhoxZ3jlcnN4@39l9NZ/7BQf26cs/LQ/9x9LJ48W1@azD7Up8/fPYlfPmoenzj0WJ/NyyepZMf4cfF8ezo3Uy/v907uNuM37mfnp8ND9/u//zsVGmcr768uXj@4eApPKBaPDw6Hp@e3ZkNXz7e@vC68@TG86m3uHSm51vP@gf@6uPkCVxP5yA/uRWNPr5@WB3XJ8/3Xiaz6OPJ58fPs1URFq@3is5@H8/m19P@@8/5yc7n4v2dcffOg8WH3WPnuHPZlAe39EF8Y/b06GW@OP3469PyxV4nLh9nw/7ww3mnXuw@fKuP3@8dff089uKT5aMnbrKXzre24HLfvPad3cmTMPGqyebBx7gptutR6Xa/PXr9dM/5fPzj0eOdB48fXtxa1v2vd7sn07uXb35Ei6PV/svjvdNPUe2sfjaR9/T14Ev89eeTxeFl@HR3/9a5/7z3Jvj84/X4SXPnuRemZ8d50Xv9afv@U68Y/tj7sbtaxJe3Tp52n@W7D7uHq7sPDs7r6PjZ9ubt56@iw3xQ7R68jtTqVlcdv/7yzdm/efPb5X7/@NPHO@Nv007qP96utp4G8@NPi4@37yzOfrz38v1Pe7vwO4f@nd6NiTrbDfTy5ZuXDx/djMtXP4cPuwe7L59s33n29unOYZRu9zoffuho9/x0O7iIJ8ns9ov0@6/iwcG@mu4Ou7ce59cn6XtlHofV1h@bf2z/Nd3p/O2u/mus0y29vfN7tu78bfsvf/vHYhbGeuN9Ueu/WBu5Kkq9cX8jTPO6@v0r7h/b1oYqS13guzzkr92/bdy/vzHdkl8Tze7ftm3z/b/ih7f/0XEndTyxd0pVFwIVkdV1w3nTaoFE13PnOq3LViuY6r7rzVRhlwruRqW@LkQ20BoYIz4SHWtwE7EJtIbGFocrVfiCBVmOW17UYVHZVV1UsW6lWFsjd4HjK7DWLCz12gwdVbCP3UmsyurqCCMSWZ1d11OVLvIwjlWxxtB33ERXKsmKfJaVYWnnmS8atFaniztS4chp3NjTQuu1CGh1eu4iKxI71drnWUhjdXA3Mi/DhUYqqlNldQbuRGvbL/CHiQRYnaGbhwHvRx76gW6sjvMnRVZVmdUZ/ZPO6ozdQlU2/u@onQqf@E8NGmV1d8WoC@WHvD5KAqxuxy1zzWeEB19kCyNlC6vbdafX9dNW3XPLVEXa1ZFKS6vLa5oUylXFJIus7gDnEyn@x3OtRUBrdYf4i6Go0IoGTxLdwC5nhV4IFGR1R60ej2dm9ERWd@ymoZ8VtV3MwjSz/@c//80oVApo9Xb/bN5RRg5xm3udte2i1joVQZDV6/7zj/777x/9d6vX@6cfzdY/mlm9/toWhWkgmMDqoVfHempPVVg0Agms3nCtnqBDiBrA6jnuvI7zMNV2GS4NXlq9EX4PKvg/XQoUZPXG7nkYBLG283o6NbghtPrwfsZSZXUwM0JTianjruoJ@kGGKK4y2Op33SCL4ywXHaAoe27m@zb7CG49IBqr33eDOMsSe8JPg63@wJ2HPI24TrRAQVYfXVcVqgzRwwRYfedKY4dpqb3KyABWf8SJAj8dpDgJwpRnMW61SVbNDASwBruuHwb2TqyrioitNei4fh3YVRFmBGytQRdjFP2VH/xez811UYYqXbfWoO/mZePNQs/2ay@iwNYaDHgnfKMkEuXQTbI00o2NWStqXH5iTA5wXUWY4BbgE@PIVrk2GgBrMHIDDJYY81c10wYTWYMxBoqn8GzxgedqJABruOvmeCLhIgvshQoohGitYeeafhYWsbEQWcPuNRtG9MzYiKxhz1UYl57ylQxPfFjD/p90kWmt4cDF/AzHp5IrYA1x3Ri6GcZslhuYW0PntxJTgOAI5z66UqvEHIzWGmLO1XGMGaTI6kqwgZazyzkR3T6wqW0FQsvpoD95mKUbPFZMjmKnBgKw5XTdSqeVwhCyMZfGrQRkOb1rJjjDtY3QctCPdbaDh@trIraWgydeqDmONA2ckjPko9eJ@bQcPOcsbWx@VCqMXQMsZ4SJDFOvjbnJ9jlViciZyhm7ZZwt7KuPHPfoCrhrYI12rx03KTL@Fw1aawTfowIMfDvhYBJMZI26a0OFyd9A@MtRz52qYmeqK2@mfWKBf/jWqO/6mZ/hwjOCGr89MBozbDKfo2Y0dEutYnzgXo0cjqYMT8fH3Iz/xNaInRod3HwW1mjsJhwpSR1ZYN/lTJ41PuEFjUQnP@5gtlOJnTUl9LYXw@XyAADRWGNMRaq0gxnccdwQo7HGPXem6pRHtq015oXkuY6Dv/@fNIAh0GmgoB@4eCZLfGDqHA9dH6OtbOwVXDIhWmvsuLMmT@nEDbDGI9cr1MTmx6RxI2ms8djlJG5PQx8OuxCBnaKzu@vOs7iys2IiAC2UHRddBj0TdM3WyzxG@1sDe9fVQQCL9mo8Q7RBQARL75olK4yJCCY41HpiTzJMDgBooBvgQdMJYwZQvOP0xCqCYejOQnSRLLVjXC4wYEwCsutcWTAY09ZECNvIjUMvYgcKai04rGo84c7uGN4c/oMeLcqmUzq0DujRYqb1isqFaaHsuMYnzrIiBWzYQt1t1X4mWjRQ9kjgUk9LU5LRgApVivdWGh2DC4EMgVHggWaZzSc7C8uNiKcu2jKSU@9IN8XfAsXjZ4iLpsDvOzSBTCn0VkIgaEcyk0/hylrvT5G@vwPCxC@I@wYQ790BUSorDB4e32S1CE0Nfee3HkOAOCFFBEtKinsYpIneANdE36a8QRlGcCWvoQcwDR4v@NJ5mC7d8yZdQhq0/SX0wqqxJ/VqZRSKEHZOwkGi4HsKg/gTpIO4m6BmYUGIBtoRbmVd1KU0WQnNmF@Bk/NUkQuMAMBNd92gKTCMGzhin0eCIMWZN9tIdVm6scrpuDvgRn4I1mA@IaPP7sxdredCcPvuHDy4sElBBZG1d8B@zjlOqCUwyqE7BbHWohUkWs6sccOHhW@zhW7kqgT9lGxhh/NeBnfbcMSA@lxZePNpYQtSvYseAu6dtQ00nRaih@ctzHFFID1KF/ABOaaTzFde1cSiMRAHkNviSuxYLQWhhbZPLw26bNdp5vIhewDQD9yVytHTS7ZyI/skC7jqlL6rFIwWekyo0i/tKkwbYrQh9KO1HiSxhYpPEySoNURpGMyqVqID6IAJJXphV4uMLRqoGKmQ8iyAuy6pDR0obqGiEIGyVgw3eu5ENZgq1JQAE8UUyj6@FyiMObDesE5EIoAJXDZkqIahwxDFa1JfEcI0dEWHWzVXAtFC7bhVg2gJJy4TYhni8VJjIA5AN80qTLsIhPyQ4z@rBMCEyWetJiVcGBEAIdEu4o9CxbYC3QkU50yRiXG7QJJKuHpcMrSFroykERSBIk3rYq0GNFp4lyyr5IP/oQGdzzxEjSn@CNiaSGhhGWBI@M0kRBwaawBcJsjRdR1JZQfcqMRgTDX@go2R5c0QE4gKAuZqkKS1VvoMIloz@oZy3WUpVByIVLwDhgRChWfHqBijfZZhEgI3ihV9YWrjRAXXnHXBia5FXIyuOuBCDDLkY4ozdvptuPC/TGiAuQYRhEAiHDDAowhCOw/Zgo5BNTQqdHjRoYXScVVVu2Dq/Csjd2lTXBqRMw4eApy/5owDyob5BjxnGuNv4G8qxfGvgKHuYESDkoNCI7rPSmlUNqNWFDikawgkQo@yRPBBQRBMPf4@gyQJnokZOoPsqFUd29dtUFyZEZ6WuvYxBywyBPMlIAHj6aEhz6DSVaZ8EapMI9AHGwL3xY3J2aKBCkFqFOZtTEQoYVEHlOi8TnJbrldgLDcX9AhhgZ2rOAGTTHbw31Vhzq@AH5V1OgXtwzCL8Gg1SFSNGCN1peHzBUX6fQwacHcj08OBKTUqTZT5hNx3cUm4sRuxNK0EwwDjFD4kLBhswgFQIoBp6Ooyl/kZrUzPoEx1guhAlERGC6ZfF1HDAbywAZnSoYapgc74OvMVImWcK0Txrl3QqCQs0aH1PKtL@GoNZoiPuaae4rwucVjHxaWn2QJ/mZ/QdHEZE0TM0m8xkikJgq3nBmGBTqVNi2fNP9Wna9QbHokUkZdBOXCnWcE5uWSGSKaEjA01MIM81qlkPEpNSORpGBwEviFYHuhJkGHipEju2QWXAovFMxMKKhAstAsiVaakcTVYcBaIQGx1waYQa6T@lYlSa@q0cypZhnuxCGMC6PH4vRD9vtgqtwlXIIpdsKpyVpPGtZkwCjETOn0XVMOrY13aMrFQVIJgHOBcQHYae6ERhccioYUFo137foOppVQCQyIY0BMAMJjwLIkKeZZgVmWM4FtoicCEB49bxqJLj/eqoijI6pJbLTgscTME1RMoEd@GGNXok7QZgQgmeLKMk36ZSV4ORA8A@p5b6AQWu1CYYg0OfRj6LmftHF2LbjoGdW@oMQh2BD54PnOMIuX//b/iEN2JUziVBDiChAsx40YBP1nxfCias8H8jtsG3gfXCmgA9CNMC3XKSb0uDMyYJAX9Wusx2o0eA74L@iVDoyWqxGSq3Z5EE5j60srOmyBpXOIcf4FMjA61tVIggKG3plDCBloa1YWhT4Ya2DiaYQywABjw@BNm9SZakX2LELDXgKRVDYLQImNMQIgW6t9xBMmUCSOAYMHzTzK4KNs0G//zb/8bYbMRal7o@E/kNsKjghzxQYGzmV4yUROmVALEXl3QtiSM0Z9VGhGxhRY@IEbnN5@ax/UklxhllQ6JIrjGLkgaXD6Il1ETh9DicmscWnMyJW3DFfXpu4u5sskiiULSyC4TVXWutKiBWu2It0KlCB2FXItVNK197Ma1DjJ8BiEeIrjZ7L//47//A897J8PQBTHzcNFlFaIbTzRHEOUJzg08TRIcgfaiTCBaqHtMF83hu3RekSBRaviEQNRKD8rit03kUIx03wUeBrlfZDDcdRc8zcuSSY0zkFAQRngWowLCAQ4z4St9ZaMUGhMne5/eLZdZ3geCVpw8wqCyyiTZA0xkdYcc3/DepH66qIwAAAuTWOwqs0anymAiWBA/keA2rckIxtRzV2GwQjfG7CVpcyMCwdhH3EoP35ogZIyVu6BrknpXec7Me13AB1ONwJGdq03AA3vmd3D5WtVVOAVruEror3Uxuht4m4fwc/1N4PaboOi1LCgswY8IM0z84G1xVqGjxGHcbOQgEhAVujy5mxhAX@BMC3QZAbB00Xt8xmkZorAmrWZGhgRjjykZH3@lEgCu2gWXSxEewhkKkwdmCz16@yycViZzZjBnKPI4FWIaXYA9ZwsRYqbyweXKhWRtWotIYhm5C05SQc3sHJA4KPC7HFOlp1KwENMrKBNYXdA8RGScrvFj1QojM67gcEDzorCImX81LVTM@IA52PMMUY9AIhhwsXUxVR6cQRRWkkeCwwGEDWGKKhHCI2blYw/TKznE0xjx2gvmqXfoPA0W7wliJ/QljhFG18bgUpbZGOSujBW8KEgKbjxwxGxzFwxvHgaIb41esDGM2y@01MbkDbpjrj@k5@DgIdOrFNjC0GkNONvIwBLTGindDM9VFAIJoO@5i1kIDlaQXeGfiAkdCohdnNW@sCZfYAF62gWta3NPNnVGqGmgL4twxYwCiQigxowOF94oeO01gHZEnlz8psxCmLtgdCl9MytBFCZhCgRWD1ROnhEndny2AvQdcadcW7LxAQtEAbDhornsYetGG9RoaEnlF/aCExoAp7PeLmNu@Fc7LDDmEA2k0DEQCxFeiI5QtENXBQH5G/x6ezhkMTmIZX1c9DqbIBJj6B5o25VJktWMU6mhAPOfXRe6dRitU3tAVq9DB4bp59pRohABZsx3cV3KBy@nw1kuhYKfODNwN0knYpqpiNhC23dx02scwxU6A0t@e@AWfAiTmlnJUInEkdQDZwtk@ShoW6g4pmU02woRgMzCaGDgPFak4ZwJjhxEOZ0pauYEMKNfozswK1jkmGdEIrB6XSYAFR5bgmjNXWD2YPq3B@Zm1IhDfFGjhbqLGSmZ4OEnoJeAIJc9UDaRbV3UeSWYAIa@e7Vm62UqphShhQUjOifVtLMQhKDM2UCNSy4QWDW4hsBA0P1e10TfCLFSjD5CDL4ek2KFYuyGCFogAfRjjGgENxVTPbgDRprjG2BnhpjRC0yFW0EJL648Tt47mvfMA2eGtrvWXmUOjAIxHKw93nlEAOAHguIaSnTruMpsxv5EbKEdcJ2THAu@DYHHShkAC9OdpKvzkJMtMFvoHbiIlIuzFcMbYgIYQMpIlkHjwAIA2UI9dieqmOBJKdwHQgKrx2VDTC8RE/OqkrCDssdljB74mFeohaQ8xeRxITwUU/e3yWd6XkRBMDLLFDPfi77UEKOBus@FgAZ0GA4HUxfCqVg0UMCKwQ2PiYBFa14qBCYPemBr@GmfvQxmwWihd1yVZgm6NrpwiAfD9TWqCrQwj9r5g8UGPt0dZRWzO4OzTbWWWJJTGrHChAbqJmULG77eAPvMwGIyZj6ImfnogcshWNQeqwgAElKBigCmrizpw63X18oZIu1JLUNvwFBN@RiSIJY501MzaWHp4/5gHmGCAg8QLk/kinMUKB1YBTxTRCdMSCfcGwyN2mu8OMtLCgJgcdDFsxxzb2zqMJgMpqKmccREUoIpy5tlBgJAP3bVBB2lJkE00OoN2S@ajRTTx6JJQYWg6jAjurALPm3mRuVZg74F8IYhOlCAURsyMGYDC645nzG9Y9aVgDmqwdsog7lkAjROgZRNxWTX6BVBKoLmXDYcmrUjViTENmEuCnQQ/hQcGU7ClmU5IrTQMuGPv4rAAg@XkAD6MQLFWFiWxhkjIJqVRkNo9YS4wYP46P4YUHO20HZchijrYG2iZD5wuu1q13qxAYIx4KKvSl0wXaagMkajMRxg7@NxJRNZ08QHMHQDqSmJGfcEAllFAM5mtIFE8MSCYHFw2kFoRjiRGeJckKQ6xF8kkD83NjpJSwgUZPXA1WJMfiyTYMIf0Ql@eNRZKzOjzKhkzw5thBPKjZoMjhY6CVFMaJsK5DJPDwyNUfNFrUoESYBAK0xvpGaYbUL3PGT@M4QGXVhny6YIJ1laY5CE3gY6kW@0/KvoyZLVQFyLWZ54wVleliD5lNqcBwTW9vRAyn5X/uiiUCISWL3xrvT2nAOzEEgAfWe9sB@mU12kGUUBsHXdVinr@gZzYb8HfpaHOQsfcgI00PW58s/5zqiBWwOoGTsr5iF8O5NJAYrMzArgZ1zBiIVHEmBaAzlb62w1J2mmSATb6LcNnow5cDESwYopPpxolkCRsE5CP8tYF7LbqjHpo7dTUGhh4OzOiK@S2CIyGEShv9v9bUHEvDYxeO7vciZj3BU36VLgEkoQ03opQxptmEEzEM1yB72ACA2UQ3dC@qoXbPUCGscQm9/EXmQCGGWFlgsR9g7z5SIwYd7fZaUT@GhRGYsRxNThOnSIkUVL2mLc7H6HA9kEwWIxgjF1Oa4laOQHPBaIN86307vSw4eoROJKApgQjOAu2@hMAkLqBgj6U90wtgax0xJka1wISNpcl1LjY1YgRQLk32Z5DPqkfIB7l7WRiWAd4Vyyq1TdpA5XfHSgalN48mqtF0EsXfZ1dHv4UTT1BKfXAtg6/9JW8Ny76wktzsrKQN5NsDYux8OFZO1YF0nuGoibSibhzj8ltaFiWrvPVFuB@BP9Dr@Fr1IigGm4NsUYloKJYEAsXqdpY2O6J0KDxwAOB/cG4oVoxxY7Zbawjdf55CnzkEKwS650wuP1QeVmXPLOJFltsOSp@@BzcFNJVnOOhomCFkPXzeuisOsAXAOILbS91nWesxxAcjizFsEIhxbVKdx0FbI@qMRAifilQauXdBah5LP6oHQTRCcr9PqwwMxgJIzgPkhda8ENDlq9/Al0gywtMQ2XTE0Aylnx2q9Wne3zOg3xa6I6L@5ZfXC7mcrzxiw5Eoa8ZWR1M2UGPQFHPOgceiSYE7TJpMVAsLAHmJQ3QlUm4N0gZOFan3Vha8uEwVWg2MAw@G3AzccThigANni1Go8Bjp5LrIK5xtoHnQNzw/nEXp244EJgy32QuGvKuCbTw@QC/oYBk6NTVgoB/W8Bz5z5t2s29MsFPbEMeTEspPOCypVks6Q8ZQQuk2OAgMS1a65XNp8Rg3yhx5U5FdkBHqlAAugZvizJKmg1mAiWwbVwa85MshGZS@6Dw00RrKSyIM41Q/kbJPUI/rgyIhaRjGl0PS3dRCYtjRamseFlHtxiQYjG6oPAqUnGSBIPa4MH4As2W9ErIhyFCE6mEJslfMRsoV/XGMEvr7K0LT8igq0nBSOmaoQf6FMgdabqo6zh7dgNi1ljEIyDttSDVGYB10RJEGzDP8XZC65KiQL3qeAfc9b1D3DnbQmEIJhGsiZpR8wNExFAPTbrYLasYuu6MOtiEKw@KZ5WU1nRIpBb63SuGCz1xEbfbZd8rjoDRGKYmLBIxAGYNQtI7ZpFHwxvnZJfrRPyOyvoOSpirthi2qOjE4l@DkwvL7JJxiWeqzyLaCTR0nccw/dTJsuICKAeuVM4ywoBLIMYwNgcPqZH4iPAJyZVUL0mqxEBL0HO4Z3xF1lbplmVZ3IiAqDtuuh4Op66Cr4E1AE0zw9xZeR5hudCjHkjwfQMJQc1hL@Ko5BK@D/NiQV@upyybgsSMCxDQ0ODEP5DoCAYHFmxQ8gB5sSSCCUyAYz0/7r0NG4ZuqjmCGKaRzIffTA@KaxFVBDKCt8slO45lsSMastvCfMZeijIns/kBmI0nDIhWqjp90jX2TQYLlD1WO0xUywO1TWX6T1NbwKSd1WXCCfeiMQijv54YCqi7XCO6R9DnH@PgXuR89xl7EMwI58ErzVcDRZRmMECjldplhUyuUGE6R/MDq2NyEjKak1rDcDsdCLMLsPIAEQDbcfNPI2xvmAVu51JEjXD1S0y1suC24F5tWogo2TUkvDOtAaRjAlPGk@RD0h5uGeViIoWBm2VN/OzwDbRwCwLjCoLYB4yhI/DvK4Y9K6FHBaH65G@8PRQuknhh9wNIEupWc0enfoGEsEwNl4ZH3EWpiIQWAPQPS7igXmSABKzhb5jOL@CN0VPVwHLkVO2sOGZh0nI6ZB64tbQ@9OXSEL4Jc3bCsK3/hL18iVjGFz/Us4lQGC2sA3XXxI9cWvAtFaXmS05HHpB9PdBZ2SUzFEr@biyMxUnh4zbon8whDm7AhtrANbHgca147ZQZy3GMHItfYohjT6FEVlyAREKvQKAVVbXqhULlRlQiRDzN3vuSnP5v819QhCEswDzY8jJ9b70f/7tPzfQO7jIWGRBoNOCK7QDsL9JVrP@E5EjfjUDCS/4q0OXQ3@nTdcQE8DgsExBKmDQsgJmwI0ACxYSUVleaVkYxTVykHSyOgoT3lOwPb301Jw5PbOhgqLZUTEA4VO1H2b2H@GGj9ud/SEyQr0BKF8VchxJgx@FSgoKWNkQ1IVvVNzmkGL@qZjzlX0sjB3j1goX17APhGB7PuM7kTPeyB5L4mMuJ0rwYWpLRAEEM@cDcFZMN2IyQmvDZDDjRfKTlexw9ZLWU4vIGoDflRjK5UIxK0wsAIaO2yqvVrsgCvcegOnFLLcAw1DCpCEQwNJry@454Ya5houCLADGvisV59eMIq/NA9IpsHKdwlNcO4ja9TFciKyqDH/UtJpKh7@TlJjGRWek0JO5B/QvlxSIZP4AQTfwLLnkykwhXELAziwzSyC9GeyPKT3Gk17N5UGKgmDrmH0lvyvPKJLuDFgxd1V4JmkVhAlghRm3BAjxy6Jr34soZ@1X@3QmtVRoRpFqBY4SZu@MhbtJghqsh4pEVo55PlydYS0@nL5kkY0IABtcvqzL5VooNwS2MNAnctGRqUfuI6EgBnQNBMhB0Kxba8DlWINZ5TytjAktTLgZcMKxzf0jM4MBYOiCLiWhWaziylDJHRC4B1IMjBmz8LJ8xkjL1gE9OcgqjSoowoCnPjT5/DpQGE8FN6PgXgyFC6ucC3seOIusO@BiCWEdGo@LSRw@oVmKhOB4APb3LwxMdQ6GktgvEUjUkwlz01ULYBoz4EDkrm1EqrK@OCGwBuB/CLSKjJ81/jCon8g2@QAhPCgu15HFmogL4kwKhannyUzh9NpSPG4Ta63ebyviIWYCPMTQMVfcROL1kfoZS6n//n@lFFMUpihzIBsOxJyADybMYcUMs@TrhDjEYSo/41YAKWGngBaGERhhZk9rqbMElCLLgeT9aqmVlfRaXRrZi/mIwAi5s2W9lUaqhjjeRjJvyGwhDgmEEHODXCxX9FiFamShH2CH1614BK2Rz2DUv26sl7oVgWBkFQ6DMgmlCSWSHnALwj11b3GvvIfZ3cxz5UT24IAoJhnXRxSITkYOOmAJHjsVV1gwGNyIPUogbGN3XX5k0yXE5BnUGGgNwBKndcp8wTRjETzuypjliMAb5HyJ0VLdBbemvznHo2hkGURkuUxwxSs18w9pOA05@YlWEI5hqihWG/xwVZzxOugix22ldMVgiijEdYI2wiPyXq2kEIUFnvia0RHiEIeVrwWDRNYDGIEIptGVqZKyfJEEwjh2QZURvEb8tIagj17MjHPET8gdY7fXWuDWAg@JUNP2mxQ3BpgN1D2XdW/r@I2CjkgRYOr/ydTmsNsDmMQeMkF4L7iX3EO4FzQ6gWboTu5paiZ6prXRISIOK4SFEm9WbKEcuVwCsPkCA95rWQ/AnR5y88KMmXc@Y3CnQq9lQGsIrqiW2saMphdEC6g6eJiyYgc9OimEpTm263KjBZVXKykztcS0gXMnT6wntjDdjJAt1H1WjXDFibXigrlsNCRDLBoEqBh/dhsbcqWQOiIcMWyzb/hItMm/oYUBE6DHeiFZqbyqqBNdgBltyBq8qk5tsxAXYs6mCAn3iZV4IQui0NE3prUIU55od9cYwCoxU6UiEMPSWWdAitr3WaeOJuTKxrDbNRui2lmDGHPGkBlCUeMey545NNAyaliQ9qYheTkFAlhADHGuWW7L8rII3JQwBDMEY5xOJUBmG2etgjEz7I5bQIKD5gm0mPqRy5VbLdlyRHyTwgBYxtxOKc82rjETTRrKbK1hT6JEPzQFpSvZY2wU3HYxBF1k8Ioxiz5ElPBmswyvLqR@Qarw6kLOjPsi4BrJJjGZ0RcMwRZXCx1izsBloOtQIICFaVFYZg2JUhtWU9DmNvfWxWmgaHATxAQwOKwT8FSawYMW6DdGJIJxxE24CrMJg2GDQ/m5sSurICRUyhhFjsQKBjkPi5Dl68ZGaWVMHbrxVPmZvcNVRMG8ABDIalbL8pYYiGsZFizLQ9gEWpgBsOUuQjBHTGUIu@F1NZgTVazjABPj9wnMqAI/jJoaTytkW3D4gx2CYuchSZmvMwpooGfxRpz5LAHAbCerplQAcI/jmBvDmLtabzilKBtOhwPJj5dVyqg0K7w6l8TcTNLzMK8LcEHQFR6okYhg6/7@6nmNUAd3pKZPpNZAHNTDnJum2mN1kIGRfLnPjsnVqXm4ZI0dBLQwSEVqDu@/AZrIjYvTbGlU2RLmITM7gckuNsR4dJifQBBFPwHrUoyeRRQEIxfJQOV57rotMKJCCoyGYIomyY6JIpVFBTYcFEPZYRswoyBZdiOUYsJEGXM/oY3GNzlwoxDXPeQuC2M3@0VaSTCsPRc0PmPRmEq0wQJhYk2jYtIBfzRYY0CYWP@hZclcCcpx9uCK83AeTvHoFbfrS6edC4BR3EUldXEZIVeXh6CKecPCJqZJgJgmGQ65hMLNr/bk7/@FfyIJsoYO9ytg5LNbTaVX4UQd3gGpv8fEixCc1CEmQtflcnAU@qxwZd2MNNByagwyrotXghC@DpkeZIXK76IjiFJzNARNNCZWmvE/RbYwDc0mFnT2HX5QYguLI4X7zIgQMBodOiPZ@2wnTSn1C8CleCJnLCtUNp6gFoTWGpIOZrXMhJKYFIGZySF3aHDNuN2LL1j24g9HXanNqVZto3k0E2dZwvcKsAav1GsRENY@K74LBnNeVBocoodzcRhOIzc72gVyx8QQZJBkJItUQ6DQCUkCFWkVOB3X2CW/JwA2uIFwh4ucKUcRBGlhMJUvijTkt1U05oCxREmajhKjDk@vQAP1lStkylOLAMQvdEmcFuAfXL0gZst@Pu4Zyyxb8J4UIgmCjUX5mGTLq9pdEU317nA8WFsRsCLMhSMXORZPPh7@UxGy1GBAxRKM4dj5/0qUU0RDidES4RjuqwN5UO0h3CHITeEJAEbVePyvzWwwNzus9WswJUmGHGjODLkDxjhTiwje1WNxCzfqLgTDxDRjGoV0lJgEef@0z9kQJlaCISJLbUNHKZCQOrsMoDL0tTBpiJIGOvYOrrxBJgrQQjuUI1vvCcj6eQdkUd6wEOkG7FVPoxC6kRTRV1ligxgluZEAYBqb8utCz3VKf16tkeWAKuY4KGI9mdbRjtqZ4O@LSk14BiCOQVYXPvkc5qtAc98nNYJg77ropxNYuFkx5qYbVvZAlj3cDigkYxEOfbgEeBMR0cLEjWj0FEx7ATHr5YBDGuWimcPxUGALw9Bd2h4gk1qlu@T@IYUnBubYtAdz0blagXFCinEyMI7clS1lt@6qkRa68VWyH5QspJB6cDVOl6uorPzHB@4yKOKahxjKIAI5gwOKaDYpZwuhaNJA3WPeo5JE4lIgWqj76BNeiJiVuYRGtxIrQp3uQHi/lACnMqdr/j63oxXgK6xVE6g83hxQQ0ThcOTCkmWab2VO9Q4YYk6@qdWGnDGEHAAGTA1FiB7HrTUpk0WswWIfBT2U1zps@JCVLGFrvknEaOWdIk6P@1Y8LjFqvkIijMJcoxcznciaRC3FnZEIBLDAC2Y1a6c9Dta0lVLeOhDGJgNP/10D2NQCYBq4QZ2AMuvfRqMQq1RDTuxA0h@pFEQSwOLIW3MCLY6V8FzRrzo9VjZ7LL6OEdCHkSKAemw2xMMnLpjOpWCg5YAoiu3/X1IU/VqJAztcsc3Mym@hs6Dg8gszYBX1spxLgCMxi9ZVqHdI71hrKRIL7h0SyXDCGQK/PGniMPSVlooK1gtJTYXTNzlom3GAIAKo0XEaKegqsrzN5YkCCNahu0DnbnYWcGKN4JAQE0XfWW8nTDS6s5bNiwQwjdolXpXrJSFbqPn2A5@3qyFgazncmgulFze@Ln3FgubaFwBbR5ZewDR9s/YiAPru732h6qLmm3TYQISNb3Wol7ZsQmKywgAYWHJT6LUhllhEDAOXUUssMY@BrBp0Bowxw7DiOpWp4JH3IJAgUC8IRznX69cmjIgq0RDAPLpu9hX3IIiGAOYxw8/pdL2YIEKNPw5mKaHxwuw8WiiuCWhKsHUY57F4qlxoTBsUBMHEZWh0eRatpbLqJhvsmDl2yCllJ5pqi2ooae4bcYbM1SdT7nMOBWk8GbDJqzysHcDLtWJRw8YUfQmaI4s1ggXB4qCXJDmmRJbACM7wWKTGMA5VNVtbKAqCcSyZ5cZmsYyBRJYDXsm4glfKBS7grCSCBXNJHcma04ZXe7UsR@RNHdUJ/sPODEzOZB7XdoD@spHKU2W9YRjLfrYYY4iYAIY@E5chenOlpSqExSFQD3hDlM0Ka@VGrJ/FDeP@EFNt5/NdIrK7mgoDYXfMUjvGRC3I14QwjFhvgqHBNyUQIXKDlvMqOq0ky4iYK3NG68JqzFWs16KU0KOMOC64nCbpD9fnJ8veHZDMc1M4kGR/ZIKTbAdzx4jvBomUURO1annuSSbrLGKLKIqJNQh5jeuO/vs/BG4A0jA0hryOdaxnGH1ipACjY4yTOq6Nngj6kdFPEeOJesp1YGfEl2eUCUjcNAsMxHTL8kOj1cmkaDIj8c0y3PkrtdpSC8usJuMVZ9xta7v5iIj4iMZ8E9WMzDCxud1MBABYEFrWqxVGD5edCAmgRzgBVsqsqWZFp1qLJX9u6Hohwt@wAole1gU8LV9b5oBL/t6uZqpGjay1nMXIjRQGEF8dVLCFCtF2uxeJuwAEcxvACJwxZcBf8g1JZaIgIYpdJQqmjrwiiJNQoE1Vh5YFztEuR3zBv74hlEGKps0WMyIcwB2PGGnMLeFygWWVbQTymIKg26liVTmhIBgGLJJkMhlTn@J/6Ibtu@A8bqiMsx2KLU5hdlxQdr48AhwYSHGb9Uh2jDBfq1IBikeOjU4qdQkFWCPZ45uxTtVUmIrEt0aNQByr2YLnYxrRMbVWSLJ8wr1JAolg6kmdEuJqE5JTEAQTq23h6it@iS96YwP11SsbWHpsIBAMcAAZNyTLilIpm6mh5YspQnl@eaFnOi0ZmogqFPsIXIqrEGHACuZrxe2iZhww4s4RvoWPXodVSJj0ogVba9TljdAakyEzOCDZIjFbOwKR5E0J242H8IXaKABgla2/c3kvGn9bG9FgmHtX5vb9GCIaDHOfC9m5MB8C8p4RKxIzbp6tZCvsCHQSN5O8gr4KUAD0DkaXF8lHyB/jKmyI2MBu39RmRPi1ERgkvFPZ5CxSnca6LkQOBVojLknLGvjVQSJTgrHDle5YPhBSjGSTr4ThovbrCVvouerE132YimdiOU1QRtkIlvJ9PZV5XwY3hPF1GSOQxkaB83pSK8@FPG4bGbH2kGsOshlZIFqoWYYbNztMTptNOBQ9/IdtdBWuZbK/pYjkrDjXqVi2LMKJxSIJskZ9vuyAmy/5CSo66jN3gtMxWkJuyRzxdSxEzEQZBAC1@DTwRP5JvqbMSHxR2Qi0TxZxMbph50YfZkwEwshEu0qYH@WGcLMpxSAYh21wMpGVx9pXIke1fNNxr9Q21wdwz0RBLAesOeD1/V7QcIbpj/@1rYXWCKSwNEPs2sI4FWZlfCR7hFuDbYa7UbAy0ZvhAGYcMGBZTWG2txuZCFZW45sbubYaGRKsLFxJ5ZVbYFBqLeCawBSvRa9iFFmZGHYExjhDnIX/jOAhO2u5YnZ2BDLIOtJSFyzNmkniDgiGsUvOVLAcdsdnjA8x9PFhjcAE8USCmsWAOpHVB4jyeyCCfLGYXcL3xQITgbB03WxSmve6rff7ikK2Ao9ABaU8CPcHJxPJptSihbDyfVp8XVT7EoHavERgxPRiWNjXX5oG@eqlaXz9XXHPLmZNouWNTnznGdRchmAK7Wrxm6JZ@x7xNXjcY1zisfHNAxDYwjB2VYw/kcj@JpU0FHHRCC9GZIUzMuylzXwISL6SFhZGmCkIYcnaNiGHdSFvhOEuNgNxVNfUf8rbEoFwJ8EKTWmg6AjlDYojh28FIB0os/OMu9QKkVsM@4BZC/zBiXbRB7yap8c8nM@FRtNwcna4Gou4liUbNl/agsiXuycKtjBjyqh/v63Aq6cyAh1OGdwqjGd4rmatQGiNDDn0MhOUClwxKh0xBWnevSQW4rWl235FaKbAOYnmSPKQ8hWxyFdaS18WbaSs1pQEG5ElwSOuSht@KlvQuPjFBobhlSFmjS@EiACWq7c6eYo80Jx6IAhW3IYGZGGlPMYSo5G8GYMvJIQqUSsiawR6qPlCH0yhpq3q8v8B)

Based on idea of @dingledooper (thanks!), but making it a step further by using the longest common suffix to help as well. Also used zlib & base85 to further reduce size a bit.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 100%, 835 bytes

Sorry folks, Pyke contains a built-in [Pokémon dictionary](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/blob/master/pokemon.json). Unfortunately, it only contains up to `#802: marshadow`, so 88 names had to be hard-coded.

Should work for all inputs, but the TIO environment seems to have a slightly different version of Pyke than on the "Pyke Interpreter" website, so inputs greater than 802 only work on the latter (see below).

```
Q0@802>"poipole,naganadel,stakataka,blacephalon,zeraora,meltan,melmetal,grookey,thwackey,rillaboom,scorbunny,raboot,cinderace,sobble,drizzile,inteleon,skwovet,greedent,rookidee,corvisquire,corviknight,blipbug,dottler,orbeetle,nickit,thievul,gossifleur,eldegoss,wooloo,dubwool,chewtle,drednaw,yamper,boltund,rolycoly,carkol,coalossal,applin,flapple,appletun,silicobra,sandaconda,cramorant,arrokuda,barraskewda,toxel,toxtricity,sizzlipede,centiskorch,clobbopus,grapploct,sinistea,polteageist,hatenna,hattrem,hatterene,impidimp,morgrem,grimmsnarl,obstagoon,perrserker,cursola,sirfetch'd,mr. rime,runerigus,milcery,alcremie,falinks,pincurchin,snom,frosmoth,stonjourner,eiscue,indeedee,morpeko,cufant,copperajah,dracozolt,arctozolt,dracovish,arctovish,duraludon,dreepy,drakloak,dragapult,zacian,zamazenta,eternatus"\,cQ0@803-@&Q0@~_+1-.ol1|
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Q0%40802%3E%22poipole%2Cnaganadel%2Cstakataka%2Cblacephalon%2Czeraora%2Cmeltan%2Cmelmetal%2Cgrookey%2Cthwackey%2Crillaboom%2Cscorbunny%2Craboot%2Ccinderace%2Csobble%2Cdrizzile%2Cinteleon%2Cskwovet%2Cgreedent%2Crookidee%2Ccorvisquire%2Ccorviknight%2Cblipbug%2Cdottler%2Corbeetle%2Cnickit%2Cthievul%2Cgossifleur%2Celdegoss%2Cwooloo%2Cdubwool%2Cchewtle%2Cdrednaw%2Cyamper%2Cboltund%2Crolycoly%2Ccarkol%2Ccoalossal%2Capplin%2Cflapple%2Cappletun%2Csilicobra%2Csandaconda%2Ccramorant%2Carrokuda%2Cbarraskewda%2Ctoxel%2Ctoxtricity%2Csizzlipede%2Ccentiskorch%2Cclobbopus%2Cgrapploct%2Csinistea%2Cpolteageist%2Chatenna%2Chattrem%2Chatterene%2Cimpidimp%2Cmorgrem%2Cgrimmsnarl%2Cobstagoon%2Cperrserker%2Ccursola%2Csirfetch%27d%2Cmr.+rime%2Crunerigus%2Cmilcery%2Calcremie%2Cfalinks%2Cpincurchin%2Csnom%2Cfrosmoth%2Cstonjourner%2Ceiscue%2Cindeedee%2Cmorpeko%2Ccufant%2Ccopperajah%2Cdracozolt%2Carctozolt%2Cdracovish%2Carctovish%2Cduraludon%2Cdreepy%2Cdrakloak%2Cdragapult%2Czacian%2Czamazenta%2Ceternatus%22%5C%2CcQ0%40803-%40%26Q0%40~_%2B1-.o%7Cl1&input=%5B880%2C+%22draco%22%2C+%22volt%22%5D&warnings=1&hex=0) (This site doesn't seem to support unicode, so output for `nidoran♀` will be in UTF-8)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVNBchQxDPxKag9wQKSScIELlS9wBorS2NoZxR5rkO0sO0VRfIPv8ZGlveEwdltrt1ot7XZOcrl8unt8f/fw8bCZbpaFCs9cOEqm2jjx@GjKHGRbOFuhXZzNmVbJjcvYVmmcaXazJGdqy4nDAK4582S2Ug3mUy8FsRFoFLRE0AShatOEpNF13xVAS5MsSFPTyZ6lgVYkSmk06DWKEMietX7v6v9xKjovDSJ1m/pM0VrL4oScIm1UpCFpgzCV5w6hVqses3QnyVHGkU5m2YxinwaisMipXWVJLHyiM68bGCfLrZcIKfkc8FFgT@O6wZlaYQJvW9ZCxzyAXI@CJ1Q1a7AJtlUukYNhoeC8wknUxu6WOkITENckJ@BmP9AErM01aDuDZN9RI@ygAEe0JvOwUMjw0LZe4dVIaKHhatHahAktxTYLTrRwk1J47M1lve7iUuD6umnEQtAzj59m13WthT2TTZiD2dASWOBVPMGJ0L1aRjXqR2lheR1p9dsbvBLyXsR1hp5VcxA/E@cAUhU6MtxJlTYtYAgLrKoFA3J0q6u1BSNn5cm6g4GgOfQxEXFMgAxtmyRD7uPwLNgGQfzEC9oER3dUCiNDe0HXGOZkeYldUezOuUeUgsbKdh6XUjZOA8y8dbzbOSjGeueVd5jMJPCocOv18IXC9c/y7u3jK4Bf397cv721n/n@cvn88IFuDkWjeT8AOUqzAf7@@X34@g8) (Supports unicode, but throws an error for inputs > 802)

Takes input in the form `[1, "bulb", "-saur"]`

**Some relevant portions of the program:**

```
Q0@
```

Read from STDIN, ignoring everything besides the pokemon number

```
Q0@802>...&
```

*IF* (pokemon #) > 802, Do the following:

```
"poipole,naganadel..."
```

- Using this long string of hardcoded names,

```
\,c
```

-- split on commas, and

```
Q0@803-@
```

-- return the name at index ((pokemon #) - 803)

```
Q0@~_+1-...|
```

*ELSE*: Find the index of this pokemon in the dictionary

```
.o
```

- Lookup in the built-in pokemon dictionary, and:

```
l1
```

- convert to lowercase, implicitly print